# O que é uma linguagem de script?

Tags: característica-linguagem

Costuma-se dizer que PHP, Javascript, Ruby, Python, entre outras são "linguagens de script."

Mas o que define se uma linguagem de programação é uma linguagem de script ou não?

Alguns diriam que as linguagens de script são as interpretadas, porém Java é interpretado e não é citado como uma linguagem de script.

O que é uma linguagem de script?

Comment: Retirei o meu voto de fechar, na esperança de aparecerem respostas interessantes, mas para já, continuo a achar amplo demais, não vejo nenhuma resposta concreta e fundamentada, apenas me parecem opiniões com algum tipo de informação correta.

Comment: Java não é interpretada há muitos anos.

Comment: A pergunta é boa justamente porque muita gente não entende bem o que é. É verdade que não dá para responder 100% porque não há uma conceituação universalmente aceita, mas vimos aqui algumas respostas bem erradas (algumas foram apagadas) mostrando que é necessário uma explicação.

Comment: @bigown apaguei sim, respondi o conceito que sempre achei ser verdade, mas como você disse ser uma premissa errada (e não quero contribuir com lixo) espero uma resposta concreta de alguém para comparar com a minha resposta, assim fica mais fácil discutir o assunto, só dizer que está errado fica muito vago.

Comment: @Filipe nenhum problema em apagar não. Se você não consegue melhorá-la, é o melhor a fazer mesmo. Eu mesmo já apaguei minhas. Nas respostas apagadas eu dei os motivos objetivos de estar errado, nada vago. Eu já aprendi muita coisa errada, na internet tá cheio de informação errada, mas quando você começa juntar as coisas, você lê as definições existentes você vê que uma contrapõe a outra e aí você só pode se valer daquelas que não encontra objeção clara. A forma de execução não define se a linguagem é de *script*, tem tantas casos contrários nisto que não serve de parâmetro.

Comment: Linguagens de script são linguagens de programação que não requerem  compilação, ou seja são interpretadas. e a unica diferenca que vejo.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Linguagem de script é qualquer linguagem que for usada para escrever um script. A grande pergunta é **O que é um script?**. E essa é bastante subjetiva, uma análise caso a caso.

A distinção toda está no objetivo e no uso. Em um script você descreve uma sequencia de comandos e tarefas que alguém deve executar (o interpretador). O exemplo clássico disso são as linguagens para os prompts de comando, seja o shell/bash ou para o batch do Windows. Outras linguagens sugiram como um intuito de facilitar a escrita de pequenos programas, permitindo maior complexidade no que antes era feito com os `.sh` ou `.bat`. Essas linguagens são chamadas de *shell languages*.

Varias linguagens criadas posteriormente que podem funcionar como script são o perl, python, ruby, etc. Mas note que com o poder e flexibilidade que elas tem, muitas são usadas para escrever grandes aplicações, especialmente do lado do servidor. Nesse caso já deixou de ser apenas de script.

Outra definição comum está em afirmar que linguagens de script são aquelas que podem ser embutidas em outros programas. Na engine de jogos Unity3D, por exemplo, você pode programar o comportamento de cada objeto usando C#. Nesse caso C# é uma linguagem de script, mesmo sendo compilado. Mas se você escrever uma aplicação inteira em C# e executar ela de forma independente, não vai ser um script. Da mesma forma você pode entender que o javascript está estendendo a habilidade do browser dando características adicionais à sua página, portanto é um script. Existe um dialeto de C/C++, o AngelScript, que foi construído com esse objetivo de ser embutível facilmente. É mais um exemplo de linguagem de script.

Dizer que tudo que é compilado não é script e tudo que é interpretado é script é errado. A forma como o código é executado não influencia, ainda mais nesses dias de JIT em que os interpretadores cada vez mais são iguais aos compiladores. A questão toda está no propósito daquele código.

De forma geral, pode-se dizer que as linguagens de script dependem de um certo ambiente para serem executadas corretamente. Seja as utilidades da linha de comando, seja as funcionalidades de uma engine de jogos ou navegador. Enquanto que uma linguagem sem ser de script executa "nua", sendo mais independente. Tem muitos casos em que é difícil distinguir, vira algo quase subjetivo.

Leitura complementar:
[Why are scripting languages (e.g. Perl, Python, Ruby) not suitable as shell languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637668/why-are-scripting-languages-e-g-perl-python-ruby-not-suitable-as-shell-lang)

Comment: Ainda fiquei com mais dúvidas eu... Parece-me que estamos a focar um ponto bastante subjetivo, o que é um script.

Comment: "closed as not constructive" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Bem... cheguei um pouco tarde neste post, mas eu sempre compreendi linguagens de script como sendo aquelas usadas em "domínios específicos", ou seja, criadas para auxiliar a resolução de problemas em um determinado segmento da ciência da computação. Geralmente, o "motor" de uma linguagem de script está embutido em uma aplicação, de modo que a mesma possa ser configurada com muita flexibilidade, auxiliando a automatização de determinadas tarefas.

Linguagens de programação por sua vez, permitem a criação de aplicativos (ou programas) para execução em um ou mais sistemas operacionais, estes aplicativos podem ser criados para diversas finalidades e são executados quase sempre independentes de alguma outra aplicação.

Eu participei de um projeto, onde foi desenvolvida uma aplicação em linguagem C, para ler e processar arquivos provenientes de centrais telefônicas. Esta aplicação usa a linguagem de scripts [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/) embutida, de modo que quando é concluído o download de um arquivo, scripts em Tcl são executados para efetuar diversos tipos de processamento no conteúdo do mesmo, os resultados produzidos após este processamento atendem outras áreas da empresa, como por exemplo a de faturamento e a de análise contra fraudes.

Neste exemplo, C seria a linguagem de programação, Tcl a linguagem de scripts.

Atualmente, as linguagens de scripts estão se tornando mais sofisticadas, permitindo por exemplo que o código fonte de um script seja "compilado" para um arquivo em "bytecode", neste caso, o "motor" na aplicação hospedeira executa o arquivo em bytecode, que tende a ter uma melhor performance de execução além de proteger o código fonte do script contra terceiros. O problema começa quando scripts são desenvolvidos para execução fora de uma aplicação, isto é possível, sendo que eu mesmo já criei scripts em Tcl que possuem interface gráfica e são executados diretamente pelo interpretador desta, fora de qualquer aplicação hospedeira, neste caso Tcl também pode ser classificada como uma linguagem de programação? Na minha humilde opinião, não. O próprio autor da linguagem afirma que a mesma foi criada para ser embutida em aplicações, de modo a resolver um conjunto específico de problemas.

Parece não existir uma classificação formal para identificar linguagens de script e de programação. Eu acho que o mais indicado é descobrir quem criou a linguagem e que uso esta pessoa ou empresa pretende para a mesma. Geralmente, se a linguagem permite ser embutida em uma aplicação escrita em uma outra linguagem, então ela é definida como sendo principalmente uma linguagem de script.

Comment: mas um script não seria uma linguagem de programação?

Answer (score -1):

Linguagens de script são aquelas em que o interpretador lê o código fonte e gera um "bytecode" que é então executado pelo compilador, ou seja o bytecode é um meio termo entre a fonte e linguagem de maquina. Portanto as linguagens de script ou interpretadas precisam do código fonte para executar o programa, ao contrario de linguagens compiladas que após ser executado a compilação, basta o executável binário para executar o programa.

Simplificando

Linguagens interpretadas necessitam do código fonte para executar, enquanto as compiladas precisam apenas do compilado.

Minha conclusão :

Linguagens de programação base (linguagens compiladas) são descompiladas pelo compilador( semelhante ao que o descompactador zip faz ) e executadas pelo executável binário (linguagem primária da máquina , linguagem que o homem não entende ou seja a origem de tudo relativo ao software da máquina ) .

Por outro lado linguangens scripts ou linguagens interpretadas são aquelas que não são executadas diretamente pelo compilador , primeiro elas são interpretadas pelas linguagens de programação base(linguagens compiladas) e essas interpretam esse script e transformam-á em código compilado  para que essas sejam processadas pelo compilador e finalmente serem executadas .

Espero que eu tenha ajudado a galerinha á entender o que são scripts ou linguagens scripts :) ...

Comment: Não não é isto, dê uma lida na resposta bem mais votada que tem informações mais concretas. Tem vários conceitos errados nesta resposta.

Answer (score -2):

Linguagens de script são aquelas em que o interpretador lê o código fonte e gera um "bytecode" que é então executado pelo compilador, ou seja o bytecode é um meio termo entre a fonte e linguagem de maquina. Portanto as linguagens de script ou interpretadas precisam do código fonte para executar o programa, ao contrario de linguagens compiladas que após ser executado a compilação, basta o executável binário para executar o programa.

**Simplificando**

Linguagens interpretadas necessitam do código fonte para executar, enquanto as compiladas precisam apenas do compilado.

Comment: Há uma enorme confusão de conceitos aqui. Além de cair no erros de outras respostas, ainda inverteu o erro deixando uma parte da resposta contradizendo a outra parte, tornando-o ainda pior.

Answer (score -3):

Linguagens de programação que foram desenvolvidas originalmente em ambiente Linux, normalmente são chamadas scripts, devido a uma relação analoga que os profissionais fazem ao se remeterem à outras linguagens de script com o shell script(sh script), bash script, etc. Em algumas traduções de livros diz se que são roteiros de comandos a serem executados, daí também a analogia script.

Comment: Queria dizer ambiente Unix correcto?

Comment: A resposta não explica bem, mas pelo menos não cai no erro de outras respostas que confundem conceitos e usam premissas erradas. Essa sua até está razoavelmente boa, mas já vi outras respostas que você deu que são muito vagas e não ajudam muita coisa. Aqui procuramos respostas que realmente ajudem a entender ou resolver problemas. Procure desenvolver suas respostas um pouco melhor e vai se dar bem. Elas nem precisam ser longas, mas precisa dar um resposta real, por isso uso esta como um exemplo de algo que se aproximou bem do objetivo.