# Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?

Tags: característica-linguagem, tipagem, independente-de-linguagem

Algum tempo atrás, o Facebook lançou sua própria linguagem de programação, baseada no PHP. Veja: [Tecnoblog: Facebook anuncia Hack, sua própria linguagem de programação](http://tecnoblog.net/153561/facebook-hack-linguagem-de-programacao/).

O Tecnoblog explica da seguinte maneira a diferença entre o PHP e o Hack (ênfase adicionada):

> O objetivo principal sempre foi o de atacar os erros. No comunicado oficial, os desenvolvedores explicam que linguagens **dinâmicas**, como o PHP, facilitam o desenvolvimento rápido, mas geralmente tornam a detecção de erros mais difícil, uma vez que as falhas só são percebidas quando o programa está em execução, o que é particularmente preocupante em projetos muito grandes.
>
> Por sua vez, usando linguagens do tipo **estática**, como C, os desenvolvedores podem encontrar erros antes da efetiva execução do código, com a possível desvantagem de linguagens como esta não serem tão práticas quanto às mais atuais. Como consequência, o Hack foi criado para unir o melhor dos mundos.

Aparentemente, isso significa que o Hack suporta declarar o tipo de retorno das funções/métodos, permitindo que as IDEs identifiquem antecipadamente erros de compilação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

1. Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem estática e dinâmica? Existem outras diferenças além da que eu consegui identificar acima?
2. Vantagens e desvantagens
3. Pode-se dizer que as linguagens de *script* são sempre dinâmicas e vice-versa? (Veja: [O que é uma linguagem de script?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17082/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-script))

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Vou falar aqui de forma como as pessoas entendem. Se você for estudar [teoria dos tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) verá que algumas coisas aí são diferentes disto.

Há uma certa confusão em vários termos sobre este assunto. Em alguns casos não há uma definição formal aceita universalmente.

Popularmente as linguagens são classificadas pela sua tipagem, então linguagens estáticas formalmente são linguagem que possuem tipagem estática. E linguagens dinâmicas possuem tipagem dinâmica.

Algumas linguagens podem ser classificadas como dinâmicas por terem outras características. Elas permitem execução de código arbitrário ([`eval`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101)) ou a transformação de códigos existentes em tempo de execução. Cada vez é mais comum as linguagens modernas permitirem estas flexibilidades. Não importa a tipagem, então formalmente existem linguagens que são dinâmicas por esta definição e estáticas pela tipagem.

### Definição

#### Estática

A definição básica da tipagem estática que uma linguagem de programação pode ter como característica é que há uma verificação dos tipos usados em dados e variáveis para garantir que sempre está sendo usado um tipo que é esperado em todas as situações. Esta verificação é feita no código fonte pelo processo de compilação. Esta análise ajuda na chamada **segurança de tipos** na utilização dos dados pelo programa permitindo que o programador **se preocupe menos** com esta questão. O compilador fornece garantias que alguns problemas não poderão ocorrer após o programa passar por esta verificação, ou seja, erros são detectados logo, antes do programa ser efetivamente executado.

Uma variável não pode mudar seu tipo.

No entanto a tipagem estática pode causar uma falsa sensação de segurança. Só uma parte dos erros podem ser descobertos antecipadamente.

Exemplo (está em C# mas poderia bem ser pseudocódigo):

```
var x = 1;
x = "1"; //erro de compilação, não pode trocar o tipo da variável
```

#### Dinâmica

Na tipagem dinâmica esta verificação também ocorre mas ela é feita em cima do dado em si, já que as variáveis podem conter qualquer tipo de dado. Claro que em determinado momento uma variável só pode conter um tipo de dado e isto é verificado. Mas a principal diferença é que a esta verificação é feita em tempo de execução. Isto é feito através de uma infraestrutura auxiliar (uma máquina virtual ou uma biblioteca normalmente chamada de *runtime*). É comum o programador ter que fazer suas próprias verificações no programa ou em códigos externos de teste para garantir que todos os tipos estão corretos nos momentos certos. O programador tem que **se preocupar mais** com os tipos embora em soluções simples pode parecer que a preocupação não seja necessária.

O que é dinâmico efetivamente é o tipo da variável. Entender e documentar os tipos ainda são necessários. Há linguagens que incentivam fazer a documentação no código com [notação húngara](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/139321/101).

Dados precisam ser representados concretamente no computador. [Variável é um *design pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101) ([variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)). Portanto é uma abstração. Dados não podem assumir várias formas, no máximo pode ser interpretados de formas diferentes em casos específicos. Variáveis podem se referenciar a tipos de diferentes. Portanto a tipagem dinâmica costuma ser um caso especial da tipagem estática. Segundo Bob Harper, um dos criadores da linguagem Standard ML, "uma linguagem dinamicamente tipada é uma linguagem estaticamente tipada com apenas um tipo estático".

Na prática a tipagem dinâmica é uma abstração também. Há uma ilusão que você pode se referenciar a um dado que possui diferentes tipos mas na prática existe apenas um marcador e há um apontamento para um dado estático diferente.

As técnicas mais comuns para alcançar esta ilusão é o uso de um tipo união ([`union`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137393/101) em C/C++) e/ou ponteiros sem especificação de tipo ([`void *`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97138/101) em C/C++). Todos os dados terão algum *overhead* de memória.

Exemplo (está em JavaScript mas poderia ser pseudocódigo, note que a sintaxe é idêntica ao exemplo anterior mas a semântica é diferente)

```
var x = 1;
x = "1"; //operação normal, o tipo que era um number passa ser string
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Dynamic.js).

#### Performance

Outra grande diferença é em relação à performance. Embora seja possível fazer otimizações em um programa escrito com "linguagem dinâmica" para aproximar ou até ultrapassar a performance dos programas escritos em "linguagens estáticas", pela dificuldade de alcançar isto normalmente não é feito com eficácia. Em teoria um [compilador JIT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) tem mais condições de otimizar código com informações precisas de como o programa será executado e mesmo na prática pode até conseguir algum resultado melhor isoladamente.

Por outro lado se você já sabe com o que vai lidar, não precisa ter nada no código gerado auxiliando o funcionamento no programa e o próprio programa não precisa ter certas verificações escritas pelo programador. Se a verificação é feita antes da execução um programa com tipagem estática não precisa ter este trabalho durante a execução.

Não ajuda também o fato de que a maioria dos programas com tipagem dinâmica vão rodar em uma máquina virtual já que isto facilita o desenvolvimento da linguagem e permite algumas flexibilidades extras normalmente desejáveis em "linguagens dinâmicas".

Na prática as linguagens não costumam ser 100% qualquer coisa. Ferramentas pragmáticas sabem quando fugir um pouco de um conceito para dar melhor vantagem para o programador.

### Linguagens híbridas

Existem as linguagens híbridas. Na prática não é possível ter as duas formas de tipagem mas é possível usar parte de um ou de outro conceito.

### Linguagem estática com tipos dinâmicos

Quando uma linguagem é considerada estática, formalmente ela tem tipagem estática, ela pode ter a [infraestrutura necessária para guardar dados diferentes em uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101). Mas os dados são guardados de uma forma diferente dos outros tipos. Você terá um tipo estático que pode guardar dados dinamicamente, mas a linguagem ainda tem tipagem estática em sua essência.

A grosso modo a linguagem usa uma estrutura de dados extra para guardar o seu tipo e indicar onde está o dado real. Normalmente é feito na biblioteca e costuma ter auxílio do compilador apenas para indicar que a verificação normalmente feita deve ser relaxada já que a verificação será feita por esta biblioteca até certo ponto e também pelo programador para evitar que determinados erros serão gerados em *runtime* através desta biblioteca.

### Linguagem dinâmica com tipos estáticos

Linguagem com tipagem dinâmica não pode efetivamente ser parcialmente estáticas. Afinal uma linguagem dinâmica, formalmente que a tipagem seja dinâmica, deve sempre esperar qualquer tipo. Se ela começar esperar um tipo específico e fazer a verificação antes da execução, ela se transforma em "linguagem estática". Não é possível reduzir o nível de abstração.

É até possível prover uma verificação de tipos anterior como recurso adicional da linguagem mas não faz muito sentido se não vier acompanhado da mudança na forma com que os dados são gerenciados na memória. Se o programa precisa ter seus tipos fixos e garantidos antecipadamente seria um desperdício ele usar uma estrutura que permita ter vários tipos. Esta estrutura tem custo de memória (*tag* do tipo, referências para o tipo em todas situações<sup>*</sup>) e de processamento (indireção extra, seleção do dado/método específico a ser utilizado).

Não faz sentido, mas as linguagens estão fazendo isto, quase todas linguagens *mainstream* estão adotando uma forma que se aproxima, sem ser, de tipagem estática.

#### Tipagem manifesta

É possível uma "linguagem dinâmica" usar tipagem manifesta sem mudar sua característica de tipagem dinâmica. A vantagem é pequena ou até questionável.

Mas também há casos de linguagens que conseguem compilar partes do código com tipagem estática e partes com tipagem dinâmica. A interface entre as partes precisam ser normalizadas para um jeito ou outro. Curiosamente algumas preferem se definir como estáticas ou dinâmicas para tentar incutir uma cultura predominante e usar a outra como exceção. Os puristas, para o bem ou para o mal, consideram uma escolha ruim. Na verdade existem duas linguagens muito semelhantes neste caso e não apenas uma.

<sup>*</sup>Algumas linguagens estáticas possuem referências para tipos quando os dados serão armazenados no *heap*. E mesmo no *stack* a informação ainda existirá no código para permitir reflexão, mas não haverá consumo de memória no *stack* para guardar o tipo.

### Inferência

Tipagem estática não significa que todos os tipos precisam ser declarados explicitamente. É comum, na maioria das situações, que o compilador consiga inferir o tipo de uma variável de acordo com sua atribuição ou até mesmo sua utilização (menos comum).

A grande vantagem da tipagem estática está mais no fato que a variável não pode mudar seu tipo. Isto realmente ajuda muito o desenvolvimento. Ter que escrever o tipo explicitamente ajuda pouco ou nada. Alguns acham que fica mais legível quando o tipo é escrito, outros acham que é apenas deficiência do compilador.

Então é possível ter uma "linguagem estática" que usa tipagem implícita reduzindo parcialmente a cerimônia que estas linguagens costumam ter.

### [Hack](https://hacklang.org/)

O PHP possui a possibilidade de fazer uma verificação de tipos antes da execução mas isto ajuda pouco porque a linguagem costuma ser executada de forma interpretada e principalmente porque ela não pode verificar todos os tipos, todas as situações, portanto você não tem segurança alguma. A segurança é definida pelo elo mais fraco. Durante a execução tudo é dinâmico.

Não conheço a linguagem Hack o suficiente para dizer como ela funciona mas parece que ela possui tipagem estática.

Eventualmente pode-se usar o tipo `mixed` que é aquela estrutura de dados que permitirá que qualquer dado seja guardado ali. É provável que o compilador trate este tipo de forma diferente. O programa trata dados de forma dinâmica por exceção, o programador diz que ali tudo pode acontecer porque é isto que ele quer.

Por várias razões parece que Hack é o PHP que bebe na água do C#, me parece que o `mixed` se comporta como o `dynamic` do C#.

### Vantagens e desvantagens

Muitas vezes as vantagens e desvantagens variam de acordo com os olhos de quem vê. Programadores discordam do que realmente seja uma vantagem, até porque quase tudo é uma questão de *[trade-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade-off)*, então [é mais fácil falar em diferenças. Algumas delas podem ser:

| Tipagem estática | Tipagem dinâmica |
| --- | --- |
| Descobre erros antes | Descobre erros no último momento |
| O código costuma ser mais legível. Os tipos aparecem no código ou o IDE consegue mostrar | O programador precisa entender e documentar o código para saber os tipos e nunca é garantido |
| Fornece melhor semântica para o código | A tipagem funciona mais como um mecanismo |
| Fornece melhor performance na maioria dos casos | A performance é inferior |
| Segurança | Concisão |
| Qualquer alteração no problema exige mudança no código | Alterações podem ser assimiladas sem alteração no código específico |
| Ferramentas de desenvolvimento possuem mais informações e podem ajudar mais o programador | É dificil ou impossível criar/usar determinadas ferramentas que ajudam o programador |
| Regras do objeto são bem definidas e fixas | Regras variam com o estado do objeto |
| Facilita a formalização | Facilita o experimento |
| Rigidez | Flexibilidade |
| Mais difícil de aprender e usar | Mais difícil de manutenção |
| Reduz a necessidade de testes | Exige testes em cima dos tipos |
| Reutilização de código é mais complicada | Reutilização de código é mais arriscada |
| Metaprogramação é complicada | Metaprogramação é mais fácil |
| Facilita grandes programas | Facilita pequenos programas |
| São consideradas tirânicas (*fun*) | São consideradas subversivas (*fun*) |

As principais vantagens das "linguagens estáticas" são a **segurança**, **performance** e **auxílio em tempo de desenvolvimento** (refatoração, *completação* de código, informação auxiliar, cobertura de código etc.).

As "linguagens dinâmicas" são **flexíveis**, **rápidas para prototipar**, **concisas**.

É bom entender que os *bugs* mais complicados continuam complicados igualmente nas duas tipagens.

Certamente há uma vantagem nas "linguagens dinâmicas" quando se pensa no desenvolvimento da própria linguagem. Definir a linguagem e criar uma implementação básica é muito mais simples que uma "linguagem estática". Porém para criar uma implementação poderosa, que possa resolver algumas das suas desvantagens, se torna um trabalho dificílimo. Até hoje ninguém resolveu todas desvantagens.

### Tipagem forte e fraca

Algumas vezes estes conceitos são confundidos com tipagem forte e fraca. Isto se explica em parte porque a força da tipagem não é bem definida e não é universalmente aceita.

Tipagem forte costuma ser a característica que não permite um mesmo dado ser tratado como se fosse de outro tipo. É muito comum linguagens estáticas terem tipagem forte. Mas existem exceções.

Isto dá mais robustez ao código.

C, por exemplo, permite que um dado seja acessado/interpretado como se fosse outro. Pode, por exemplo:

- Gravar um `int` e acessá-lo como se fosse um ponteiro.
- Gravar um `float` e acessar como se fosse um `int`. É certo que o resultado será catastrófico neste caso, mas é possível.
- Obter um 0 e ser considerado falso ou outros números (não importa de que tipo) serem interpretados como verdadeiro em operações que exigem um booleano.
- Gravar dois `short` em sequência e ler como um `int`. Provavelmente nada útil será obtido mas é possível.
- Gravar "SOpt" e ler isto como se fosse um `int`, sei lá porque.

C é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca. C++ também, apesar dela tentar reforçar um estilo onde isto não seja tão usado.

Os compiladores de C/C++ tentam evitar que isto seja usado abusivamente.

Daí concluímos que segurança de tipos não é uma característica inerente de linguagens ditas estáticas. A segurança pode ser quebrada por outros fatores. *Type safety* é outro conceito diferente que pode ser confundido erroneamente com tipagem forte e tipagem estática.

Muitas "linguagens dinâmicas" possuem tipagem forte, mas outras possuem tipagem fraca, normalmente criando **coerções implícitas**. É comum existir coerção em algumas situações sob regras definidas. Exemplo: `"1" == 1` é verdadeiro e `1 + "1"` dá `"11"`.

A coerção implícita tem a vantagem de tornar o código ligeiramente mais curto. Isto costuma ser característica de linguagens de *script*, onde o tamanho do código faz diferença. Então, linguagens feitas para desenvolver aplicações, em oposição à *scripts*, não deveriam ter esta característica (*hello* PHP).

A definição destes termos não ajudam muito e dizer que uma linguagem é fracamente ou fortemente tipada de forma exclusiva também não costuma ser verdade.

De forma geral podemos dizer algo assim:

- **Variável tem** tipo => tipagem **estática**
- **Variável sem** tipo => tipagem **dinâmica**
- **Valor tem** tipo => tipagem **forte**
- **Valor sem** tipo => tipagem **fraca**

### Linguagens de *script*

Cada vez mais fica difícil definir linguagens de *script*. Elas costumam ser dinâmicas mas nada impede que sejam estáticas.

A tipagem dinâmica dá mais flexibilidade e ajuda fazer aplicações pequenas rapidamente. Estas linguagens costumam exigir pouca cerimônia e a tipagem dinâmica provê pouca cerimônia na tipagem. Mas é mais uma questão de adequação do que uma exigência.

Linguagens dinâmicas costumam executar mais de forma interpretada do que compilada e é outro fator indireto que ajuda a serem usadas para fazer *scripts*. Mas é apenas um facilitador, novamente, não é uma exigência.

Nenhuma linguagem quer perder espaço por isso cada vez mais as linguagens (de tipagem) estáticas permitem características de tipagem dinâmicas, reflexão, concisão, e execução de forma simplificada (ilusão de interpretação). Assim elas podem ser consideradas de *script* também, apesar de não ser seu foco principal.

Além da adequação, a característica de *script* está mais ligada à implementação do que à linguagem em si.

### Uma reflexão

Se uma linguagem permite que seus tipos estáticos possuam valores inválidos ou que não correspondem ao que se espera neste tipo, um `null` por exemplo, ela ainda tem tipagem estática? Parece que sim, mas há dúvida se deveriam. Quebra a segurança de tipos e de uma certa forma pode ser interpretado como o dado podendo ter dois tipos. Obriga uma verificação em *runtime* para garantir que não haverá problemas com o tipo.

### Qual é melhor?

A pergunta que não quer e provavelmente nunca vai calar é: **qual é melhor?**

É óbvio que não há universalmente uma melhor que a outra. Sempre podemos falar o clichê que existe uma ferramenta melhor para um problema.

Na prática eu vejo que a escolha recai, na maioria das vezes, em gosto e experiência. E isto é bom. Eu costumo dizer que antes de escolher a melhor ferramenta para o problema, escolha algo que você saiba e se sente confortável em usar: [**"a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você sabe usar"**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/09/01/language-wars/). É a velha disputa entre engenheiros que querem que tudo seja perfeito e administradores que querem que venha o melhor resultado. Uma serra elétrica corta madeira mais rápido e com mais precisão. Um marceneiro de fim de semana pode se machucar com uma serra elétrica.

Claro que há casos que tecnicamente uma é melhor que a outra mas isto está cada vez mais sutil.

Minha observação pessoal é que programadores de "linguagens dinâmicas" costumam pensar menos no problema e criam *designs* excessivamente simplificados trazendo problemas futuros. Mas há casos que um *design* melhor não é vantagem.

Por outro lado vejo que programadores de "linguagens estáticas" tendem a pensar demais nos problemas e criam *designs* excessivamente complicados sem trazer muitas vantagens futuras e não resolvendo todos os problemas futuros.

Note que isto não define a qualidade do programador e muito menos que 100% dos programadores são assim em 100% dos casos. Há casos que o oposto acontece. E deveria mesmo. Quando se programa em "linguagens dinâmicas" o planejamento antecipado costuma ser mais importante.

Não posso afirmar que a tipagem em si seja responsável pela tendência (se ela for verdadeira). Pode ser o tipo de programador que a tipagem atrai. É o surfista indo ao mar com ondas e não o mar com ondas fazendo o sujeito virar surfista. Talvez as pessoas escolham a tipagem pelos motivos errados.

O que eu vejo acontecer muito é que programadores que usam "linguagens estáticas" não usam as facilidades dinâmicas existentes nestas linguagens a não ser que não tenha outro jeito. E os programadores de "linguagens dinâmicas" acham que verificar os contratos nunca deveriam ser feitos dentro do código (de fato estas linguagens não costumam fornecer facilidades para isto). Não sei se deveria ser assim.

[PDF com algo mais formalizado para ler](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Elopes/teaching/inf212W12/readings/rdl04meijer.pdf). E uma [publicação](https://tratt.net/laurie/research/pubs/html/tratt__dynamically_typed_languages/) bem completa e aparentemente muito bem fundamentada.

Veja também: [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Comment: Um comentário sobre a questão da performance: nem sempre as otimizações no caso estático serão melhores que no caso dinâmico. Um exemplo é o JIT da JVM, que chega a **desfazer** várias otimizações que ocorreram na fase de compilação para fazer otimizações *melhores* na fase de [pré-]execução. ([fonte](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.br/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html); pode ter *bias*) Mas concordo quando diz "pela dificuldade isto normalmente não é feito com eficácia".

Comment: Dei uma melhorada. Eu gosto muito deste artigo e já me inspirou bastante. O problema é que na prática é muito difícil alcançar tudo o que ele diz. Curiosamente é mais fácil otimizar em cima do código fonte mesmo. Implementações JITadas de JS e Lua fazem em cima do fonte e conseguem resultados bem razoáveis. Como você entende os formalismos melhor que eu, sua resposta acabou ajudando melhorar a minha :)

Comment: Outro complemento: "estrutura [de memória] que permita ter vários tipos" não é o único *overhead* da tipagem dinâmica - há também a questão do despacho de métodos ([*method dispatch*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1805510/520779)). Se uma função está sobrecarregada para vários tipos (i.e. polimórfica), uma análise estática consegue determinar qual a implementação correta a se usar e linkar o código ainda na fase de compilação. Já uma dinâmica [sem características estáticas opcionais] precisaria em tempo de execução escolher qual o método correto a ser chamado conforme o tipo do valor da variável.

Comment: Aliás, eu acho essa questão mais significativa que a outra: mesmo linguagens estáticas como Java ainda guardam - junto com o objeto - uma referência para sua classe (é isso que permite que se faça reflexão). E no fim das contas, é o *overhead* na representação **dos dados** que conta. Não faz muita diferença se **as variáveis** gastam um pouquinho a mais de memória ou a menos, pois com a exceção de chamadas recursivas profundas a memória gasta pelo código é pequena em relação à gasta pelas estruturas de dados.

Comment: Sem querer me estender muito, concordo com quase tudo. É possível que eu tenha usado uma outra nomenclatura mas é isto. Eu acho que este assunto ainda dá p/ render muito. Ontem mesmo acabei explicando algumas coisas desta pergunta para uma pessoa que daria outra pergunta :)

Comment: @Maniero, onde você viu que C é fracamente tipada? Pergunto isso, porque em alguns lugares diz que é tipagem fraca e em outros diz que é forte.  Esse post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430182/is-c-strongly-typed por exemplo, mostra que essa questão divide opiniões. Você teria algum material mais confiável para confirmar essa dúvida?

Comment: @FagnerFonseca as pessoas confundem os termos. É extremamente comum. Leu tudo da resposta? Eu falo disto. Em comentário fica difícil falar disto, eu poderia responder em uma pergunta. Em resumo, se um tipo de dado pode se passar por outro a linguagem é fracamente tipada, e isso é o q C mais faz. `char` é tanto um caractere, quanto um número. Alguns tipos se confundem com ponteiros, qualquer porcaria que coloque na memória pode ser interpretada com um dado de um tipo. Isso é tipagem fraca. Mas as variáveis são sempre do mesmo tipo, isso é tipagem estática.

Answer (score 25):

> Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem estática e dinâmica?

Não existe o conceito de "linguagem estática" ou "linguagem dinâmica". O que [o artigo original em inglês](https://code.facebook.com/posts/264544830379293/hack-a-new-programming-language-for-hhvm/?_fb_noscript=1) fala - e que a tradução em português falhou em expressar - é em linguagens com **sistema de tipos** estático vs. dinâmico.

> Traditionally, **dynamically typed** languages allow for rapid development but sacrifice the ability to catch errors early and introspect code quickly, particularly on larger codebases. Conversely, **statically typed** languages provide more of a safety net, but often at the cost of quick iteration. We believed there had to be a sweet spot.

Em um sistema de tipos estático, cada variável possui um tipo (classe, domínio), e o compilador tenta assegurar que somente valores daquele tipo sejam atribuídos à variável - e que somente operações aplicáveis àquele tipo sejam chamadas tendo a variável como parâmetro. Se uma variável não possui o tipo correto (i.e. idêntico ao esperado ou subtipo do mesmo), a única maneira de utilizá-la naquele contexto é através de uma conversão de tipo explícita (*cast*).

Em geral isso implica em declarar o tipo de toda variável, membro, parâmetro ou valor de retorno, mas isso não é sempre verdade. Linguagens que utilizam **inferência de tipo** permitem que em certas circunstâncias a declaração de tipo seja omitida, e o compilador tenta descobrir qual é o tipo correto baseado no contexto onde a variável foi criada. Um exemplo é a declaração `var` do C#.

Já em um sistema de tipos dinâmico, as variáveis não possuem tipos. Os **valores**, é claro, continuam tendo um tipo - seja um tipo primitivo, uma instância de uma classe, uma "lista de propriedades", etc. Mas uma vez que uma variável guarda referência para um valor, essa referência pode ser usada em qualquer contexto e servir de parâmetro para qualquer operação - é responsabilidade do programador garantir que somente valores do tipo certo sejam usados (seria mais preciso dizer: do *domínio* certo; pois a tipagem dinâmica permite por exemplo que se crie funções que aceitem mais de um tipo diferente como parâmetro - e se comporte de forma diferente dependendo do valor recebido).

> Vantagens e Desvantagens

As linguagens com tipos dinâmicos tendem a ser mais concisas, pois ou se usa uma palavra-chave simples para toda variável (ex.: o `var` do JavaScript) ou não se usa palavra-chave alguma ao se criá-la (ex.: Python). Isso faz bastante diferença em particular quando os tipos possuem nomes longos (ex.: `VirtualMachineDeviceRuntimeInfo`) ou quando - se fosse uma tipagem estática - genéricos estão envolvidos (ex.: `HashMap<Integer,List<String>>`).

Note que com inferência de tipos pode-se reter [parcialmente] essa vantagem sem abrir mão da tipagem estática.

Por outro lado, linguagens com tipos estáticos tendem a "proteger mais o programador de si mesmo". Em vez de depender do programador ser cuidadoso para sempre chamar a operação certa com o valor certo, o próprio compilador se certifica que o tipo está correto e - se não estiver - gera um erro antes mesmo do programa estar em execução. Pelo menos essa é a teoria; na prática, é inviável se usar um sistema de tipos restrito a ponto de nunca aceitar *nada* que não seja parte do domínio (ex.: o tipo `int` pode ser usado como denominador de uma divisão? Não se seu valor for zero...) - e linguagens com tipos mais "completos" tendem a ser progressivamente mais difíceis de se usar na prática (ex.: Haskell).

Essas são as principais vantagens de cada uma (e correspondentemente desvantagens da outra). De resto, há muita opinião envolvida, e fica difícil argumentar objetivamente. De minha parte, eu enxergo o tipo como um **meta-dado**, e acho que é desejável que uma linguagem dê suporte não somente a esse mas também a outros meta-dados (programação por contrato) - porém de forma **opcional**.

> Pode-se dizer que as linguagens de script são sempre dinâmicas e vice-versa?

Não. Esses conceitos são ortogonais. Ser "de script" ou "*standalone*" não tem relação alguma com a tipagem estática ou dinâmica, bem como não há relação entre estas e: 1) compilada vs. interpretada; 2) [tipos fortes ou fracos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing); 3) nível de abstração alto ou baixo; etc.

Se há uma correlação entre linguagem de script e tipos dinâmicos isso provavelmente é devido às vantagens e desvantagens citadas acima: deseja-se que o esforço para se produzir um script para operar/automatizar um sistema seja pequeno, e em geral não há uma fase distinta de compilação vs. execução (no sentido que, uma vez que o script está pronto, espera-se que ele execute imediatamente - em produção).

Por outro lado, quando se usa uma linguagem *standalone* para se **construir** um sistema, o código normalmente passa por diversas iterações de compilação, testes, refatoração, etc - de modo que essa "rapidez" em colocar o código em execução não é assim tão crítica. Nesse caso, um compilador mais eficaz em encontrar erros se mostra uma característica mais desejável.

Apesar dessa correlação, exceções existem para ambos os lados. Aliás, a própria classificação de uma linguagem como sendo ou não "de script" não é uma coisa tão bem delineada: veja por exemplo que o C já foi considerado "a linguagem de script do Unix"... E JavaScript já não é só "a linguagem de script do browser": vide seu uso no lado servidor (node.js), e em outros contextos.

Answer (score 2):

1. Numa linguagem de tipagem estática o tipo é definido em tempo de compilação, já a dinâmica é definida em tempo de execução. Em C, que é uma linguagem de tipagem estática, por exemplo, você define uma variável indicando explicitamente o seu tipo. Se você tentar atribuir um valor a essa variável incompatível com o tipo definido, o compilador irá acusar um erro. Já numa linguagem de tipagem dinâmica, como JavaScript, para criar uma variável, é usada uma palavra-chave reservada "var" e dependendo do valor que está sendo atribuído a essa variável, por baixo dos panos, o tipo será definido.
2. A vantagem de uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica seria a velocidade na codificação, sem se preocupar muito com os tipos. Um possível problema seriam em operações entre tipos que contêm valores incompatíveis para determinadas operações. O resultado só seria descoberto em tempo de execução, ou seja, se existir um erro, dependendo do tipo de erro, você tem que está no local certo e na hora certa para perceber que ele está lá.
3. Acho que não existe uma regra. A resposta para essa pergunta pode estar nos compiladores e interpretadores. Compiladores gostam de tipagem estática; interpretadores, de tipagem dinâmica.