# Prolog possui tipagem estática ou dinâmica?

Tags: característica-linguagem, tipagem, prolog

Embora eu esteja bem familiarizado com o conceito de [tipos estáticos vs. dinâmicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/215) - podendo facilmente reconhecer se uma determinada linguagem se enquadra em um ou no outro - eu nunca soube responder com exatidão qual a tipagem de Prolog: se é uma, outra, ambas ou nenhuma das duas...

O artigo sobre Prolog na [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Tipos_de_dados) diz:

> Prolog não emprega tipos de dados do mesmo modo que as linguagens de programação mais comuns normalmente fazem. Todos os dados são tratados como sendo de um único tipo, Termo, cuja natureza depende da forma como esse termo foi declarado. Ou seja, os elementos léxicos utilizados na sua declaração determinam se esse termo será um número, um texto, uma variável, uma estrutura complexa e assim por diante.

Isso não esclareceu muita coisa... Tipo, qual a diferença entre dizer "tudo é um Termo em Prolog" vs. "tudo é um Objeto em JavaScript"? Obviamente, *existem* tipos em Prolog - no mínimo há a diferença entre Átomos, Variáveis e Termos Compostos. Ou estou enganado, e isso não pode ser considerado um "tipo"? A Wikipedia em inglês [afirma a mesma coisa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Data_types):

> Prolog's single data type is the term. Terms are either atoms, numbers, variables or compound terms.

De todo modo, a forma como os dados são usados em Prolog é substancialmente diferente de tudo o mais que já estudei (mesmo linguagens imperativas e funcionais têm muito mais em comum entre si do que entre elas e a programação em lógica).

#### Exemplo 1:

```
foo(42).
foo('bar').
foo([_,_,_|_]).
```

Aqui eu defini uma função (estritamente falando, uma relação) `foo` que tem sucesso se seu parâmetro for o número `42`, a string `bar` ou uma lista com pelo menos 3 elementos. E falha caso contrário. Só. Isso não quer dizer que ela "aceita os tipos inteiro, string e lista" - na verdade ela aceita **qualquer coisa**:

```
?- foo(42).
true.
?- foo(10).
false.
?- foo(1.23).
false.
?- foo([1,2,3,4,5]).
true.
?- foo([1,2]).
false.
?- foo(qualquer_coisa).
false.
?- foo(QualquerCoisa).
QualquerCoisa = 42 ;
QualquerCoisa = bar ;
QualquerCoisa = [_G3014, _G3017, _G3020|_G3021].
```

Esse "aceitar qualquer coisa" é que me confunde: normalmente uma linguagem com tipos dinâmicos verifica em tempo de execução se determinado valor pode ser usado numa operação X, lançando uma exceção caso um valor do tipo incorreto esteja sendo usado. Mas como aqui não há verificação alguma - todas as operações são aplicáveis a todos os valores e tipos, e a unificação (comparação, casamento, *matching*) *sempre* é realizada - estaria correta a afirmação que "só existe um único tipo"?

#### Exemplo 2:

```
bar(X,Y,Z) :-
    X = Y,
    foo(X),
    X = Z.
```

*Parece* que estamos atribuindo a `X` primeiro o valor de `Y` e depois o valor de `Z`, mas em Prolog não existe o conceito de "atribuir um valor a uma variável", apenas existe a unificação. Por exemplo:

```
?- bar(X, [1,A,3], [B,2,C]).
X = [1, 2, 3],
A = 2,
B = 1,
C = 3.
```

Mas isso **não significa** que `X` possui apenas um tipo, imutável:

```
?- bar(X,_,Z), writeln(X), Z = 'bar'.
42
bar
X = Z, Z = bar ;
[_G112,_G115,_G118|_G119]
false.
```

Em cada "galho" da árvore de busca, `X` possuía um único valor (na primeira era `42`, e a chamada retornou `false`; na segunda era `bar`, e a chamada retornou `true`; ao pedir uma alternativa, na terceira era `[_,_,_|_]` e a chamada retornou `false`). Mas durante o retrocesso `X` deixou de ter um valor numérico para ter um valor string. Ele mudou de valor, mudou de tipo. Isso significa que a tipagem é dinâmica?

#### Exemplo 3:

```
distancia(ponto(X1,Y1), ponto(X2,Y2), D) :-
    !,
    D is sqrt((X1-X2)**2 + (Y1-Y2)**2).
distancia(_,_,_) :- throw('Tipo inválido!').
```

Ao contrário do exemplo 1, aqui uma exceção será lançada se o primeiro ou o segundo parâmetro for [concreto e] de um tipo diferente de `ponto`. Caso contrário a função terá sucesso ou falhará (i.e. comportamento normal, não excepcional). A princípio eu *poderia* (mas não sou obrigado a) programar nesse estilo o tempo todo - ou mesmo criar uma "macro" ([`term_expansion`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_expansion/2)) para "traduzir" meu programa inteiro para este estilo, como se fosse uma "ajuda" pro compilador. Isso significaria que embora Prolog não **seja** estaticamente tipada, ela **suporta** programação via tipagem estática?

- Esclarecendo: no exemplo acima a verificação de fato ocorre em tempo de execução, sendo um caso claro de tipagem dinâmica; entretanto, sendo Prolog uma linguagem [homoicônica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), criar macros desse tipo é uma tarefa simples, poderia-se não só fazer a tradução como também exigir que cada variável tivesse seu tipo declarado - tudo isso sem deixar de "ser Prolog" (i.e. não estaria "modificando a linguagem" nem "criando um dialeto" - faria isso dentro das capacidades nativamente suportadas pela linguagem).

  E essas macros executam em tempo de carga (parte do processo de compilação), não de execução; é uma verificação feita em cima da estrutura estática do programa, não de seus valores em tempo de execução. Por isso, no meu entendimento, isso conta como tipagem estática. ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/bpUrr2), [exemplo](https://ideone.com/IUZvLg))

#### Pra não ficar muito amplo ou baseado em opiniões...

Estou buscando uma resposta que analise essas características mencionadas de acordo com a definição do que são tipos estáticos e dinâmicos. Sem desviar muito pro "território cinza" (ex.: Java é estaticamente tipada, mas usando reflexão pode-se programar de forma dinâmica; entretanto, ninguém em sã consciência usaria isso como argumento para contestar a classificação de Java como estática...).

Em particular, quero entender se uma tipagem que *não é* estática automaticamente é dinâmica, ou se existe uma terceira classificação (ou além). Ou se, de fato, pela forma como Prolog trata dos dados pode-se considerar que ela "não emprega tipos".

P.S. [Exemplos acima no ideone](https://ideone.com/34j7A3) (adaptados).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tipagem usada no *Prolog* é dinâmica da mesma forma que a da maioria das linguagens dinâmicas como por exemplo *Python*. (E sim, todas as linguagens não estáticas são dinâmicas desde que haja tipagem de variáveis)

**Estendendo um pouco para a força na tipagem das variáveis:**

*Prolog* é uma linguagem na qual a maioria dos casos não há tipos definidos, ou seja pode passar qualquer tipo para qualquer predicado e normalmente o pior caso é que tal predicado (proposição) será falsa.

Por *Prolog* aceitar a maioria dos tipos em praticamente todos os casos tornam uma linguagem mais fracamente tipada que *Python*. No entanto os predicados aritméticos como `=:=` esperam números e provam que há tipos no *Prolog*. (logo se há tipagem deve ser dinâmica ou estática)

Para mais detalhes sugiro que leia essa comparação: [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21508/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1tica-e-din%C3%A2mica/21513#21513)

Comment: De fato, a parte de aritmética assume mesmo um tipo numérico distinto. Quanto a ser fracamente tipada, não sei se concordo: Python também aceita qualquer valor em qualquer chamada (na hora de usar, sim, pode ter uma exceção), e ambas rejeitam se o número de parâmetros estiver incorreto. Da mesma forma, ambas rejeitam operações em tipos incompatíveis (ex.: `10 + "20"`). Além disso, dependendo da forma como o predicado está definido, a cabeça não unifica se o termo de entrada for incompatível. Ou seja, em relação à *força*, eu não classificaria Prolog como "fracamente tipada".

Comment: @mgibsonbr, note a expressão usada: "**mais** *fracamente tipada*"