# Nomenclatura ou linguajar no lambda

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda, convenções-de-nome

Temos esta expressão:

```
var teste = meucotexto.minhatable.Where(x => x.meu_campo.....)
```

Como leio essa parte `x => x.meu_campo`

Leio "x está para x.meu_campo" ou "x de x.meu_campo" ou outra coisa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não acho que exista uma forma universalmente apropriada. Não precisamos nos manter a formalismos bobos só porque está certo. O importante é as pessoas se comunicarem eficientemente. É comum fazermos simplificações quando falamos ou até escrevemos certas coisas que estritamente estão erradas, mas que não causa grandes problemas. Dou um exemplo em [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). É comum todo mundo pronunciar a palavra "data" em inglês de forma errada sem causar problemas. Todo mundo entende que estamos falando de dados, de algo digital.

O importante é manter a consistência entre as pessoas que vão se comunicar.

## Vamos tentar achar uma forma legal.

Acho que as formas mais usadas, pelo menos em C#, é **"torna-se"**, **"transformado em"**, **"que venha ser"**. Se não me engano já ouvi o [Anders Hejlsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) pronunciando e indicando esta forma.

Também já vi o uso de **"de modo que"** ou **"de tal modo que"** ou mesmo **"tal que"**.

Outra possibilidade seria um **"indo para"** para indicar a passagem de parâmetro. Me parece um jeito menos formal. Curiosamente a Microsoft recomendava [isso no VS2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb397687(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mas desistiu de definir nas versões seguintes. Talvez possa usar **"passado para"**.

Talvez possa depender do que significa a *lambda* sendo usada. Veja o que um grande especialista, que sabe unir a teoria com a prática como poucos, [lê *lambdas* ao telefone](https://web.archive.org/web/20140508103603/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/16/reading-code-over-the-telephone.aspx).

Sua leitura não me parece ser correta porque não há relação direta entre elas. **"Está para"** costuma indicar proporcionalidade, o que não ocorre com *lambdas*. Mas não chega ser um completo absurdo. Se todo mundo que está se comunicando fala assim, que seja. O problema pode ocorrer quando se comunica externamente. Mas como poucas pessoas sabem o jeito certo de pronunciar, tanto faz. É possível que as pessoas se entendam mais pelo uso do que pela pronúncia.

Mas tem gente que lê "@" como "arroba" e não como "at" ou "em" como deveria ser. E "#" como "cerquinha" não importa o contexto, então se alguém ler "=>" como "seta" ou "seta dupla", ou "seta gorda", não me surpreenderia.

No seu exemplo eu leria: **"x torna-se x.meu_campo"** ou mais detalhadamente **"xis torna-se xis ponto meu campo"**. Mas você pode ler o texto em um contexto mais completo. Pode ler de forma a fazer sentido onde está sendo usado e talvez até esquecer que isto é uma *lambda*. A linha completa poderia ser lida como **"Em meu contexto.minhatebela onde x.meucampo for igual a valor tal"**. Isto faz sentido para você e para quem você está falando? Se não faz, procure o que faz e mantenha este padrão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Valeu, essas linhas que eu coloquei são apenas hipotéticas, não tenho uma forma de falar. Apenas leio e vejo o que é. Mas gostei do que li. Eu apenas fiz uma introdução.

Comment: Entendi, só quis ser completo.

Answer (score 7):

Deveria ler a relação de `x` com o `Where` e a `minhatable` e não a relação `x => x.meu_campo`.

Ou seja, tal como uma query SQL, leria, 'Por cada `x` em `minhatable` onde `x.meu_campo = algo`, faça algo'.