# Como simplificar o código com ForEach do List?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista

Como utilizar o `ForEach()` do `List` na implementação abaixo

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
        pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(){Nome = "José" , Sexo = "M"});
        pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(){Nome = "Pedro", Sexo = "M"});
        pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(){Nome = "João" , Sexo = "M"});
        pessoas.Add(new Pessoa(){Nome = "Maria", Sexo = "F"});

        bool temMulher = new VerificaSeHaMulher(pessoas).Verifica();
    }
}

class VerificaSeHaMulher
{
    List<Pessoa> pessoas;

    public VerificaSeHaMulher(List<Pessoa> pessoas)
    {
        this.pessoas = pessoas;
    }

    public bool Verifica()
    {
        foreach(Pessoa pessoa in pessoas)
          if(pessoa.Sexo.Equals("F"))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}

class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome;
    public string Sexo;
}
```

No caso, quero deixar mais limpa a implementação do método `Verifica`.

Comment: Tem algo específico que acha que está ruim? Parece que está bem simples. Há necessidade de ser uma classe? Nada errado com isto, desde que precise disto. Talvez esteja usando um *strategy pattern* ou variação dele em algum lugar. Mas se estiver usando por acidente, deveria simplificar isto mesmo. Fora isso eu só mudaria a sintaxe da comparação para não ficar com cara de Java. Onde *lambda* entra nessa estória?

Comment: Havia colocado o lambda por ignorância. Ajustei

Comment: A confusão faz sentido. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79894/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22265/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101

Comment: Uma opção para simplificar código é a utilização do resharper é um componente pago mais é bom para esse tipo de ajuda. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva, te aconselho à ler [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) e [Where is List<T>.ForEach()](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/758f7b98-e3ce-41e5-82a2-109f1df446c2/where-is-listtforeach?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu mudaria algumas coisas mais por estilo. Mas é o meu gosto, não quer dizer que é claramente melhor.

Fora isto eu pensaria se este método não deveria estar dentro de outra classe. Tem utilidade em usar desta forma, dependendo dos seus requisitos, mas se você não conseguir dizer qual o motivo disto ser uma classe, está enfeitando o pavão.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {   
        var pessoas = new List<Pessoa>() {
            new Pessoa() {Nome = "José" , Sexo = "M"},
            new Pessoa() {Nome = "Pedro", Sexo = "M"},
            new Pessoa() {Nome = "João" , Sexo = "M"},
            new Pessoa() {Nome = "Maria", Sexo = "F"}
        };
        bool temMulher = new VerificaSeHaMulher(pessoas).Verifica();
    }
}

class VerificaSeHaMulher {
    private readonly List<Pessoa> pessoas;
    public VerificaSeHaMulher(List<Pessoa> pessoas) => this.pessoas = pessoas;

    public bool Verifica() {
        foreach (var pessoa in pessoas) if (pessoa.Sexo == "F") return true;
        return false;
    }
}

class Pessoa {
    public string Nome;
    public string Sexo;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JxBbti). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hRLkMU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ForEach2.cs).

Se quiser usar LINQ basta fazer isto:

```
return pessoas.Any(p => p.Sexo == "F");
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/msNtHV).

[Documentação do `Any()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__).

Comment: Cara, era isso que eu precisava, obrigado.