# Qual é a finalidade do operador => no uso de listas?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, operadores

Qual é a finalidade do operador `=>` no uso de listas `List<T>`, estou começando a utilizar listas genéricas e me deparei com este operador, ele só é utilizado neste método `LISTA.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));` ?

Abaixo segue meu exemplo para ilustração:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ListaGenericaCollection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> LISTA = new List<string>();

            string opcao = "1";

            while (opcao.Equals("1")) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Digite um nome para inserir na lista: ");
                string nome = Console.ReadLine();

                LISTA.Add(nome);

                Console.WriteLine("Deseja inserir outro nome na lista? 1-SIM | 2-NAO:");
                opcao = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            LISTA.Sort();
            Console.WriteLine("A lista tem " + LISTA.Count + " itens:");
            LISTA.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Também reparei que a variável `i` não foi especificada um tipo de dado para ela, ela é um tipo genérico?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nenhuma. Isto é usado para criar uma *lambda*, que é um função anônima. Isso pode ser usado em qualquer situação que se espera uma função/método anônimo. Não está relacionado com a lista.

```
i => Console.WriteLine(i)
```

`i` é o parâmetro que a *lambda* receberá e o `Console.WriteLine(i)` é o corpo dela que será executada. Neste caso específico o método `ForEach()` chamará esta *lambda* para cada item da lista passando o item para `i`.

O tipo de `i` é inferido pelo compilador através da [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) [`ForEach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_ForEach_System_Action__0__).

Uma outra forma de escrever o mesmo:

```
(i) => { Console.WriteLine(i); }
```

Jeito antigo usando [`delegate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
delegate(string i) { Console.WriteLine(i); };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Lambda/Basic.cs).

Isso é usado quando precisamos de funções chamadas *callback*, onde você passa uma função para ser executada, ao invés de passar o resultado da execução.

[Pergunta com mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

[Nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22265/101).

[Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14212/101).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

No C# 6 esta sintaxe pode ser usada em métodos comuns dentro de uma classe. Mas apesar da sintaxe ser a mesma, neste caso não seria uma *lambda*. Ou seja, não é um ponteiro para uma função que será armazenado em uma variável para ser chamado quando precisar. Exemplo:

```
public void Imprime(object obj) => Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

Comment: Só um pequeno detalhe. No último exemplo, o parâmetro de `WriteLine` deveria ser `obj`.

Comment: Claro, maldito ^C ^V :)

Comment: Apenas para complementar, o apelido do "operador lambda" é *Fat Arrow* - Seta Gorda na tradução livre.

Answer (score 9):

O nome desta operação é *delegate*, e funciona como uma chamada para um predicado.

O código

```
LISTA.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Equivale a

```
foreach (var i in LISTA)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```