# Posso acessar uma variável (não array) em PHP usando índice 0 como se fosse um array?

Tags: php, array, variáveis

O caso é o seguinte, tenho uma função que caso aconteça uma coisa ela cria um *array* com *n* números `($x[n])` e caso aconteça outra ele armazena numa variável comum com mesmo nome `($x)`.

Eu sei que posso ao invés de armazenar as coisas numa *variável comum* `($x)`, poderia armazenar em um *array* com índice 0 `($x[0])`, mas enquanto escrevia o código eu me deparei com essa dúvida e achei que seria interessante compartilhar essa dúvida aqui.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
if (!isset($_POST['x']))
{
    $x = 1;
}
else
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
        $x[$i] = $i;
    }
}
echo $x[0]; // Se $_POST['x'] não existir, o número 1 será printado?
```

Esse bloco de código é apenas um exemplo, eu não utilizei essa lógica no meu programa, como eu disse foi apenas uma dúvida que me surgiu ao fazer algo parecido.

Então, alguém saberia me responder essa pergunta e se a resposta for negativa, o porquê de ela não funcionar?

Comment: Coloque o código para mostrar como está fazendo. Pode ser mais fácil visualizar sua intenção e bolar alguma solução. Coloque a geração do *array* ou variável escalar e como está consumindo isto. DE uma maneira geral a resposta é não só *arrays* - de todos os tipos, incluindo *strings* - possuem índice. O que não quer dizer que não pode ser feito de outra forma.

Comment: O código não é necessário, pois não utilizei isso. Foi apenas uma dúvida que tive enquanto estava desenvolvendo, mas vou editar com um exemplo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apenas *arrays* possuem índice, então só é possível acessar valores através de variáveis que sejam, de alguma forma, *arrays*. Variáveis escalares não podem ser acessadas por índices.

Só lembrando que existem dois tipos de *arrays*, não esqueça do *array* associativo. Também considere *strings* como *arrays*, afinal no fundo uma *string* é um *array* de caracteres. Então tecnicamente ele pode ser chamado de escalar, mas não se comporta como um tipo escalar.

Então no seu código, eventualmente, pode ser interessante ter um *array* ou um valor escalar atribuído para uma varável única, esta é uma das vantagens de [linguagens de tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). Mas para saber qual deve ser a forma de acessar o dado, antes deve-se testar o tipo da variável para tomar uma decisão apropriada de acordo com o resultado deste teste.

Seu código pode ser facilmente testado e dá para ver que o resultado não será o esperado quando o valor for escalar. Ele provavelmente considerará que está pegando um valor indefinido e não vai apresentar nada.

Answer (score 2):

Sim você pode acessar uma variável escalar(simples) como um índice desde que ela seja uma [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) isso retornará o caracter naquela posição. Esse comportamentão não é valido para os outros tipos como int, float, boolean.

```
$str = 'ola mundo';
echo $str[2]; // retorna somente a letra 'a'
```