# Variável do tipo Objeto dentro de uma classe

Tags: php

Não sei se é possível, mas gostaria de fazer como faço em `java` o seguinte código no `PHP`

em JAVA

```
public class Not_req {

    private Cabacelho_Req cab;
    private Requisicao req;

    public Cabacelho_Req getCab() {
        return cab;
    }

    public void setCab(Cabacelho_Req cab) {
        this.cab = cab;
    }
```

No `PHP` não consigo colocar em uma classe
em `PHP`

```
class Not_req {
    private Cabacelho_Req $cab;
    private Requisicao $req;

}
```

Em PHP isto fica errado. Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O PHP é uma linguagem com [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21513/4751), ou seja, diferente do Java não definimos o tipo da variável.

Para garantir o tipo da nossa propriedade utilizamos o [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php) juntamente com o encapsulamento.

Para obter o que você deseja faça assim:

```
public class Not_req {

    private $cab;
    private $req;

    public function getCab() {
        return $this->cab;
    }

    public function setCab(Cabacelho_Req $cab) {
        $this->cab = $cab;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado.