# Qual a diferença entre o conceito de tipagem estática e dinâmica e o conceito de fortemente e fracamente tipada?

Tags: python, tipagem

Existe certa confusão sobre o conceito de linguagens de programação com tipagem estática e dinâmica e o conceito de linguagens de programação fortemente e fracamente tipadas.

Por exemplo, pelo meu entender `Python` é uma linguagem com tipagem dinâmica, pois posso atribuir qualquer valor uma variável (`x` no exemplo):

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x = "teste"
>>>
```

Porém, `Python` também é uma linguagem fortemente tipada pois não posso fazer algo do tipo:

```
>>> x = "0"
>>> x += 1
Traceback <most recent call last>:
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't covert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Alguém poderia me explicar isso melhor?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/91)

Comment: Acho que podemos considerar duplicata. Leo Ribeiro, a resposta nesse link esclarece sua dúvida?

Comment: Acredito que não @bfavaretto, pois a própria resposta do link diz:
_A definição destes termos não ajudam muito e dizer que uma linguagem é fracamente ou fortemente tipada de forma exclusiva também não costuma ser verdade._

Comment: Mas isso não é justamente a resposta? O que falta lá pra esclarecer sua dúvida?

Comment: @LeoRibeiro considero duplicata. Ou então não está claro o que deseja. Lá tem toda informação que eu julgo ser necessária para esclarecer o tópico. Se tem algo mais específico que ainda tem dúvida, seja específico na pergunta. A resposta diz isto porque é isto mesmo. As coisas não são preto no branco. As linguagens não são puras. Hora ele pode se comportar de um jeito, hora de outro.

Comment: Entendi senhores. Acredito que podem retirar então.

Comment: A gente não apaga as duplicatas, apenas coloca esse aviso em cima apontando pra outra pergunta. As duplicatas são vistas como caminhos alternativos pra chegar às respostas. Manter duplicatas significa dar mais chance para as pessoas encontrarem as respostas que precisam via mecanismos de busca. Ah, e bem-vindo ao site! :)

Comment: Eu até poderia responder aqui e ganhar mais pontinhos, mas eu praticamente copiaria um parte do que está lá :)

Answer (score 4):

Liskov e Zilles definiram linguagens fortemente tipadas como aquelas onde um objeto, quando passado de uma função para outra, deve ter tipo compatível com aquele declarado na função que recebe o objeto.

Linguagens estáticas são linguagem que possuem tipagem estática, onde o tipo de uma variável não pode mudar. Uma linguagem estática não é necessariamente de tipagem forte onde o tipo **não** pode ser interpretado de formas diferentes.

Em C, por exemplo, que é linguagem estática, podemos interpretar um dado numa região de memória de formas diferentes quando usamos ponteiros.