# O que é estilo de tipagem?

Tags: c#, terminologia, tipagem, característica-linguagem

No Wikipedia, [na página sobre C#](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp) diz sobre o "estilo de tipagem" da linguagem:

> estática e dinâmica, forte, segura e insegura, nominativa,
>   parcialmente inferente

O que é estilo de tipagem? O que significam os termos citados acima?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96722/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-conceito-de-tipagem-est%C3%A1tica-e-din%C3%A2mica-e-o-conceito-de

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Na verdade, o termo mais adequado é o sistema de tipos adotado pela linguagem. Cada classificação possui pelo menos duas formas, e em geral um se opõe ao outro, mas é possível adotar ambos com pelo menos um deles opcional.

## Estática X Dinâmica (presença)

É a capacidade de um dado ou variável/constante ser verificado em tempo de compilação se é o que se espera naquele contexto. Também tem a ver com a capacidade de mudança do tipo da variável depois de declarado. Na tipagem estática não pode ser trocado e tudo é verificado em tempo de compilação, já na dinâmica isso não ocorre e é necessário ter certeza que está tudo certo, em muitos casos verificando antes de usar um determinado dado.

C# usa tipagem estática, mas opcionalmente pode usar dinâmica com [`dynamic`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12728/101). Isso foi abordado em [Por que os outros tipos de variáveis não são substituídos por dynamic em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161729/101).

Já foi respondido em profundidade em [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101)

## Forte X Fraca (permissividade)

Não é uma classificação muito oficial e mesmo a sua definição é confusa, tanto que frequentemente é confundida com estática e dinâmica, mas é um erro achar que é a mesma coisa.

A tipagem forte impede um dado de um tipo ser tratado como se fosse de outro tipo, enquanto a fraca permite.

É comum existirem ambos na linguagem, mas a classificação acaba se dando pelo que é predominante, talvez até mesmo por não ter uma definição formal.

C# usa tipagem forte e fraca na verdade. Um `short` pode ser tratado como `int`. Frequentemente um tipo qualquer pode ser tratado como `string`, qualquer tipo pode ser tratado como `object` ou um ascendente direto ou indireto, como é o caso do próprio `object`. Mas como é feito de forma segura, em geral considera-se apenas que a forte é adotada.

[Os termos já foram respondidos em profundidade em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

## Segura X Insegura (robustez)

Aqui determina se um tipo pode ser usado de forma errada ou não. Não necessariamente se é o tipo certo ou não, pode ser qualquer forma de erro. Nem sempre conseguimos classificar a linguagem como sendo uma forma ou outra.

Quase toda linguagem possui alguma insegurança de tipo. Em geral as linguagens se autodenominam seguras por uma questão de marketing. A classificação acaba sendo subjetiva. Se o programa pode quebrar sem maiores explicações, pode haver problemas de segurança pelo uso inadequado dos tipos, ou outras falhas, então ele não é *type safety*. É muito difícil fazer uma linguagem que garanta isso sempre, e ainda mais sendo flexível o suficiente para se tornar viável.

É um erro achar que segurança de tipo e tipagem forte são a mesma coisa.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327538/101) e [ainda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249099/101).

## Nominal X Estrutural (morfologia)

Estamos falando da capacidade de identificar qual é o tipo do dado pelo seu nome manifesto ou pela sua estrutura, ou seja pelos seus membros.

C# usa a tipagem nominal, porém cada vez mais o estrutural está sendo adotado. Já ocorria com tipos anônimos e mais agora com tuplas que são inerentemente anônimas.

Mas alguém pode contestar isso dizendo que na verdade os tipos são sempre nominais e o C# usa apenas um truque. Aí eu não sei qual é a linha traçada porque tudo o que vemos em linguagens de alto nível são truques para não expor o mecanismo exato.

## Manifesta X Inferente (aparência)

Estamos falando de como os tipos são declarados. Se eles devem ser explícitos, ou seja, precisa escrever o nome do tipo para declará-lo. Se eles podem ser implícitos, ou seja, o compilador consegue detectar o tipo pela sua atribuição ou uso.

Tipos estruturais obviamente só podem ser inferidos.

## Reificado X Apagado (preservação)

Quando a informação do tipo fica presente no *runtime* ele é reificado. Mas a informação pode ser apagada porque não tem serventia para o *runtime* (provavelmente por limitação) e trata tudo de forma universal.

C# consegue inferir pela atribuição de variáveis locais, desde que seja fácil detectar que algo é inambíguo, então não detecta o tipo de um [delegado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101). Em outros locais e situações ele não detecta, especialmente pelo uso. C# detecta o tipo de retorno e parâmetros de *lambdas*, o que dificulta a inferência do delegado. A inferência das variáveis locais é detectada por [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

O estilo de tipagem nada mais é do que a classificação do sistema de tipos de alguma linguagem, podendo ser a união de mais de uma das categorias:

### **Tipagem forte**

Quase um sinônimo para tipagem segura. Os tipos de todas as coisas precisam ser respeitados e você não pode burlar qualquer tipo (é aquilo e pronto), Haskell e Python se enquadram na definição.

### **Tipagem fraca**

É bem compreensível: você pode burlar o sistema de tipos, exemplo é converter um ponteiro do tipo struct Node para int, em C.

### **Tipagem estática**

Significa que toda a checagem de tipos é feita em tempo de compilação, um bom exemplo é a linguagem C, que consegue descobrir o tipo de todas as coisas antes de gerar o executável.

### Tipagem dinâmica

A checagem de tipos é feita em tempo de execução, Python é um bom exemplo.

### **Tipagem segura**

Sempre que você tentar usar um tipo incorreto em alguma ocasião o compilador/interpretador precisa tratar e te dar alguma mensagem de erro.

### **Tipagem nominativa**

Os tipos são equivalentes se seus nomes são iguais: int com int, float com float, struct ast com struct ast etc.

### **Parcialmente inferente**

Se diz respeito à habilidade da linguagem deduzir o tipo de algum elemento sem precisar que você especifique explicitamente.

Comment: Vitor, adicione isso lá na pagina do Wikipedia tmb. Será legal! :)