# Quais são as principais características da linguagem Go?

Tags: característica-linguagem, golang

Comecei a ouvir falar muito em *GoLang* e que está cada vez mais a ganhar terreno entre as linguagens de programação mais usadas.

Pelo que sei, acho que é uma linguagem de programação. Então,

- Quais as principais características?
- Posso programar e executar em qualquer sistema operacional?
- Como funcionam os tipos nela?
- Qual foi o intuito de sua criação?

<sup>Se alguém conseguir me dar uma ideia básica sobre a GoLang.</sup>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Quais as principais características?

Vou citar só o que é mais importante.

Ela é uma linguagem de alto nível, muito mais que C, de forma semelhante ao C#, por exemplo. É compilada e gera executável nativo.

Originalmente foi concebida para ser uma linguagem para desenvolvimento de sistemas e não tanto para aplicativos, mas isto não ocorreu de fato, então é de multipropósito e é usada em muitas coisas para web, embora possa ser usada para qualquer coisa.

Ela é do paradigma imperativo, essencialmente. É modular, possui encapsulamento e polimorfismo. Embora possa embarcar outro tipo em uma estrutura que está se criando não há mecanismo de herança, op que limita o polimorfismo. Ela evita recursos que a torne multiparadigma. Ela prefere os mecanismos mais básicos.

Ponteiros são expostos embora não possa usá-los livremente como ocorre em C. São mais como referências.

A sintaxe é sucinta como em Python, por isso atrai programadores desta que desejam mais performance. Programadores de JavaScript também tem gostado dela. É meio estranho, ela fica no meio termo entre uma linguagem de sistema (intenção original) e de *script* (como ela é realmente usada).

Possui coletor de lixo então não precisa se preocupar muito com o gerenciamento de memória. Tem as desvantagens disso também. Ela é rápida, mas não chega no nível de C.

Trabalha com uma forma fácil para lidar com processamento paralelo e concorrente ([Channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2)).

> Posso programar e executar em qualquer sistema operacional?

Não, nenhuma linguagem pode. Pode rodar em: FreeBSD 8-STABLE, Linux 2.6.23, Mac OS X 10.8, Windows XP e as versões superiores, claro. Há algum suporte para outros, mas não é oficial.

> Como funcionam os tipos nela?

Não tenho certeza o que quer saber, mas a [tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101) é estática, forte, segura, nominal e estrutural, manifesta ou inferente conforme a necessidade e gosto. Não há hierarquia de tipos.

Claro que é seguro até certo ponto. Como a linguagem não tem genéricos, a solução muitas vezes é produzir códigos menos seguros para evitar duplicação de esforços. Também dá para contestar a segurança quando há tipagem estrutural onde pode executar o que não se espera. Então ela tem um certo *feel* de linguagem dinâmica sem ter todas as vantagens disto.

[Há proposta para ter genéricos](https://blog.golang.org/why-generics) e há detratores. Eu já fui ferrenho defensor, mas dada a forma como as pessoas usam não sei se é uma boa ideia. Parece estar acontecendo uma *PHPzação* de Go. Na verdade, desde o início ela sofre de falta de identidade do que ela quer ser, mas parece que as pessoas a usam como linguagem de *script* (isso foi mudando aos poucos depois que respondi aqui), então *generics* não faz sentido, junto com outras coisas. Faz se considerar que tudo pensado originalmente para ela não é de *script*, portanto as pessoas que a usam como *script* estão com a ferramenta errada, mas não tem como brigar com isso, o mundo do TI está assim, popularidade conta mais que motivação técnica.

Algum tempo depois da resposta *generics* foi implementada e está sendo usada, fazendo a linguagem ser mais robusta e permitindo mais eficiência em alguns casos.

> Qual foi o intuito de sua criação?

Originalmente ser uma linguagem C melhor que o próprio C. Ser mais segura e mais poderosa com uma sintaxe melhor, com facilidades para o compilador resolver tudo rapidamente, sem contexto, com facilidades para analisar dependências, e de forma simples também para humanos, não pode se transformar em Java ou C++. Os criadores se recusam colocar algo que complique a linguagem e o compilador, o que é uma crítica que muitos fazem, já que isso impediu a criação de genéricos (agora tem. furaram a filosofia).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Conceptual.md).