# Qual a diferença entre Type-safe e Null-safe?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, kotlin, null

Estou escrevendo um artigo sobre Kotlin, e me deparei com esses tipos, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Qual a diferença entre Type-safe e Null-safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Type-safe*** é uma característica que um objeto sempre é do tipo esperado e o compilador consegue determinar se uma operação pode ser feita nele. Não haverá um comportamento indefinido se isso falhar, poderá haver erro ou alguma regra de como resolver a questão.

Em Kotlin a verificação é feita em tempo de compilação evitando problemas na execução e gasto de processamento. Mas a característica não exige que seja feito nesse momento.

Então você pode fazer um `indexOf()` em um objeto que seja uma *string*, mas não pode chamar esse método em um `Stream` por exemplo.

Não confundir com [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

***Null-safe*** (também conhecido como *void safety*) é a propriedade que garante que um objeto nunca é nulo, ou se for nulo exige-se o devido tratamento para não dar erro.

Novamente em Kotlin tudo feito em tempo de compilação, mesmo que não seja uma exigência para se definir assim.

Isso é interessante para evitar o chamado *billion-dollar mistake* que o [Tony Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.A.R._Hoare) se auto-crítica por ter inventado a possibilidade de objetos poderem ter um valor nulo.

Ter um valor nulo de certa forma viola a segurança de tipos, então uma linguagem só é completamente *type safety* se ela também for *null safety*.

Você não pode fazer `var texto : String = null;`.

Se declarar o tipo anulável `var texto : String? = null;` aí cabe o nulo, mas ele só pode ser acessado se verificar antes se a variável é nula, algo como `texto?.length` que é um operador que só executa se não for nulo.

[Documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Claro que o assunto é um pouco mais complexo que isso.

Quando vai escrever um artigo é bom dominar completamente o assunto para não correr o risco de escrever algo errado. É muito fácil achar que algo é de um jeito e na verdade ser de outro. A internet está cheio de artigos com conteúdo errado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).