# O que é a linguagem de programação Ballerina?

Tags: característica-linguagem, ballerina

[image]

> Ballerina is an open-source programming language for the cloud that makes it easier to use, combine, and create network services.

Seguindo a mesma lógica de outras perguntas aqui com a finalidade de entender melhor alguma ferramenta/linguagem pouco conhecida no mercado, pergunto o que é a linguagem **Ballerina**?

Em sua descrição traz "*linguagem para nuvem que facilita o uso, a combinação e a criação de serviços de rede*", o que isso significa? Que outras características dessa linguagem podem fazê-la competitiva com as linguagens mais usuais?

Trecho de exemplo da linguagem retirado da [documentação oficial](https://ballerina.io/):

```
import ballerina/http;

service /hello on new http:Listener(9090) {
    resource function get sayHello() returns string {
        return "Hello Ballerina!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Vamos ver se alguem consegue explicar "que problema ela resolve". Aguardemos as respostas...

Comment: E se possível, os problemas que ela gera.....

Answer (score 4):

> *Nota: Sou engenheiro da equipe responsável pelo compilador da linguagem Ballerina.*

## Qual problema ela resolve?

Ballerina visa facilitar a criação de serviços de rede seguros e com bom desempenho. É uma linguagem de propósito geral, assim como muitas outras, mas além disso, há recursos que foram adicionados (e outros que foram removidos) para facilitar o trabalho com a rede.

Em primeiro lugar, a linguagem possui suporte à [representação gráfica](https://ballerina.io/learn/why-ballerina/graphical/) do código, gerando diagramas de sequência automaticamente. Um dos objetivos finais é garantir que qualquer programa escrito em Ballerina possa ser visualizado através deste diagrama.

Alguns recursos da linguagem:

- Tem um sistema de tipo estrutural (semântico), o que significa que os nomes dos tipos não importam, apenas a forma do tipo é considerada. Isso a torna mais semelhante às linguagens dinamicamente tipadas, enquanto fornece a segurança e o suporte de ferramentas de linguagens estaticamente tipadas.
- É [*null safe*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249099/112052).
- Tem um modelo de threading leve, onde pode-se escrever código de maneira simples e fazer com que seja executado em paralelo.
- Podemos gerar artefatos de implantação de Docker e Kubernetes com uma configuração simples.
- Tem um sistema de gerenciamento de configuração embutido.

Uma lista mais elaborada dos recursos pode ser encontrada [nesta apresentação](https://ballerina.io/learn/language-introduction/).

---

Na [documentação](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/) é possível ver a maioria dos recursos disponíveis da linguagem. Especificamente na seção *Working Over the Network* há vários exemplos de serviços HTTP, como esse:

```js
import ballerina/http;

type Student record {
    string Name;
    int[] Grades;
};

service / on new http:Listener(9090) {

    // This resource method serve http GET requests to path /hello/[XXXXX] and the value XXXXX will be bound to a parameter `name`
    resource function get hello/[string name]() returns string {
        return string `Hello ${name.toUpperAscii()}`;
    }

    // /queryPramToJson?name=Jane&id=443948333
    resource function get queryPramToJson(string name, string id) returns json {
        return {user_name: name, id};
    }

    // Query params, the hard way
    // localhost:9090/queryParamObject?name=Jane
    resource function get queryParamObject(http:Request req) returns json {
        map<string[]> qParams = req.getQueryParams();
        string[]? name = qParams["name"];
        if name == () {
            return "No query param found with name=name";
        }
        else {
            return "Hello " + name[0];
        }
    }

    // `val` extracted from http header.
    resource function get header(@http:Header string? val) returns json {
        return {value: val};
    }

    // Ballerina natively support JSON
    // This resource is serving http POST requests as we want to pass data as http payload
    resource function post jsonEcho(@http:Payload json j) returns json => j;

    // Json structure similar to { "Name": "Miranda", "Grades": [65, 99, 88] } will be mapped to `Student` type.
    resource function post bumpGrades(@http:Payload Student student) returns json {
        string name = student.Name;
        int[] newGrades = student.Grades.map((i) => int:min(i + 10, 100));
        int sum = 0;
        foreach var i in newGrades {
            sum += i;
        }
        int avg = sum / newGrades.length();

        return {Name: name, Grades: newGrades, Average: avg};
    }

    // XML is natively supported.
    resource function post extractCity(@http:Payload xml store) returns xml {
        // Extract a descendent element from a xml value.
        xml city = store/**/<city>;
        return city;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship of the language with Java? Could you give concrete examples about the network services you mentioned?

Comment: At the moment, Ballerina is a JVM language. We have a small team working on a native compiler, but it will take a couple of years for it to be production ready.

Comment: @Woss I updated the answer with an example and a pointer to more sample code.