# O que é a linguagem de programação Rust?

Tags: característica-linguagem, rust

De acordo com a [página oficial](https://www.rust-lang.org/pt-BR/) da linguagem:

> Rust é uma linguagem de programação de sistemas que roda incrivelmente rápido, previne falhas de segmentação, e garante segurança entre threads.

Ela é relativamente nova, de 2010, e parece ser quase desconhecida ou ignorada pela nossa região - visto que a tag [rust](/questions/tagged/rust) nem existia aqui no site até esta pergunta.

Como forma de entender o contexto da linguagem:

- O que é Rust?
- Em muitos momentos, Rust é comparado ao C++. Ela surgiu como uma alternativa ao C++? Quais as principais diferenças entre elas?
- Sempre é citado também a expressão "programação de sistemas" (no inglês, *systems programming*). O que isso significa?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rust é uma linguagem de programação focada principalmente em:

- **Segurança sem coletor de lixo.**
- **Concorrência sem disputa de dados.**
- **Abstração sem overhead.**

Seu design habilita a criação de programas que possuem alta performance e controle de uma linguagem baixo-nível, porém com a abstração poderosa de uma linguagem alto-nível. Essas propriedades fazem Rust ser indicada para programadores que possuem experiência em linguagens como C e estão procurando por uma alternativa mais segura, assim como aqueles que vêm de linguagens como o Python que procuram formas de escrever códigos que rodam melhor sem sacrificar a expressividade.

Rust realiza a maioria das medidas de segurança e decisões de controle de memória em tempo de compilação, fazendo com que a performance de execução não seja afetada. Isso é útil em diversos casos que outras linguagens não são boas: programas com requisitos de espaço e tempo previsíveis, inseridas em outras linguagens, e escrever código baixo-nível, como drivers de dispositivos e sistemas operacionais.

---

Em Rust **não existem ponteiros nulos ou ponteiros soltos**, impossibilitando falhas de segmentação. Rust gerencia memória e recursos automaticamente, **sem necessitar de um coletor de lixo**.

A linguagem impede corridas de dados entre threads pois **não é possível que duas threads possam modificar um mesmo valor ao mesmo tempo**. Para que uma referência possa ser compartilhada entre várias threads, ela deve ser **somente leitura**. Existem diversas técnicas seguras de comunicação entre threads.

O princípio de abstração sem overhead vem do C++. Nas palavras de [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup):

> "Você não paga por aquilo que você não usa. E mais: aquilo que você
> usa, não conseguiria programar melhor à mão".

Rust permite um alto grau de abstração através do sistema de traits, que são interfaces que podem ser implementadas separadamente da declaração de um tipo. Tipos genéricos são utilizados extensamente.

---

Exemplo de código utilizando um simples algoritmo de ler e escrever um número:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

Função retornando um número:

```
fn five() -> i32 {
    5
}

fn main() {
    let x = five();

    println!("The value of x is: {}", x);
}
```

Mais exemplos de código [aqui](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/).

Fontes: [Rust Oficial E-Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Answer (score 19):

## TL; DR

> O que é Rust?

Uma linguagem de programação que preza pela eficiência (abstração de custo zero sempre que possível) e segurança (de tipos, memória e compartilhamento), mantendo um certo grau de usabilidade.

> Em muitos momentos, Rust é comparado ao C++. Ela surgiu como uma alternativa ao C++? Quais as principais diferenças entre elas?

Sim, Rust seria um C++ moderno e sem legado, mas não 100%, Rust não tenta ser orientada a objetos e não leva a meta-programação ao extremo. As diferenças básicas mais abaixo.

> Sempre é citado também a expressão "programação de sistemas" (no inglês, systems programming). O que isso significa?

Sistemas, nesse contexto, se opõem a aplicativos. Estamos falando de coisas de base, como sistemas operacionais e *drivers*, ou até programação *bare metal* embarcado em dispositivos que nem usam SOs. Também entra nisso softwares que não são usados diretamente pelo usuário e que precisam ser muito eficientes por serem o lado mais concreto que aplicativos acessam, de plataformas, principalmente estamos falando de softwares servidores como bancos de dados, *file systems*, gerenciadores de área de trabalho GUI, processadores HTTP e outros protocolos de rede, navegadores, compiladores, etc.

## Detalhes

Páginas oficiais sempre são *marketeiras*. "Incrivelmente rápido" é subjetivo. Ruby também roda rápido, chega a fazer milhões de cálculos em um único segundo.

O chamado *elevator pitch* de Rust é a [segurança de tipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101), de memória, e de [corrida de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

#### Segurança de tipos

Ao contrário do que prega muitas linguagens de tipagem estática e que se consideram seguras, isso costuma estar longe de ser verdade, não vale para C++, C# ou Java, todas são inseguras em alguns pontos. Rust garante sempre que o tipo é o correto no momento da compilação. O que obviamente a torna um pouco menos flexível. Claro, você pode explicitamente dizer que quer que o tipo se passe por outro, mas isto precisa ser válido, não há coerção inválida.

#### Segurança de memória

Rust garante que a memória nunca seja acessada em estado inválido (ela garante a inicialização corretamente e só pode acessar o que está ativo) e nunca deixa vazar memória. Tudo isso com um sistema de referências, empréstimos, e tipos de gerenciamento de memória com referência única (`Box<T>`), com contagem de referência (`Rc<T>`) e o mesmo de forma atômica (`Arc<T>`), além de alguns auxiliares como o `Weak<T>` para evitar referências cíclicas. Nesse ponto Rust não é 100% segura, mas é se você tomar alguns cuidados em casos extremos, e se falhar apenas haverá vazamento de memória, mas esse é um ponto pouco usado.

Rust coleta o lixo de memória de forma automática, ela só não usa um mecanismo de *tracing* para fazer isso. Mas pode até fazer, a linguagem está preparada para isso e tem iniciativas da comunidade para entregar algo neste sentido. O que não se comenta é que muitas vezes esse mecanismo pode ser menos eficiente que um bom *tracing garbage collector*.

Não há problema algum escrever na memória concorrentemente entre *threads*, mas isto só pode ser feito de forma segura, o compilador consegue determinar se isso está ocorrendo.

#### Segurança sobre concorrência

E finalmente ela provê formas que um dado não seja acessado de forma concorrente causando algum impacto negativo, a chamada *data race*. Não sei dizer se funciona 100%, apenas vejo muitas pessoas dizendo que sim, mas tenho quase certeza que é só se tomar alguns cuidados. A questão é que você não é pego de surpresa como ocorre em outras linguagens.

## Quase 100% garantido

100% é muito difícil e pode criar enormes complicadores para a linguagem e para o código. Já dizem que Rust é uma linguagem complicada de aprender e ela em si tem dificuldades para ser implementada, por isso o compilador dela é um dos mais lentos do mercado, o que vai um pouco contra a ideia de ser rápida, pelo menos neste sentido (dizem que vão melhorar e claro que já fizeram alguns esforços, mas não existe milagre, se tem uma análise de grafos muito complexos não tem muito o que fazer, apenas pode melhorar um pouco as estruturas internas e algoritmos para melhorar alguns pontos, e quem sabe usar alguns truques, como D faz que desliga a coleta de lixo, assim tem ganho na alocação (um *tracing* GC costuma alocar mais rápido) e não paga o preço da liberação (mas isso impede o compilador ser usado como serviço a não ser que se implemente um sistema de região de memória nele).

Essas garantias não são válidas quando se usa um contexto `unsafe` necessário para algumas operações de forma eficiente, onde pode ter acesso a ponteiros nulos, e acesso como tipagem fraca.

## Nível de abstração

Ela é uma linguagem de alto nível com alguns recursos de baixo nível. Tem mecanismos inovadores e bem interessantes. Dizem que [lá estão alguns dos melhores teóricos sobre linguagens de programação](https://www.quora.com/Which-language-has-the-brightest-future-in-replacement-of-C-between-D-Go-and-Rust-And-Why/answer/Andrei-Alexandrescu), sem perder o pragmatismo de uma linguagem de mercado, tanto que você provavelmente já roda algum binário gerado por Rust, por exemplo em partes do Firefox. A Mozilla financia a linguagem.

## C++

Ela não substitui nenhuma linguagem, mas é uma alternativa ao C++, foi criada para isso. A maioria dos programadores C++ não querem saber de Rust e conseguem demonstrar que certas complicações não vale o esforço. Há quem conteste. Eu acho a linguagem bem interessante, mas não é tudo o que algumas pessoas dizem, e em certos cenários vejo códigos mais complexos do que deveriam, e para obter eficiência precisa escrever mais, em alguns casos para conseguir o que quer precisa escrever códigos verbosos e que parecem sem sentido (faz dentro da filosofia da linguagem de te obrigar a pensar e explicitar certas coisas antes de fazer).

Rust é expressiva, mas não tanto assim. Ela exige algum *boiler plate* para dar as garantias que propõe.

## Zero abstração

Há o mito dela ter zero abstração. Ela busca isso, mas nem sempre cumpre. Não digo que seja algo ruim, mas há alguns casos que você paga por algo que não precisa, há várias críticas sobre o assunto e reconhecimento da comunidade que tem mesmo. É um preço a se pagar por ter um pouco mais de usabilidade. C++ tem conseguido algum resultado em versões mais novas (futuras) por aprender com os erros do passado (dela e dos outros) e por permitir mais formas de abstrações que Rust.

## Rust X C++

A lista de diferenças para o C++ é extensa para postar aqui onde tem várias perguntas, algumas:

- Ela controla o tempo de vida do dados.
- Controla o acesso concorrente de forma natural.
- Os mecanismos de gerenciamento de memória são mais flexíveis e robustos.
- Exceto pelo `unsafe` não dá para fugir das garantias, inclusive não faz promoção de tipos de forma automática.
- Não tem compromisso com C e seus defeitos.
- *Generics* não é tão poderoso quanto *templates*, mas é bem mais fácil e seguro.
- *Traits* é muito forte, mas C++ permite tudo isto de forma mais geral, pode não ser tão bonito e garantido, mas isto pode mudar em C++20 e 23.
- Obviamente a biblioteca é completamente diferente.
- Todas essas novidades do C++11 pra frente não costuma estar em Rust. Muitas vezes porque não precisa ou tem algo melhor, ou pelo menos diferente.
- Rust não é orientada a objetos, ela só tem `struct` e a implementação de métodos que usam esta estrutura, além dos *traits*, não tem classes, construtores, essas coisas.
- Geralmente você não acessa ponteiros diretamente.
- Rust não tem exceções, porque é um mecanismo problemático e já considerado arcaico. Mas em alguns casos a exceção pode ser útil para a performance, então Rust perde para C++, até C# ou Java neste casos específicos.
- Rust não acessa faixas de dados sem verificação de limite, o que pode piorar bastante a performance se o compilador não conseguir elidir esta verificação de forma segura.
- Rust tem [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410484/112052).
- [e mais](https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp)...

  ```
    E você deve reescrever tudo o que tem em Rust.
    </meme>
  ```

[image: Rewrite in Rust book (satyrical)]

C++ tem evoluído de forma impressionante e com o tempo algumas dessas diferenças podem desaparecer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Rust/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Meme? https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/58532625.jpg

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado https://i.imgur.com/8acN5PG.png Coloquei mais no chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44188030#44188030