# O que é e qual a explicação para type-safe em C#?

Tags: c#, terminologia, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Não conseguir entender o conceito de *type-safe* em C# e qual é sua utilização, visto que C# é *type-safe*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Darei um resumo para leigos, não farei aqui uma monografia sobre teoria de tipos.

Segurança de tipos é a qualidade de fazer operações em dados apenas quando a operação faz sentido. Linguagens ditas *type safety* possuem mecanismos que impedem o código fazer o que pode dar errado por incompatibilidades entre tipos e uso de um tipo onde não pode. Geralmente impede uma compilação finalizar. É a linguagem que obriga o código respeitar os contratos estabelecidos.

Imagine tentar acessar um valor inteiro em um valor que está na memória como ponto flutuante. Sem a devida conversão isso é um erro, já que a codificação de bits de um deles nada tem a ver com o outro, internamente é diferente como enxergamos onde tudo é número, não basta só abandonar a parte decimal, é uma composição totalmente diferente, elas não se misturam. Mas se o acesso faz a conversão automaticamente sempre que precisa, sem causar resultados indesejados, aí já é seguro.

Ou imagine tentar acessar um `Substring()` em uma variável que seja do tipo `date`, ou ainda tentar fazer um `ToString()` em uma variável que não tenha sido inicializada com um objeto (a variável ainda aponta para nulo).

> Well-typed programs cannot "go wrong"
> -- Robin Milner

Se isso for levado a ferro e fogo, poucas linguagens, se é que alguma, podem ser consideradas seguras na tipagem. Algumas pessoas dizem isso sobre Haskell (e é exagero), mas nem mesmo sobre ML que ele mesmo criou (só a SML que veio depois conseguiu isso) dizem ser 100% seguras. E ele é o criador da inferência de tipos que facilita manter a tipagem segura e simples por evitar a explícita manifestação do tipo.

É muito difícil garantir que tudo dará certo. É matematicamente possível, mas impraticável na maioria dos casos. Por isso essas linguagens que evitam *type punning* não são usadas.

Geralmente considera-se como *type safe* as linguagens que resolvem todos problemas de tipo, incluindo o acesso equivocado de posição de memória de forma indevida (não ter ponteiros selvagens que acessam áreas não permitidas para aquele dado) ou acessem áreas não reservadas para o dado daquele tipo.

Também considera semântica. Um tipo que guarda temperatura em escala Celsius e outro em escala Kelvin (que eu escolhi só pra não ter que escrever Fahrenheit :P), normalmente permitem as mesmas operações e possuem a mesma codificação interna, geralmente composta por um inteiro ou um número de ponto flutuante padrão, e assim mesmo eles podem ser incompatíveis já que o mesmo número interno de cada um representa valorizações completamente diferentes, para compatibilizá-los precisaria de uma normalização.

Linguagens de [tipagem dinâmica e principalmente de tipagem fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) são inseguras por natureza. Mas tipagem estática e forte não garante a segurança por si só. Por exemplo, nunca vi uma linguagem que não tenha *generics*, ou mecanismo parecido, ser segura do ponto de vista de tipagem.

Algumas pessoas consideram que se o erro for capturado antes de executar ainda garante a segurança de tipos, então linguagens dinâmicas poderiam ser, já que elas dão erro antes de fazer algo. Acho isso ingênuo e sem propósito. Se isso valer então tudo pode ser seguro, mesmo sem ser. Prefiro considerar que qualquer erro causado por uso indevido de um dado por causa do seu tipo viola a segurança de tipo. Acho isto mais universal.

100% de segurança é um pouco complicado de realizar e as linguagens que fazem isso possuem dificuldades de expressar bem todas situações. Principalmente em linguagens mais antigas porque no começo ninguém dava muito valor para essa característica, e quando resolvem fazer isto não podem abandonar o legado.

## C#

C# é segura até a página 3. Tem inúmeras situações que ela não é segura na tipagem. E nem estou falando do uso de [`dynamic`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203656/101). Mesmo o uso de `object` é um problema a não ser em casos bem específicos.

Existem problemas de [variância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32880/101) que deixam fazer cosias que não poderia quando há subtipo.

O uso de `null` viola a segurança de tipo porque há casos em que uma variável referencia-se a nada quando você espera um dado que tenha capacidade de fazer uma série de coisas específicas por ser daquele tipo.

Coerções implícitas ou até explícitas que podem dar errado também deixam a tipagem bem insegura. Coerções garantidas que sempre funcionam e que não criam uma ambiguidade ou confusão no seu uso subsequente não violam a segurança.

Contexto `unsafe` permite vários problemas de segurança de tipos.

Uso de uniões (`struct` com *layout* explícito que sobrepões os membros) também cria complicadores para a tipagem.

E nem falei de passar por isso usando injeção de código na CIL, tão pouco de erros nas bibliotecas padrões que incentivam o uso errado.

E é só o que lembro agora, tem outras violações.

Alguns desses problemas estão sendo resolvidos. Curiosamente Java é menos segura, mas muita gente acha que não. Em alguns aspectos até C++ chega ser mais segura (mas não em outros). Se não fosse o marketing...

[Rust](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249783/101) é um exemplo de segurança em vários aspectos, mas ainda tem várias inseguranças.

A maioria das linguagens são pragmáticas e abrem mão de 100% de segurança para dar mais usabilidade e flexibilidade na linguagem. Mas o marketing manda dizer que é *type safe*.

Veja também: [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No fundo é um marketing, pois a grande maioria não implementa 100% type-safe.