# Por que não foi inventada uma linguagem de programação para substituir o C e o C++ para facilitar o desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais?

Tags: característica-linguagem, sistema-operacional

As linguagens de programação C e C++ substituíram o Assembly no desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais.

Ninguém em sã consciência desenvolve atualmente um sistema operacional totalmente em Assembly. Por favor, me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Porque ainda não foi criado nenhuma linguagem de programação para substituir o C e o C++ para facilitar o desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais?

Foram investidos dinheiro e tempo na invenção do C e do C++ para substituir o Assembly para facilitar o desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais. Por que não investir dinheiro e tempo na invenção de uma linguagem de programação para substituir o C e o C++ para facilitar o desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português :D Recomendo visitar o [tour] para conhecer um pouco mais como o Stack Overflow funciona. Sugestão, publique perguntas que são diretas, e que apresentam um problema de desenvolvimento em específico.

Comment: @RORSCHACH você está equivocado quanto a isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Dúvidas teóricas podem ser feitas. Por esse motivo provavelmente andaram negativando a pergunta e a resposta.

Comment: por que seria necessário criar uma nova linguagem se linguagens como C e C++ já são amplamente conhecidas e dominadas por quem trabalha com sistemas operacionais?

Comment: Tem Rust, que pretende ocupar este nicho.

Comment: Você fala em compiladores e Sistemas Operacionais , coisas que a maioria procura a estabilidade , suponha que seja criada a linguagem ZorgX e o SO PloftY ambos superiores a tudo que exista , faltaria massa crítica de programadores , equipamentos e ambientes para rodar isto , em geral o orçamento é limitado e se tende a ser conservador , mas a inovação vem , passos evolutivos , pequenas modificações , grandes revoluções existem mas são raras.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pergunta parte de uma premissa errada. Tem várias outras linguagens que foram criadas (inventada seria um termo ruim) com o objetivo, entre outros, de fazer um sistema operacional, a maioria sem sucesso porque não eram boas o suficiente, ou as existentes já eram boas o suficiente, o que mostra que é complicado fazer algo para substituir essas linguagens. A que teve maior sucesso foi [Rust](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/282486/101), e de fato foi usada para criar o [Redox](https://www.redox-os.org/).

Várias linguagens substituíram o Assembly porque linguagem de baixo nível é muito improdutiva e tem diversas desvantagens, é uma diferença brutal e essa é uma das poucas coisas que é considerada bala de prata na computação. Mudar de C ou C++ para outra linguagem de médio ou alto nível o ganho é muito pequeno e geralmente tem alguma perda associada, pra que criar algo novo que só é diferente e não necessariamente melhor? Se acha que deve criar outra precisa dar uma justificativa válida e que convença as pessoas. Voluntarismo não é suficiente.

O Assembly ainda é necessário para algumas partes da criação de qualquer SO que não seja só de brinquedo. E tem vários pequenos SOs feitos inteiramente em Assembly mesmo mais recentemente. Podem não ser SOs que concorrem com Windows, Linux, essas coisas, mas são totalmente funcionais e alguns são usados em nichos. Existem vantagens, não é só desvantagem fazerem em Assembly.

Praticamente ninguém acha que é necessário criar outra linguagem para construção de sistemas operacionais. Se não tem motivo não tem porque fazer, não tem porque investir nisso. As pessoas que fazem isto estão confortáveis com o que existe. Mesmo Rust foi criada para outras coisas, ser capaz de construir um SO viável foi apenas efeito colateral.

Essas linguagens são chamadas *system languages*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quais são as várias linguagens que substituíram o Assembly?  Porque praticamente ninguém acha que é necessário criar outra linguagem para construção de sistemas operacionais? Porque não existe motivo de criar outra linguagem para construção de sistemas operacionais?

Comment: Você que quer que crie que precisa justificar. Não precisa de justificativa para não fazer algo, precisa para fazer.

Comment: Quais são as várias linguagens que substituíram o Assembly?

Comment: Todas as milhares de médio e alto nível.

Comment: As linguagens C e C++ são linguagens de médio nível. Não seria boa idéia criar uma linguagem de alto nível para facilitar o desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais?

Comment: C é médio nível, C++ é alto nível, então se quer uma de alto nível, já tem. E sistemas operacionais tem exigências que muito alto nível não funciona bem. Não que não seja possível, já vi criarem em JS e Lua, mas não são produtos sérios.

Comment: Você disse que a linguagem Rust foi usada para criar o Redox. O Redox é um produto sério?

Comment: É, não é popular, mas é bem sério.

Comment: O Redox é mais sério do que o Linux? Quais são as diferenças entre a seriedade do Redox, Windows, OS X da Apple e todos os outros sistemas operacionais populares? Talvez eu irei desenvolver um sistema operacional usando Rust.

Comment: Aí é outra questão e não é sobre programação. Na verdade não faz sentido pensar nisso. Eu acho que não deveria, mas se é seu desejo pode fazer.

Comment: Você disse que tem várias outras linguagens que foram criadas (inventada seria um termo ruim) com o objetivo, entre outros, de fazer um sistema operacional, a maioria sem sucesso porque não eram boas o suficiente, ou as existentes já eram boas o suficiente, o que mostra que é complicado fazer algo para substituir essas linguagens, você também disse que a que teve maior sucesso foi Rust e de fato foi usada para criar o Redox.

Comment: Quais são as outras linguagens que tiveram sucesso no desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais? Quais são os sistemas operacionais que foram criados através do uso dessas linguagens?

Comment: Defina sucesso.

Comment: Você mesmo disse que tem várias outras linguagens que foram criadas (inventada seria um termo ruim) com o objetivo, entre outros, de fazer um sistema operacional, a maioria sem sucesso porque não eram boas o suficiente, ou as existentes já eram boas o suficiente.

Comment: Você mesmo disse que a que teve maior sucesso foi Rust e de fato foi usada para criar o Redox.

Comment: Quais são as outras linguagens que tiveram sucesso no desenvolvimento de sistemas operacionais e quais são os sistemas operacionais que foram criados através do uso dessas linguagens?

Comment: Então eu vou ficar só com essa. Até porque isso é irrelevante e fora do escopo deste site. Aqui não é um fórum, não é para ficar debatendo ou interrogando, se faz um pergunta objetiva e obtém uma resposta, se precisava mais que isto a pergunta não é adequada.

Comment: Tá me parecendo que isso aqui é projeto de ML de alguém tentando criar um bot.