# Duck type em Elixir

Tags: tipagem, erlang, elixir

`[5,a,15] = [5,10,15]` Fazer esse tipo de atribuição em Elixir é *duck typing* 
 ou são conceitos diferentes?

Pergunto pois fiquei com a dúvida já que do lado esquerdo é declarada uma "variável" sem um tipo explicito ou um valor de atribuição direto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está atribuindo uma lista com 3 valores para uma lista com elementos, dois deles são valores, portanto não faz sentido o seu uso assim. O único elemento que serve a algum propósito é a variável `a`. Então 10 será atribuído para `a` e poderá usar esta variável depois com esse valor.

Na verdade Elixir define isso como [*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445451/101) sempre.

A variável `a` não tem um tipo definido porque Elixir é uma linguagem de [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). O valor que ela guarda é que tem tipo. Este tipo é definido de acordo com a sintaxe usada, portanto é inferida pela sua estrutura.

Veja [mais sobre tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Então o segundo elemento da lista à esquerda é uma variável que guardará o valor que está no segundo elemento da lista à direita. O seu tipo é um inteiro inferido pela forma como ele está estruturado (escrito).

Elixir não diz que implementa [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101). Que bom, respeito isso.

Na verdade não gosto do termo. Parece que ninguém sabe o que isso quer dizer de fato e cada um tem sua versão, a maioria delas não acrescenta nada ao que já existe e não indicam que isso tem a ver com sistema de tipagem. Então é melhor esquecer esse termo, que é engraçadinho, mas não serve para nada em termos de engenharia.

De qualquer forma nada indica estar usando isso de acordo com a maioria das definições.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado, só falei sobre ela não ter um tipo explicito pra deixar bem claro. Sei sobre o conceito de linguagem dinâmica e o de Duck Type ( Que você explicou em outra pergunta que eu li ha ha ) ... perguntei pois assisti uma talk recentemente e o apresentador se deparou com essa questão.

Comment: Quando é assim,. coloca o *link* para dar contexto.

Comment: Sim, colocaria se tivesse ... assisti no pc de um colega e não lembro do título, vou tentar procurar e adicionar nesta e em futuras perguntas.

Answer (score 0):

O conceito de *Duck Typing* é o seguinte: *"se faz 'quack' como um pato, então é um pato"*. Esse conceito é bastante utilizado em linguagens com tipagem dinâmica para reaproveitamento de código (DRY - *don't repeat yourself*), porém mais conhecido na comunidade Ruby por causa dos recursos de módulos.

Mas o que isso quer dizer?

Imagine que você tenha uma função que recebe um valor **não tipado** e faz alguma operação (mesmo que seja um print) nesse valor:

```rb
module Printer
  def print
    self.to_s
  end
end
```

Esse módulo por si só em Ruby não faz nada, mas quando incluído (*include*) numa classe, todas as classes que façam essa inclusão vão "responder ao" (*respond_to*) método *print*.

O *self* no método não está com nenhuma restrição quanto ao tipo (classe) onde esse módulo possa ser inserido, logo ele fará *duck typing*.

Para entender melhor o *duck typing* nesse exemplo, considere a seguinte frase: "se *print* como um *Printer*, então é um *Printer*".

```rb
class Car
  include Printer
end

class Person
  include Printer
end
```

*Car* e *Person* são tipos completamente diferentes e por isso, sem o *duck typing* não seria possível algo como:

```rb
def show(car_or_person)
  car_or_person.print
end
```

Para fazer isso em Java, que é uma linguagem com tipagem estática, poderíamos fazer duas coisas:

1. Ter dois métodos *show*

```java
...
public void show(Car car) { car.print(); }
public void show(Person person) { person.print(); }
...
```

ou

2. Ter uma classe abstrata (ou uma interface default depois do java 7):

```java
public abstract class Printer { 
  public void print() { 
    System.out.println(this.toString()); 
  } 
}

public class Car extends Printer {}
public class Person extends Printer {}

...

public void show(Printer printer) { printer.print(); }
```

Porém *duck typing* é mais associado com linguagens com tipagem dinâmica, logo o código fica melhor em Ruby ou Elixir (através dos *protocols*).