# Como o Python trata as variáveis estáticas e dinâmicas?

Tags: python, variáveis, tipagem, variável-estática

Variável estática, é aquela onde separamos a memória do computador já de antemão de forma definida (li isso no livro "Estrutura básica de dados"). Já a variável dinâmica é aquela em que surge na própria execução do programa, também conhecidas como "variáveis anônimas". Estas nós só temos acesso a partir do endereço.

Comment: Esclareça melhor sua pergunta. O que quer saber em específico? Que variável estática está falando? Enfim, dê mais detalhes sobre sua dúvida.

Comment: O que você entende por "variáveis estáticas" e "variáveis dinâmicas"?

Comment: Só esclarecendo que sou muito neném na área de TI. Estou apenas engatinhando ainda.. Variável estática, é aquela onde separamos a memória do computador já de antemão de forma definida(li isso no livro "Estrutura básica de dados"). Já a variável dinâmica é aquela  em que surge na própria execução do programa, também conhecidas como "variáveis anônimas". Estas, nos só temos acesso a partir do endereço.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica exclusivamente, não há tipagem estática, pelo menos não na linguagem padrão (tem umas variações que até têm, mas são dialetos, não podem ser considerados Python de verdade, tem semântica diferente). Até existem linguagens que possuem tipos graduais ou dinamismo opcional, mas não é o caso de Python.

Então primeiro precisa entender sobre esses [dois estilos de tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) que as linguagens adotam. Também sobre [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Python até está implantando a anotação de tipo para que alguns erros possam ser identificados em momento de compilação, mas a tipagem ainda será dinâmica. Não haverá ganho de performance, embora em alguns casos possam criar alguma otimização, mas você não poderá contar que a variável sempre terá o mesmo tipo, isto é uma mudança semântica importante e incompatível com o que a linguagem é hoje.

Então Python só trata de variáveis dinâmicas. Todas elas podem ter valores de qualquer tipo em determinado momento. Python não pode ter mais de um tipo ao mesmo tempo, e o valor não existe sem tipo, mesmo que ele não esteja declarado explicitamente. Além disto ela possui tipagem forte, então ela não faz coerção insegura que pode apresentar um resultado inesperado.

A implementação atual da linguagem usa uma estrutura para todos os valores que consta o valor e o tipo do valor. Em C (Python é escrito em C) isso costuma ser feito com uma `struct` com um membro do tipo e outro membro que é uma `union` que se sobrepõe o valor do tipo.

Quase tudo o que está no comentário está errado ou está confuso ou sem contexto, assim como a premissa da pergunta. Não existe isso de variável anônima no conceito que usamos, [variável é um nome por definição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), é uma posição de memória com nome. Então fica complicado falar sobre informações equivocadas. Se só temos o endereço não temos variável, podemos ter o endereço em alguma variável, se o endereço não está em variável é só um valor e se existe um valor em algum lugar e não tem uma referência com um nome para ele não temos uma variável.

A memória é reservada para os valores de acordo com seu tipo, sempre.

A variável é um conceito de tempo de desenvolvimento, ela não existe quando está executando, variável é um conceito abstrato demais para estar presente durante a execução que é algo bem concreta.

Aqui no site tem bastante informação sobre isso e sugiro pesquisar mais. A fonte que está usando ou é ruim ou está interpretando-a de forma equivocada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero, será que estou estudando errado ?

Comment: Talvez, não tenho como afirmar isto. Se der mais detalhes eu poderia tentar dizer algo.