# Como o Python gerencia a memória durante a atribuição de diferentes tipos?

Tags: python, tipagem, memória, python-internals

Queria entender sobre como é feita a tipagem dinâmica.

Em Python, por exemplo, quando criamos uma variável com conteúdo um número `int` e depois essa mesma variável recebe uma *string*, o fato de não dar problema com alocação de memória me deixa confuso. O que acontece em Python? Todos tipos são tratados como especificação do objeto principal, aí funciona por meio de *upcasting* e *downcasting*?

Comment: Se você compreende inglês, a  página de [Memory Management](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html) da documentação explica como funciona o gerenciamento de memória no python 3. Infelizmente não há a versão dessa página em português.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As linguagens de tipagem dinâmica costumam ter apenas **1** tipo que é o objeto. Esse tipo é que possui a infraestrutura para gerenciar os demais tipos de dados.

Eu imagino que entenda como um dado é armazenado na memória, sabe que precisa do tipo para saber o tamanho da alocação para armazenar. Como Python e outras linguagens de tipagem dinâmica possuem só 1 tipo de dado fica fácil fazer isso, todos os objetos básicos são alocados da mesma forma com o armazenamento de mesmo tamanho.

Quando estou falando de alocação é do espaço, não do gerenciamento dessa alocação porque é um conceito ortogonal, e nada tem a ver com a tipagem dinâmica, o gerenciamento de memória pode ocorrer de forma semelhante em linguagens de tipagem estática. Digo isso porque um comentário fala sobre o assunto e não é o que a pergunta quer saber, ela usou o tewrmo equivocado por não entender do que se trata com exatidão.

Esse objeto tipicamente é uma estrutura que precisa de duas informações básicas (no fim mostro especificamente de Python como é). Precisa de uma informação de qual é o tipo do valor que tem nele e o valor em si.

Esse tipo que está marcado é o que determina a tipagem que você conhece no Python, portanto a tipagem é feita em outra camada. Isso pode ser 1 byte e cada número indicar um tipo diferente. Não precisa ser assim, mas é uma forma simples e fácil de fazer.

A outra informação é o valor. Esse valor pode ter um tamanho único, por exemplo pode ser 8 bytes.

Então esse conjunto terá sempre 9 bytes. Pronto, você sabe que sempre alocará esse tamanho.

Mas o que tem nesse valor?

Se o tipo for um booleano ele só usará 1 desses 8 bytes e terá o valor 0 ou 1. Se tiver um número terá uma forma de valor com ponto flutuante ou um inteiro como otimização (cada linguagem pode fazer isso ou não) e se tiver outros tipos numéricos básicos vai fazendo assim e ocupará de 1 a 8 bytes que já foi armazenado para você.

Começa mudar um pouco quando tem uma *string*. Esse tipo é por referência e não por valor, então o valor ali nesses 8 bytes teria um ponteiro para o texto. Tipos por referência sempre existem em duas partes, o ponteiro e o objeto apontado onde o objeto de fato tem o dado. Aí essa alocação extra pode ter tamanho diferentes e é determinado no momento da execução, por isso o mais comum é ser alocado no *heap*. Isso funciona igual em qualquer outra linguagem que não tem tipagem dinâmica.

O mesmo vale para ouros tipos por referência como a lista e o dicionário, só o ponteiro para o objeto é que vai ali, e em 8 bytes cabe qualquer ponteiro.

Se entende de C esse objeto seria mais ou menos isso:

```
struct {
    char type; //obviamente indica qual é o tipo
    union { //só usa um dos valores abaixo, e sempre armazena o espaço para o maior deles
        char boolean; //só se for o booleano
        double number; //só se for um número
        void *reference; //só se for um objeto por referência
    } value;
} object;
```

Só para ilustrar, não precisa ser exatamente assim.

Essa é uma forma de criar uma [*tagged union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) já que C não tem esse mecanismo, em outros linguagens a tipagem poderia ser mais automática.

Então em todo código esse é o objeto que circulará. E toda linguagem sabe que antes de acessar o valor o código tem que analisar que tipo está esperando naquele contexto e o tipo do objeto que manipulará pra ver se pode realizar aquela operação ou deve dar erro se eles forem incompatíveis. Para saber o tipo daquele objeto é só olhar esse campo `type` que eu mostrei aí em cima, dependendo do valor ali que está nele sabe que tipo é (por exemplo 0 seria um `None`, 1 seria um booleano, 2, número, 3 string, 4, lista, 5, dicionário, 6 objeto, etc.).

A linguagem garante que toda vez que colocar um valor ali ele sincronizará o tipo no outro campo para ficar sempre compatível. Se o seu código mandar fazer alguma mudança no objeto o valor mudará e o tipo junto.

Tudo isso é feito dinamicamente. Isso nada tem a ver com a linguagem ser interpretada ou compilada, dá para fazer isso em ambas, e de fato hoje é comum Python rodar de forma compilada.

## Conversão

Quando o tipo não é o que deseja você tem que usar alguma função que gere um outro objeto para você. Em alguns casos pode querer mudar o próprio objeto (aí ele passa ser do novo tipo "pra sempre"). Em algumas operações é possível fazer só uma reinterpretação, por exemplo pode fazer com que um booleano seja interpretado como um número normal sem gerar outro número, afinal um booleano é representado como um número então ele sabe o que fazer.

Note que Python exige que você faça isso explicitamente, afinal ela tem tipagem forte, um conceito que as pessoas costumam confundir.

Como curiosidade quando você tem um tipo `object` em Python, ele carrega internamente mais um tipo que ele é, então temos 3 camadas de tipo: aquele tipo único que Python usa pra representar tudo, o tipo `object` e o tipo do que é mais especificamente esse `object` (o nome da classe). O primeiro não é acessível ou importante para quem só usa a linguagem.

O *up* e *downcasting* é usado mais em cima dos tipos que são `object`. Existe *casting* de outros tipos, mas é menos comum e em alguns casos na verdade exige conversão, não basta uma reinterpretação. *casting de verdade não converte (às vezes falamos em *casting* quando converte, mas é só para simplificar). Isso não é muito diferente de outras linguagens, é só questão de entender como o dado é realmente armazenado.

Não quero entrar em tantos detalhes, mas pode pesquisar mais sobre o assunto aqui no site, Eu respondi sobre isso em [Como o Python trata as variáveis estáticas e dinâmicas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/336796/101).

Em [Como o Python trata e representa um array internamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364148/101) tem mais informações especificamente sobre *arrays*, inclusive tem trechos de código de Python mostrando como realmente armazena objetos.

Mais detalhes em [Linguagens de programação tipadas e não tipadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324630/101).

## Estruturas de Python

A estrutura real que Python usa deve ser esta (se não mudou quando você estiver lendo aqui tempos depois, já que isso é detalhe interno da linguagem e eles podem mudar quando e como quiserem). Não é algo tão simples, e na verdade tem várias partes, exemplo:

```
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

Note que há um campo para a contagem de referência que é a forma preferencial de mecanismo de coleta de lixo de Python.

Também:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject ob_base;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size; /* Number of items in variable part */
} PyVarObject;
```

Outra:

```
typedef struct _typeobject {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    const char *tp_name; /* For printing, in format "<module>.<name>" */
    Py_ssize_t tp_basicsize, tp_itemsize; /* For allocation */

    /* Methods to implement standard operations */

    destructor tp_dealloc;
    Py_ssize_t tp_vectorcall_offset;
    getattrfunc tp_getattr;
    setattrfunc tp_setattr;
    PyAsyncMethods *tp_as_async; /* formerly known as tp_compare (Python 2)
                                    or tp_reserved (Python 3) */
    reprfunc tp_repr;

    /* Method suites for standard classes */

    PyNumberMethods *tp_as_number;
    PySequenceMethods *tp_as_sequence;
    PyMappingMethods *tp_as_mapping;

    /* More standard operations (here for binary compatibility) */

    hashfunc tp_hash;
    ternaryfunc tp_call;
    reprfunc tp_str;
    getattrofunc tp_getattro;
    setattrofunc tp_setattro;

    /* Functions to access object as input/output buffer */
    PyBufferProcs *tp_as_buffer;

    /* Flags to define presence of optional/expanded features */
    unsigned long tp_flags;

    const char *tp_doc; /* Documentation string */

    /* call function for all accessible objects */
    traverseproc tp_traverse;

    /* delete references to contained objects */
    inquiry tp_clear;

    /* rich comparisons */
    richcmpfunc tp_richcompare;

    /* weak reference enabler */
    Py_ssize_t tp_weaklistoffset;

    /* Iterators */
    getiterfunc tp_iter;
    iternextfunc tp_iternext;

    /* Attribute descriptor and subclassing stuff */
    struct PyMethodDef *tp_methods;
    struct PyMemberDef *tp_members;
    struct PyGetSetDef *tp_getset;
    struct _typeobject *tp_base;
    PyObject *tp_dict;
    descrgetfunc tp_descr_get;
    descrsetfunc tp_descr_set;
    Py_ssize_t tp_dictoffset;
    initproc tp_init;
    allocfunc tp_alloc;
    newfunc tp_new;
    freefunc tp_free; /* Low-level free-memory routine */
    inquiry tp_is_gc; /* For PyObject_IS_GC */
    PyObject *tp_bases;
    PyObject *tp_mro; /* method resolution order */
    PyObject *tp_cache;
    PyObject *tp_subclasses;
    PyObject *tp_weaklist;
    destructor tp_del;

    /* Type attribute cache version tag. Added in version 2.6 */
    unsigned int tp_version_tag;

    destructor tp_finalize;

} PyTypeObject;
```

Mais um usada em certos casos:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t length;          /* Length of raw Unicode data in buffer */
    Py_UNICODE *str;            /* Raw Unicode buffer */
    long hash;                  /* Hash value; -1 if not set */
    int state;                  /* != 0 if interned. In this case the two
                                 * references from the dictionary to this object
                                 * are *not* counted in ob_refcnt. */
    PyObject *defenc;           /* (Default) Encoded version as Python
                                   string, or NULL; this is used for
                                   implementing the buffer protocol */
} PyUnicodeObject;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Object.c).

Tem outras, pode ver no código fonte do *runtime* da linguagem.

Fontes:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9e3e06e582accec82eb29cf665c3b4c7d84d2eb0/Doc/includes/typestruct.h
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d6fb53fe42d83a10f1372dd92ffaa6a01d2feffb/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h