# Composição de objetos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, memória, objetos

Nesse caso, estou tentando entender como se dá a ligação entre duas classes e seus objetos.

Dado que, ao criar um objeto, seria reservado um espaço na memória para o mesmo, esse espaço inclui o objeto pelo qual é composto?

Exemplo:

```
class Cliente:
  def __init__(self, nome, idade):
    self.nome = nome
    self.idade = idade
    self.enderecos = []

  def insere_endereco(self, cidade, estado):
     self.enderecos.append(Endereco(cidade, estado))

  def lista_endereco(self):
     for endereco in self.enderecos:
        print(endereco.cidade, endereco.estado)



class Endereco:
  def __init__(self, cidade, estado):
    self.cidade = cidade
    self.estado = estado
```

Nesse exemplo, o objeto da classe `Endereco` está sendo armazenado no espaço de memória reservado para seu respectivo cliente? Seria por isso que, ao deletar um cliente, é deletado também o respectivo endereço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se tem uma herança não existe dois objetos, existe um só que é criado baseando-se em um modelo que está definido em duas partes. Pode ver mais sobre em [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Mas nesse caso está usando apenas composição, então tem um objeto que contém outro. Esse "contém" é que precisa ser explicado. Não quer dizer que um objeto está dentro de outro.

Todos os objetos que você cria com uma classe existem por si só e são sempre alocados de forma independente. O objeto existe em duas partes: uma referência que aponta para o objeto, e o objeto em si. Ele é um tipo por referência. Ele seria um ponteiro, mas em Python é até um pouco mais complicado que isso.

Uma lista também é um objeto por referência. Então `self.endereços` , grosso modo, apenas tem o ponteiro para a lista em si. A lista está alocada em outro local da memória, não está dentro de `Cliente`. Ali dentro de `Cliente` tem só o ponteiro.

Dentro desse objeto lista você terá ponteiros para objetos. No caso estamos vendo que o código coloca objetos do tipo `Endereco`. Esse objeto que guarda o endereço está em outra posição da memória, não está dentro da lista que tem só um apontador para o objeto real.

Há uma ligação do `Cliente` com a lista chamada de `enderecos` que tem uma ligação com um objeto `Endereco`. Ligação é diferente de estar tudo junto um dentro do outro.

Quando um objeto é apagado, o mecanismo de gerenciamento de memória do Python, que é principalmente de contagem de referência, fará um trabalho para ver se deve apagar os objetos ligados a ele. Se ninguém mais fizer referência a esse objeto ele é apagado. Mas se em algum outro lugar tiver uma referência para um `Endereco` por exemplo, esse objeto não será apagado, ele precisa sobreviver para não tornar inviável esse outro local.

Pode ver mais detalhes em [Como o Python gerencia a memória durante a atribuição de diferentes tipos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454193/101) e [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101).