# O que é Type Annotation?

Tags: funções, typescript, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Estou lendo um [book](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/javascript/null-undefined.html) sobre TypeScript e me deparei com algo que me chamou a atenção que é o *Type Annotation*.

Veja o exemplo:

```
function foo(): { a: number, b?: number } {
    if (this.a <= 0) { 
        return { a: 1 };
    }
    else {
        return { a: 2, b: 4 };
    }
}
```

Achei esta *syntax* um pouco diferente do que eu estou acostumado, e fiquei confuso e com algumas dúvidas sobre este recurso.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é o Type Annotation?
2. Quais cenários o Type Annotation é aplicável?
3. O Type Annotation é restrito apenas para funções?
4. Type Annotation seria o mesmo que argumentos de uma função?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> O que é o Type Annotation?

Tecnicamente é toda sintaxe que um determinado valor ou variável ou outro local onde possa haver um valor tem seu tipo definido explicitamente. O termo é mais usado em linguagens, como TypeScript, que forçam o tipo na compilação como se fosse tipagem estática, porém ele rodará na verdade de forma dinâmica, já que no JavaScript seu *backend* básico tem tipagem dinâmica. O termo vale para outras linguagens mas como o normal delas é ter a anotação do tipo o termo não é tão usado.

> Quais cenários o Type Annotation é aplicável?

Todos que deseja segurança de tipo e precisa dizer isso explicitamente. Então ele ocorre em todas linguagens de tipagem estática ou que desejam simular características deste modelo de tipagem.

> O Type Annotation é restrito apenas para funções?

Não, ali é só uma forma de usar anotação de tipo, na verdade, toda anotação que já viu em TS ou outras linguagens é um *type annotation*, só não tinha visto o termo antes justamente por ele não ser tão comum, você usa meio sem perceber.

> Type Annotation seria o mesmo que argumentos de uma função?

Eu não sei se no fundo está preocupado com o retorno de um objeto, isso é algo que o JS já aceita, você está criando um objeto anônimo com os membros `a` e `b` e está retornando isso. O que o TypeScript tem de diferente é que você pode dizer qual é o tipo deste objeto no retorno da função, então você pode dizer quais são os membros, seus nomes e seus tipos. Isso dá segurança de tipo porque não pode mudar e retornar algo diferente sem dar erro, ou não pode usar esse retorno errado em um local que espera exatamente este tipo.

Note que esse é um tipo anônimo, ele tem uma estrutura, mas não um nome, então em vez do nome você vê a estrutura deste tipo, mas ele ainda é um tipo. Leia mais sobre essas definições em [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Outra coisa que pode parecer estranha é que pode estar acostumado com sintaxe em linguagens onde o tipo do retorno da função vem antes do nome. As linguagens mais modernas estão adotando o tipo depois, é mais correto e mais fácil de *parsear*.

Então tem dois conceitos aí: um é o retorno de um objeto e outro é a tipagem dele. Note que lá no livro tem o exemplo como é em JS, a única diferença é a tipagem, portanto a presença da anotação de tipo.

Isso também é uma anotação de tipo:

```
function foo() : number {
    return 1;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/ReturnTyping.ts).