# Como o tipo "unknown" funciona em TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem

O tipo  `unknown` é uma *feature* um pouco mais recente da linguagem, e é dito como um `any`, só que *type safe*.

Então, ficaram-me algumas dúvidas:

- Qual a sua diferença em relação ao `any`?
- É seguro utilizá-lo no quesito de segurança de tipos?

Comment: Quero ver o dia que o TypeScript se tornará uma linguagem de "verdade" ou no minimo fazer algo em tempo de execução e não em tempo de "compilação", pq se me lembro até aonde usei (não lembro qual versão) os tipos passados em parametros e argumentos nem sempre funcionam como é esperado em tempo de execução, claro que deve estar tudo documentado e falando sobre isto, mas acho que muita coisa ainda vai depender do JS de verdade.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido compilar TS para Wasm, Até pode e inicialmente achei interessante, mas tem problemas. Pode deixar a linguagem sem a camada do JS e executar mais rápido, poderia até permitir algumas coisas na linguagem que não dá agora, mas a tornaria incompatível com a transpilação para JS. Existe uma dificuldade para usar a infra do browser pelo Wasm então não dá para sair usando sem pensar bem. A vantagem do TS é que não precisa disso, ele usa a infra do browser preparada p/ o JS, até pq é JS. São objetivos diferentes. Vixi quase virou resposta e nem detalhei :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O meu entendimento disto é que o `any` funciona como o `dynamic` do C# (já explico para quem não conhece a linguagem) e o `unknown` é o `object`, ou quase isto.

Com o `any` você pode tentar acessar qualquer membro do objeto e a linguagem deixa, até que na execução se o membro não estiver disponível para o objeto haverá um erro, e por isso não há segurança de tipo. Na hora que for executar ele sabe se dá para acessar, mas não antes. Você pode receber qualquer valor em um objeto do tipo `any` e pode guardar esse objeto `any` em qualquer outro objeto.

```js
let valor: any;
valor = 1;
let numero : number = valor;
valor = "SOpt";
valor.toUpperCase();
valor = [];
valor = {};
//valor.toUpperCase(); //tire o comentário para ver o erro em tempo de execução
console.log(numero);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/AnyUnknown.ts).

O erro aí ocorre porque nessa última linha um objeto qualquer não tem a função `toUpperCase()`, mas quando o objeto era uma `string` funcionou o chamado.

Já o `unknown` não te deixa acessar membro algum do objeto e por causa disto qualquer tentativa de acesso causará erro (é um pouco diferente do C# que o `object` deixa acessar alguns membros do tipo `object`). Também há a diferença que ele pode receber qualquer objeto, mas não pode ser atribuído para qualquer objeto, precisa haver compatibilidade.

E ainda deve ter uma dúvida para que serve então um tipo que não deixa acessar qualquer coisa. Aí entra a segurança de tipo mantendo a flexibilidade da linguagem. Você pode transportar tipos de forma "genérica", mas só pode usar se tiver certeza que pode acessar o conteúdo que está lá, então somente se você testar essa capacidade antes é que ele deixa fazer algum acesso. Existem algumas formas de provar que é seguro acessar um membro do objeto, vou mostrar duas:

```
let valor: unknown;
valor = 1;
//let numero : number = valor; //isso dá erro em compilação
let numero : number = valor as number;
console.log(valor); //compila e funciona
valor = "SOpt";
//valor.toUpperCase(); //isso daria erro em compilação
if (typeof valor === "string") console.log(valor.toUpperCase()); //compila e funciona
valor = [];
valor = {};
```

Veja [funcionando no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AnyUnknownts).

Rode no [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#).

Somente quando o código pode provar que o tipo está correto é que ele deixa acessar os membros do objeto. Então é seguro usar porque o compilador só deixa passar quando ele garante que não quebrará a tipagem.

Isto pode ajudar: [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).