# Por que o tipo "any" existe no TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem

Estou estudando TypeScript e cheguei na parte do tipo `any`. O que eu entendi é que o `any` é utilizado quando não se sabe o tipo do valor que a variável terá.

Mas se esse é o caso, as duas linhas de código abaixo não são a mesma coisa?

```
let var1: any = "Hello World"; 
let var2 = "Hello World"; // Código JS
```

Por que o `any` existe no TS? Há alguma diferença, ainda que mínima, entre usar o `any` e não declarar nenhum tipo para a variável?

Comment: Acredito que seja para interfacear com código Javascript baunilha, que pode enviar ou receber valores misturando tipos.

Comment: E me fiz essa mesma pergunta em relação ao `unknown`....

Comment: @CmteCardeal, sobre o `unknown`: [Como o tipo “unknown” funciona em TypeScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427010/69296).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para entender a motivação do `any`, é preciso, antes, entender um dos princípios fundamentais do TypeScript, que é possibilitar a adoção gradual.

Por muito tempo, o ecossistema do JavaScript não teve nenhum meio eficiente de verificar, estaticamente, os scripts e “programas” que eram desenvolvidos com essa linguagem. Como a tipagem dinâmica do JavaScript, aliada aos diversos *quirks* da linguagem, eram (e ainda são) a fonte de muitos *bugs*, surgiu o TypeScript para garantir maior robustez ao desenvolvimento. Há quem diga, bem enfaticamente, que tipos estáticos ajudam bastante nesse caso – e, embora isso não venha ao caso, eu concordo.

Naturalmente, iriam surgir casos nos quais uma *codebase*, originalmente implementada em JavaScript, teria seus desenvolvedores optarem por migrá-la ao TypeScript. O poblema é que, a depender do tamanho da base de código, a tarefa é, não raro, difícil. Daí surge a necessidade de  mecanismos para garantir uma adoção gradual do TypeScript mais flexível.

O `any` é um desses mecanismos. Ele é um meio de dar *flexibilidade* ao programador. O uso do `any` é como se o programador falasse, ao compilador, o seguinte:

> Eu quero que você, compilador, não se preocupe com este valor. A ele atribuo este tipo coringa, `any`, que basicamente me permite fazer qualquer coisa com ele sem que você me encha a paciência.

É isso.

Pense no `any` como a união de todos os tipos do TypeScript. Um valor do tipo `any` aceita qualquer coisa e, por isso, não é nada seguro. Ao usar `any`, abre-se mão, por conveniência, de todas as seguranças que o TypeScript te dá.

E só para enfatizar um pouco mais a definição, voltemo-nos à [documentação do TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), que diz:

> O TypeScript também tem um tipo especial, `any`, que você pode usar sempre que **não** quiser que um valor específico cause erros de *type-check*.
>
> Quando um valor é do tipo `any`, você pode acessar qualquer uma de suas propriedades (que também serão do tipo `any`), chamá-lo como função, atribuí-lo a valores de qualquer tipo – em resumo: qualquer coisa que não seja sintaticamente ilegal.

Reiterando, veja que o uso de `any` abre mão das seguranças que o TypeScript oferece. Por isso, em versões mais recentes do TypeScript, surgiu o [`unknown`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/427010/69296), que faz algo parecido, porém com um pouco mais de segurança.

Ainda sobre o `any`, documentação diz mais:

> Quando você não especifica, explicitamente, um tipo e o TypeScript **não consegue inferi-lo** pelo contexto, o compilador usará `any` como padrão. Assumindo que a opção `noImplicitAny` esteja desativada (que é o comportamento padrão, embora menos seguro).

Com isso, podemos aludir ao exemplo de código da pergunta:

```
let var1: any = "Hello World"; 
let var2 = "Hello World";
```

São coisas diferentes. No caso acima, `var1` terá o tipo `any`. Já `var2`, devido à possibilidade de inferência do TypeScript, terá o tipo `string`. Portanto, é o mesmo que:

```
let var1: any = "Hello World"; 
let var2: string = "Hello World";
```

Esse é um dos casos em que o TypeScript consegue, seguramente, inferir o tipo da variável. E isso é óbvio para o compilador, tanto é que nenhum aviso é emitido ou `any` é assumido por padrão. Você está atribuindo à `var2` uma string, que está no próprio código. Nesse tipo de caso, é claro ao TypeScript que aquela variável *sempre* será uma string (veja que a ela sempre será atribuída uma string literal). Portanto, diz-se que `string` é o tipo **inferido**.

Veja a diferença entre [este trecho](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false#code/PTAEAMDMHtvUAuBTAtoglgB2hAhgOwE9wAaUFXAZ1HyXwAsBXNJAJ1ZwEvRV0F0AJjkDIBKGiYA5wGOcAInzQAkikwAbdAGM%20AQSKzQApJVz8AbrgG4AdKEWVKOfDNDdWSDdBR1LQqwChIRnwNfmh8UA0CBQRFfEg2ADFYAAoYaABKUABvP1AIsIdVJCtVaABzVNh0gG4-AF8gA), no qual não há inferência possível e `any` é assumido; e [este](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMCdIe0guUAFAhpFBbcAXKoDkAZjDPqAJYYAOANuQMbnY0CeoAFigM6goB2BfizLYWVcADoAUIQCufetnIwB9fnxjYAkn0JQAYiQAUxGAEpQAbymhQ9FVxg1JNGAHMTJMwG4pAXyA), com a opção `noImplicitAny` habilitada e há erro emitido.

Esse é um dos poderes do TypeScript, que tem relativamente boa habilidade de inferência. Conforme já vimos anteriormente, quando a inferência não é possível, por padrão, `any` será utilizado, mas existe uma opção que proíbe esse comportamento, exigindo do programador, nesse tipo de caso, explicitar o tipo. Trata-se de [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny).

Portanto, tem que tomar cuidado para saber quando o tipo é `any` e quando o tipo é inferido. Se você estiver utilizando um editor que suporte (como o VSCode), ao passar o mouse sobre um valor, poderá ver o tipo que ela assume. Aí fica fácil de saber.

Em resumo, o `any` é um coringa – mas tem que tomar cuidado para não confundir esse “coringa” com a inferência.

A inferência, quando aliada à opção `noImplicitAny`, é algo que garante segurança e robustez ao código. É uma conveniência do compilador para que você não tenha sempre, onde é óbvio pelo contexto, de explicitar o tipo manualmente.

O `any` é um *escape-hatch* que te permite abrir mão de certa segurança por flexibilidade. É uma conveniência que vale a pena em ocasiões como a migração gradual. Quando TypeScript está sendo utilizado desde o dia zero, raramente faz sentido, já que se abre mão de segurança.

Comment: Então significa que, ao inferir que o tipo é `string`, eu não posso alterar o valor da variável para `number`, por exemplo. É isso?

Comment: Sim, @JeanExtreme002. Uma vez que o tipo tenha sido inferido, uma mudança ao tipo não é permitida. Veja [aqui](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBArgziBOA7AhgWxBAvBARAKQHsALRCAEQJBwG4AoWBFdLCAVgAZqIB6biAFQCeABwwByRFFQAjBGIgBLGBEQFIyGDAUBzFNNAQwBQyPEww8BYm1iAdEA). Inferência é algo bem poderoso, já que, ao mesmo tempo que traz certa segurança, permite que o programador não perca o tempo digitando tipos já seguramente informados pelo contexto. Não a toa linguagens mais modernas, como Rust, e linguagens originalmente sem inferência (como C#, por `var`) têm adotado esse recurso.

Answer (score 9):

As duas linhas dão o mesmo resultado, mas não são a mesma coisa. Existe uma semântica explícita na primeira linha, que é mais legível e mostra que a intenção é justamente essa.

Se TypeScript é uma linguagem com tipagem estática em primeiro lugar, deixando ser dinâmica funcionar (tipagem gradual), o ideal é que esse dinamismo seja explícito. Se deixar implícito pode ser que o código veio de JavaScript que não tem tipo, ou o código foi feito de forma desleixada.

Existe *opção* que controla o comportamento da segunda linha de como será interpretado pelo compilador.

A segunda forma não existe para comunicar com JavaScript porque depois de compilado a primeira linha fica idêntica à segunda no alvo em JS. Na verdade todos os tipos são perdidos depois de compilado.

Se a dúvida for porque existe um tipo tão aberto, aí é para dar mais flexibilidade, porque tem problema que é mais fácil de descrever tendo um tipo dinâmico, e também porque esse problema pode ter que comunicar com JS que espera assim. Mas é algo colateral.

Existem diversos casos que a semântica do tipo é ser dinâmico, poder ter qualquer valor naquela variável, e tem mais ainda quando trabalha junto com códigos em JS em que todas as variáveis são `any`.

A segunda forma escrita em TS é preguiçosa. Até um tipo de união pode ser melhor que `any` quando você pode ter dois ou mais tipos específicos, mas não todos os tipos. Em uma linguagem de tipagem essencialmente estática explicite o tipo sempre, até quando ele pode ser qualquer um.

Veja mais: [O que é estilo de tipagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101). E também em [Diferença entre usar generics e "any" no TypeScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/466543/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Relacionado ao assunto, tem uma regra para ESLint [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md) e a configuração [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) do TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

Simplesmente:

`let var1: any = "Hello World";`

`var1` pode ser redefinido como qualquer outro objeto e typescript não vai brigar com você pq definiu isso ao usar `any`.

`let var2 = "Hello World";`

Nessa linha voce ja implicitamente declara `var2` como um string e se tentar redefinir este valor para um numero (por exemplo) ja daria um erro. Em typescript, se voce não definir um tipo na declaração de um objeto, o typescript vai definir o tipo da quele objeto automaticamente.

Outros exemplos:

```
let foo = { cc: 'bar' }; // o tipo de foo seria: {cc: string}
foo = { cc: 'asdf', dd: 'sdfsd' }; // erro
foo = 'test'; // erro
foo = { cc: 22 }; // erro
foo = { cc: 'qualquer string' }; // certo
```

```
let foo2 = [22]; // o tipo de foo2 seria: string[]
foo2 = { cc: 22 }; // erro
foo2 = ['55', 66, 77]; // erro
foo2 = [55, 66, 77]; // certo
```

agora

```
let foo3: any = [22]; // o tipo de foo3 seria: any
foo3 = { cc: 22, tt: 'test' }; // certo
foo3 = 'test'; // certo
foo3 = [55, 66, 77]; // certo
```