# Em Python, como usar anotação de tipo quando o tipo de retorno do método é a própria classe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tipagem

Vou demonstrar um exemplo em TypeScript de um código que refiz o equivalente em Python:

```js
class Foo {
  private x: number
  private y: string

  constructor(x: number, y: string) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  getX(): number {
    return this.x;
  }

  getThis(): Foo {
    return this;
  }
}
```

<sup>link do [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAcBOBLAbmAC4Cm0AHgFzQB2ArgLYBGJ26Wehp0AntRETw0A5qnbB4NAdjrAi8bAAoqtRi2wAaXv0G4RAShTsMRABa4IAOnLQAvBQDcx6GYuWed3k4wBfMRmESIgANRX1qemZWIwwMbCC6bBoXcytyb2g-dkCiABVUsOoEJDRY6HiiROTXCAy-HyA)</sup>

O tipo retornado por `getThis` é a classe `Foo`. Sem problemas de *warnings* até aqui.

Seguindo essa mesma linha, o equivalente que tentei recriar em Python:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: str):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def get_x(self) -> int:
        return self.x

    def get_self(self) -> Foo:
        return self
```

A minha lógica em `def get_self(self) -> Foo:` não funciona pois recebo *warnings* do VSCode e nem consigo executar o código:

[image: Erro: "Foo" in not defined]

Isso me gerou uma estranheza, pois o VSCode me dá um auxilio de tipos quando chamo o `get_self` sem passar a anotação de tipos na definição de método:

[image: VSCode mostrando que o método retorna "Foo"]

Eu sei que Python não é uma linguagem estaticamente tipada e que as anotações de tipos são apenas *Type Hints*, mas fiquei curiosos se nesse caso é possível adicionar um *Type Hint* para o próprio tipo da classe, a nível de código e de maneira explícita, igualmente feito no exemplo acima em TypeScript.

- Existe alguma forma de se fazer essa tipagem para o `self`?
- Algo como `def get_self(self) -> self:` ou `def get_self(self) -> Self:` parecem não funcionar também.

Comment: Não sei responder isso, me parece estranho mesmo, provavelmente alguém saberá. ´Já tentou tipar p `self` nos parâmetros? Só queria dizer que Python é fortemente tipada. Ela não é estaticamente tipada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101.

Comment: No momento estou impossibilitado de escrever uma resposta. Deixo essa documentação para auxiliar quem estiver disposto a responder a pergunta https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partir do **Python 3.11**, você pode usar [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self), conforme definido pela [PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673):

```py
from typing import Self

class Foo:
    # __init__, demais métodos, etc...

    def get_self(self) -> Self:
        return self
```

Em versões anteriores, você pode usar [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), mas não fica tão "limpo":

```py
from typing import TypeVar
SelfFoo = TypeVar("SelfFoo", bound="Foo")

class Foo:
    # __init__, demais métodos, etc...

    def get_self(self) -> SelfFoo:
        return self
```

Ou, de acordo com a [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references), também é possível usar uma string com o nome da classe:

```py
class Foo:
    # __init__, demais métodos, etc...

    def get_self(self) -> 'Foo':
        return self
```

E só para constar, quando você tenta fazer `def get_self(self) -> Foo`, dá erro porque o nome `Foo` não está disponível naquele momento. Isso porque [as classes são criadas em *runtime*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#:%7E:text=they%20are%20created%20at%20runtime), ou seja, quando o corpo do método está sendo avaliado, o nome da própria classe ainda não está disponível (pois ela ainda não terminou de ser criada).

---

Referência: [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533148)

Comment: Existe algum motivo para ter que fazer isso e não ser automático permitir isso?

Comment: @Maniero Entendo que seja porque [as classes são criadas em *runtime*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#:~:text=they%20are%20created%20at%20runtime). Ou seja, quando o corpo do método está sendo avaliado, o nome da própria classe ainda não está disponível (pois ela ainda não terminou de ser criada). Na resposta é dito isso, mas vou melhorar o texto pra deixar mais claro.