# Qual é a finalidade do void em C?

Tags: c, ponteiro, tipagem, void

Tenho dúvidas a respeito do uso do `void` em funções.

1° Exemplo:

```
int somaV(int valor_1, int valor_2)
{
    return valor_1 + valor_2;
}
```

Eu sei que esta função irá me retornar um inteiro que é a soma dos dois parâmetros na função `valor_1` e `valor_2`.

2° Exemplo:

```
void* soma(int valor_1, int valor_2)
{
    return (int) valor_1 + valor_2;
}
```

Eu vi em um programa que continha uma implementação parecida como a do segundo exemplo acima que usei para ilustrar a situação que testemunhei do uso do `void`. Eu testei a função `soma()` e ela retorna a soma dos dois parâmetros mesmo tendo o `void` especificado como retorno ou seja vazio.

Isto me deixou confuso em relação ao uso do `void`, eu pensava que servia somente para dizer que uma função não vai ter retorno nenhum ou não irá receber nenhum parâmetro como este exemplo `soma(void)`.

Afinal de contas qual é a finalidade deste comando em C? O uso do `void*` especificado como ponteiro pode retornar valores mesmo sendo `void`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

O retorno `void` significa ausência de retorno. Já um tipo `void *` significa um ponteiro genérico, um ponteiro de um tipo desconhecido ou não especificado, um ponteiro para qualquer coisa, um endereço de memória qualquer.

Eles aparecem bastante na linguagem C, embora nem sempre o programador os perceba. Por exemplo, a função `malloc` retorna um ponteiro do tipo `void *`:

```
int *meu_numero = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Aqui, o retorno de `malloc` é do tipo `void *`. O cast para `int *` é necessário para que você diga ao verificador de tipos do compilador para considerar que o valor retornado (que o compilador vai saber ser `void *`) deve ser considerado como sendo um `int *`. Neste caso, você recebe um ponteiro de tipo desconhecido e depois diz para o compilador qual é o tipo. Uma prova disso, é que esse mesmo código pode ser escrito de outra forma equivalente, denunciando o `void *`:

```
void *algum_ponteiro = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *meu_numero = (int *) algum_ponteiro;
```

O `void *` também pode aparecer como um parâmetro, tal como na função `free`. A função `free` pode receber qualquer tipo de ponteiro, não importando qual é o tipo exato do objeto que é apontado. Por causa disso o tipo do seu parâmetro também é `void *`.

Outras funções também usam ou produzem ponteiros do tipo `void *`, em especial aquelas que trabalham com coisas na memória sem querer saber exatamente que coisas são essas, e sim apenas que se trata de alguma região na memória. Exemplo de funções como essa são a `fread`, `fwrite`, `memset`, entre muitas outras.

Comment: +1.
Apenas um detalhe: não é uma boa prática fazer cast do retorno do malloc em C, apesar de ser obrigatório em C++. Uma boa argumentação aqui (em inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1796236

Comment: @Pablo Sim, excelente observação.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, vou ter muita informação boa a respeito do void.

Answer (score 19):

O `void *` estritamente significa um ponteiro para nada. Mas ele é melhor interpretado como ponteiro para qualquer coisa. Ou seja, esta é uma forma de generalizar um tipo, de deixar de especificar o tipo.

Quando o usa significa que você pode trabalhar com qualquer tipo de dado ali. Ele simplesmente aponta para um endereço de memória e é problema do programador que receberá isto saber tratar de forma adequada e provavelmente fazer um *cast* para o tipo desejado, de forma compatível com o que tem lá. Obviamente tragédias podem acontecer se tentar acessar de forma inadequada. Chama-se [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

É preciso cuidado quando usa ele porque perde uma das vantagens do C. É uma forma de criar dinamismo em uma linguagem estaticamente tipada. Também é uma forma de polimorfismo.

Note que você está retornando um ponteiro.

```
int x;
float y;
char * z;

void * var;
var = &x;
var = &y;
var = &z; //ou dependo da intenção: var = z;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Void.c).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @bigown.

Answer (score 16):

Ponteiros `void*` precedem C++ e *templates* como um mecanismo para lidar com tipos "genéricos" em C. Para ser mais específico `void` representa a ausência de tipo, que pode ser entendida como a presença de qualquer tipo.
Como você já descobriu, é possível atribuir um `int`, `char` ou qualquer outro tipo a um `void*`.

Com `void*` funções que não precisam saber os detalhes do tipo podem fazer seu trabalho. O programador, que conhece o tipo, pode fazer os *casts* necessários. Veja que ausência de tipos basicamente coloca a responsabilidade sobre tipagem nas costas do programador .

#Por que isso é útil?

Um dos melhores exemplos de uso de `void*` é a função `qsort`, cuja assinatura é:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

Com o `qsort` podemos ordenar um array `base` de qualquer tipo. Você só precisa definir uma função do tipo `int(const void*, const void*)` capaz de comparar os tipos do array `base`.

Exemplo:

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

//...
int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };
qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
```

Você poderia ter um método para comparar `char*`, ou quem sabe para um tipo específico de `struct` ou qualquer outra coisa. Graças a ponteiros `void` a função `qsort` é "genérica".

## Mas e funções que retornam ponteiros void*?

A ideia é a mesma. APIs genéricas podem funcionar com múltiplos tipos de retorno. Um bom exemplo são o par de funções `int pthread_setspecific(pthread_key_t key, const void *value)` e `void *pthread_getspecific(pthread_key_t key)` do [`pthreads.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread.h.html). Você pode armazenar e recuperar qualquer tipo de valor graças ao uso de `void*`.

Outro bons exemplos são as funções *alloc* como bem mencionado nas respostas anteriores. Em c você não precisa e nem deve fazer *cast* do resultado de `malloc` (isso mudou no C++):

```
// C
int *arr= malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
// C++ escrito para ser compatível com C
int *arr= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
// C++ "de verdade"
int *arr= new int[length];
// C++11 - Melhor ainda, esqueça o delete
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[10]);
```

---

- [http://www.cplusplus.com/ - qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)
- [Open Group - pthread_setspecific](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_getspecific.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, assim que eu chegar da faculdade eu vou analisar melhor o conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Quando usado como um tipo de retorno de função, a void palavra-chave especifica que a função não retorna um valor. Quando usado para a lista de parâmetros de uma função, void especifica que a função não usa nenhum parâmetro. Quando usado na declaração de um ponteiro, void especifica que o ponteiro é "Universal"

fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/cpp/void-cpp?view=msvc-160