# Diferença entre void e void*

Tags: c, c++

Qual a diferença entre o void* e o void como tipo de **retorno de uma função**?

Exemplo 1:

```
void *func_nome(int param){
      ...
  }
```

Exemplo 2:

```
void func_nome(int param){
      ...
  }
```

Comment: @LuizVieira deu pra entender o que é (void *) mas e o (void) ? e em relação a ser uma função, e não uma váriavel

Comment: Vc quer dizer em relação "ao retorno" de uma função (funções recebem 0 ou mais valores e retornam um valor). Seja como retorno ou como parâmetro, o tipo dos valores envolvidos precisam ser definidos. E aí se encontra a distinção, que já está explicada na outra pergunta. É que não estava claro que você também não sabia o que o `void` sozinho significa. Considerando isso, eu tirei o meu voto pra fechar.

Comment: Encontrei a resposta em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97138/qual-%c3%a9-a-finalidade-do-void-em-c

Answer (score 4):

Ao se declarar uma função em C, C++ (e outras linguagens derivadas, como Java e C#) é sempre necessário declarar o tipo de retorno da função. `void` é um tipo especial para indicar que a função não retorna nenhum valor. Significa literalmente "nada". É o que algumas outras linguagens (como Pascal) definiriam como um procedimento (`procedure`).

Qualquer `tipo*` indica um ponteiro para aquele tipo. Por exemplo: `int*` é um ponteiro para inteiro e `char*` é um ponteiro para caractere. Mas `void*` não é um ponteiro para "nada". Trata-se de um caso especial. Ele indica um ponteiro para qualquer tipo, como se fosse um coringa. É usando quando não se sabe qual o tipo de dado está sendo apontado. É utilizado, por exemplo, como retorno da função `malloc`, porque a memória que ela aloca pode ser utilizada para qualquer tipo de dado. Cabe ao programador depois fazer a coerção para o tipo pretendido.