# Como um array de funções reconhece a posição do próxmo elemento?

Tags: c, array, c++, funções, ponteiro

### O porquê da pergunta:

A pergunta pode parecer estranha, mas é que sou iniciante em programação e neste momento estou estudando **ponteiros para função** e em um exemplo no livro pelo qual estudo é apresentado a possibilidade de criar ponteiros para função e armazena-los em um *array*, entre um de seus propósitos estaria a criação de um sistema controlado por um menu de opções.

## Código:

*Obs: não vou colocar todo o código aqui, mas só o que acho ser o suficiente para elaborar a pergunta. Se o leitor achar necessário, o código-exemplo completo retirado do livro se encontra ao final do texto.*

Primeiramente é definido um array de ponteiros de função do tipo void que recebem um argumento do tipo inteiro:

```
void (*f[ 3 ])( int ) = { function1, function2, function3 };
```

Através de um *prompt* o usuário informa um inteiro que é armazenado em uma variável com identificador *choice*. Essa mesma variável é utilizada no subscrito do array de ponteiro de função:

```
(*f[ choice ])( choice );
```

A função contida na posição *choice* do *array* é executada com a atribuição de um parâmetro inteiro. Daí vem minha dúvida:

## Pergunta:

É uma pergunta bem teórica, de fato, mas gostaria de entender como o compilador C reconhece o espaço em bytes que deve percorrer na memória para acessar outra função, pois até onde sei, o subscrito de um *array* em C é apenas um operador que adiciona um inteiro seguindo a **aritmética de ponteiro** - *Se obedecer essa lógica*, no exemplo apresentado deveria ser percorrido `(**choices * qtd. bytes de uma função**)`.

> C: como programar / Paul Deitel, Harvey Deitel ; -- 6. ed, 2011. **pág. 269**.

```
/* Fig. 7.28: fig07_28.c
Demonstrando um array de ponteiros para funções */
#include <stdio.h>

/* protótipos */
void function1( int a );
void function2( int b );
void function3( int c );

int main( void )
{
    /* inicializa array de 3 ponteiros para funções que usam um
    argumento int e retornam void */
    void (*f[ 3 ])( int ) = { function1, function2, function3 };

    int choice; /* variável para manter escolha do usuário */

    printf( "Digite um número entre 0 e 2, 3 para sair: " );
    scanf( "%d", &choice );

    /* processa escolha do usuário */
    while ( choice >= 0 && choice < 3 ) {

        /* chama a função para o local selecionado do array f e passa
        choice como argumento */
        (*f[ choice ])( choice );

        printf( "Digite um número entre 0 e 2, 3 para terminar: ");
        scanf( “%d”, &choice );
    } /* fim do while */

    printf( "Execução do programa concluída.\n" );
    return 0; /* indica conclusão bem-sucedida */
} /* fim do main */

void function1( int a )
{
   printf( "Você digitou %d, de modo que function1 foi chamada\n\n", a );
} /* fim de function1 */

void function2( int b )
{
   printf( "Você digitou %d, de modo que function2 foi chamada\n\n", b );
} /* fim de function2 */

void function3( int c )
{
   printf( "Você digitou %d, de modo que function3 foi chamada\n\n", c );
} /* fim de function3 */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me parece uma questão de interpretação de texto. Leia novamente o nome do mecanismo. Ele é um **ponteiro para função**. Então ele é um **ponteiro**, certo?

Todo dado pode ter seu tamanho obtido com o operador `sizeof`. E neste caso é bom usá-lo mesmo que saiba o tamanho de antemão porque vai que compile em outra arquitetura e o tamanho mude.

Você poderia pegar o tamanho do ponteiro para função, mas o tamanho do ponteiro não muda de acordo com o que ele está apontando, o ponteiro só tem um tamanho. Então acho seguro, se não tiver uma mecanismo seu muito criativo, usar um `sizeof(void *)` para pegar o tamanho do ponteiro. O [`void`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97138/101) é um tipo coringa. Pode usar também algo como `sizeof(function1)`.

Na esmagadora maioria dos casos será 4 ou 8 bytes (mais comum hoje em dia). Existem raros casos hoje que pode ser 2 bytes e outros tamanhos são bem esotéricos.

Parece que está achando que esse *array* de ponteiros tem a função nele. Mas não é isso que ocorre, o ponteiro, por definição, é um mecanismo de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), ele aponta para outro lugar, e uma das suas utilidades é justamente ter uma forma do mesmo tamanho indicar coisas de tamanhos diferentes. Talvez esteja faltando entendimento do que é um ponteiro:

[image: Diagrama de como o ponteiro aponta]

Um *array* precisa de linearidade de tamanho, todos seus elementos precisam ter seu tamanho igual. Funções (o código de máquina mesmo) possuem tamanhos diferentes, então não pode colocar funções no *array*, nem faria muito sentido também, por isso o ponteiro é usado. Imagino que entende isso se entende da aritmética de ponteiro.

Se prestar bem atenção ao mecanismo, funções naturalmente possuem ponteiros, mesmo as funções normais são sempre chamadas através de um ponteiro. Quando compila não vai o nome, ou o corpo da função (em código fonte ou código binário), vai o ponteiro relativo de onde está função.

Então, considerando uma arquitetura de 64 bits.

```
void (*f[ 3 ])( int ) = { function1, function2, function3 };
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Array.c).

`f` é a variável com um dado que possui 24 bytes, portanto ele terá o endereço onde está alocado os bytes executáveis dessas três funções.

Para o seu código o nome da função é um símbolo que internamente o compilador sabe que é um ponteiro para algum endereço da memória onde ele colocará a função. Esse endereço pode mudar por várias razões.

O compilador pode reservar o espaço e colocar o endereço efetivo só depois quando ele souber o endereço que a função ficará.

O [*linker*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101) certamente mudará esse valor porque junto com outras coisas o endereço da função será outro.

E quando for executar a função entrará em um local ainda a ser determinado naquele momento (nem sempre mudará o endereço da função porque ele pode ser relativo a um endereço base, depende de implementação).

Na verdade a forma exata de como funciona sempre dependerá de como o compilador achou melhor fazer e não ser que a especificação da linguagem exija uma forma específica de fazer em algum ponto. Mas o básico é isso, não dá para fazer algo útil de forma tão criativa que fuja muito disso.

Comment: Entendi, na verdade é muito mais simples do que eu pensava. O que eu tenho ali são ponteiro que contém uma lista de ponteiros, seria algo assim? Quando eu coloco o nome da função na verdade eu já estou me referindo a um ponteiro para função. No exemplo, o ponteiro f apontaria pera outros três ponteiros para função: function1, function2 e function3, cada um em um espaço de 8 bytes (que foi o que obtive com sizeof). Meu pensamento está correto? Quando formulei a pergunta não tinha total ciência de que o próprio nome da função era um ponteiro. Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: `Quando eu coloco o nome da função na verdade eu já estou me referindo a um ponteiro para função` sim. `o ponteiro f apontaria pera outros três ponteiros para função` sim. O nome da função é um símbolo para um endereço, o nome em si não é o ponteiro, mas tem um endereço ali que se comporta como um ponteiro. Depois de compilado nomes desaparecem.

Answer (score 2):

Uma lista de ponteiros para funções contém apenas ponteiros, não o "corpo" das funções. E geralmente os ponteiros para funções têm o mesmo tamanho dos ponteiros para qualquer outro objeto.

Nem há forma fácil de descobrir o tamanho do corpo da função de dentro do programa (e, se houvesse, não seria útil para nada).