# Número dividido por um divisor maior que ele retorna zero?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu fui fazer um cálculo no Python 2.7 e me assustei ao ver o resultado:

```
 val = 1 / 16
 print(val); # 0
```

Exemplo no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/vaLYCG)

Ou seja, quando fazemos uma divisão onde o número divido é menor que o divisor, o resultado retornado é zero.

- Como faço pra obter o resultado em `float`?
- Por que o Python se comporta dessa maneira?

Comment: No Python 3 isso mudou. Pelo que li sobre essa mudança, foi justamente porque tornava o entendimento confuso. Agora, em Python 3, a divisão inteira é outro operador: `val = 1 // 16`; as duas barras `//` representam a divisão inteira

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Divisão de inteiros, retorna inteiro. Faça com que um deles seja do tipo `float`:

```
val = float(1) / 16
print(val);

#saida: 0.0625
```

Ou então força a mudança do comportamento do operador `/` para que seja igual ao do `python3.x`:

```
from __future__ import division

val = 1/16
print(val);

#saida: 0.0625
```

- [SOen - Python division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division)

Comment: *Divisão de inteiros, retorna inteiro.*... PHP e Javascript são exceção :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Agora ri a sério.

Comment: Na verdade, esse comportamento é desconcertanete numa linguagem de tipagem dinâmica como Python. Tanto que arrumaram no Python 3 - mas é um dos únicos casos em que o Python faz a conversão de tipos automaticamente.

Answer (score 6):

Em quase toda linguagem a divisão de números inteiros resulta em um número inteiro. Para garantir que a operação resulte em um número com ponto flutuante deve ter pelo menos um dos operandos como `float`, portanto precisa colocar um ponto decimal em um deles. Isto é [tipagem forte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

```
val = 1.0 / 16
print(val); # 0
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KBg9Kv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nmffimzf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/FloatDivision.py).

Comment: Não é a regra em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica. E, valeria ter citado que o comportamento mudou no Python 3.  Pra quem ainda precisa usar Python 2, forçar o comportamento com menos surpresas com `from __future__ import division` é melhor do que ficar se preocupando com conversão explícita em todas as divisões. (Python tem tipagem dinâmica, mas forte - a divisão, no Python 3, se tornou a exceção que confirma a regra)

Comment: Isso nada tem a ver com a linguagem ser dinâmica ou não, tem a ver com ela ter tipagem forte ou não. Quando uma linguagem quer dizer que tem tipagem forte deveria cumprir isto. Quando faz o certo inicialmente e depois decide ir pro lado errado demonstra falta de direção. Cada um pode fazer o que achar melhor, mas operação com um tipo não deveria gerar outro tipo a não ser que a linguagem se declare de tipagem fraca.