# A tipagem no PHP interfere no desempenho de uma aplicação?

Tags: php, tipagem

Por curiosidade, e por usar muito isso sem saber direito se é necessário, definir o tipo da variável é uma coisa que eu faço em 100% do meu código.

Geralmente é definido por algo como isso:

```
class classe 
{
    private $dado;

    public function dado(int $dado = 1)
    {
        $this->dado = (int) $dado;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Ou em casos raros onde não há orientação a objeto:

```
$var = (int) 1;
```

A dúvida é:

> Definir tipos em 100% do código reduz ou melhora o desempenho ? (mesmo
>   que o ganho ou perca de desempenho seja irrisória)

E uma segunda dúvida é:

> Vale a pena validar o tipo ?

Exemplo:

```
class classe 
    {
        private $dado;

        public function dado(int $dado = 1)
        {
            if(is_int($dado) == true)
            {
                $this->dado = (int) $dado;
            }else
            {
                $this->dado = die('Tipo não suportado');
            }     
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

PS: No exemplo em questão que estou tentando melhorar o desempenho se trata de uma camada de abstração pra construção de páginas com  CSS Bootstrap 4 + JS.

Comment: Se o argumento do método foi definido como `int`, qual seria a função do *cast* para `int` em seu corpo? O parâmetro já será `int`, então é desnecessário. Isso se agrava ainda mais no segundo exemplo: você define o argumento como `int`, verifica se ele é `int` e, se for, faz o *cast* para `int`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É que o código em questão que eu utilizo essa ultima opção, é um código que não me da um resultado, é só uma camada de construção, eu utilizo esses métodos em outro código, só assim eu passaria a ter um resposta, então saber exatamente onde foi e qual foi o erro é uma parte importante do processo, mas voltando ao que você disse, definir o tipo no parâmetro é o suficiente pra todo o método ?

Comment: Se você ja faz a conversão dele pra int no parâmetro, não vejo necessidade do if e else.

Comment: Definir o tipo do argumento já garante que para qualquer outro tipo informado seja gerado um `TypeError`.

Comment: Se você força tipos em 100% do seu código PHP, é sinal de que deveria estar usando outra linguagem, de tipagem forte. Sobre a sua dúvida, encontrei informações em inglês [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940170/are-scalar-and-strict-types-in-php7-a-performance-enhancing-feature) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308391/will-type-declaration-in-functions-make-my-code-perform-better).

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu cheguei a cogitar isso, pois o PHP da muita 'liberdade' pra quem está programando, mas uma pergunta de idiota, que outra linguagem consegue substituir o php (substituir no quesito de ter uma semântica parecida) para trabalhar apenas com web ?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/57801