# Declarar uma variável utilizando var ou o próprio tipo?

Tags: java, variáveis, dart

Comecei a estudar Dart e me deparei com este questionamento. Em java, sempre é utilizado o tipo na declaração de uma variável. Entretanto, o Dart permite você declarar tanto utilizando "var" quanto o tipo da variável, salvo algumas exceções. Qual seria a forma mais correta/mais legível? Na minha opinião (sou suspeito por já programar em Java), o mais correto seria já especificar o tipo da variável em sua declaração, uma vez que deixaria mais especificado sua função, tornando mais claro e legível o código. Só que se existe essa possibilidade de realizar declarações com "var", algo de bom que eu não estou conseguindo enxergar deve ter. Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: "*Em java, sempre é utilizado o tipo na declaração de uma variável.*" - Isso até o Java 9. No Java 10, você pode declarar com `var`. E parâmetros de lambdas nunca precisaram de declaração de tipo explícita (exceto em uns poucos casos) desde que foram introduzidos no Java 8.

Comment: Entendo, estou por fora dessa nova atualização... mas e quanto à pergunta?

Comment: Sugiro leitura: [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21508/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1tica-e-din%C3%A2mica)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Em java, sempre é utilizado o tipo na declaração de uma variável.

Isso até o Java 9. No Java 10, você pode declarar com `var`. E parâmetros de lambdas nunca precisaram de declaração de tipo explícita (exceto em uns poucos casos) desde que foram introduzidos no Java 8.

Saber qual é mais legível depende muito e é algo subjetivo. Depende do que você quer fazer com o código. Por exemplo:

```
String x = "abc";
String z = "def";
System.out.println(x + z);
```

Ou:

```
var x = "abc";
var z = "def";
System.out.println(x + z);
```

O segundo é mais legível, pois é óbvio pelo contexto que a variável é do tipo `String`. Para exemplificar com um caso mais extremo:

```
Map<String, List<FuncionarioEmpresaDTO>> x = criaUmMapDosFuncionários();
umOutroMétodoQueRecebeOMapDosFuncionários(x);
maisOutroMétodoQueRecebeOMapDosFuncionários(x);
```

Fica mais simples com isso:

```
var x = criaUmMapDosFuncionários();
umOutroMétodoQueRecebeOMapDosFuncionários(x);
maisOutroMétodoQueRecebeOMapDosFuncionários(x);
```

No entanto, isso nem sempre é verdadeiro:

```
var x = métodoMuitoLoucoQueRetornaTudoOqueVocêImagina();
var y = x.métodoQueVocêNemSabiaQueExistia();
System.out.println(y);
```

Neste caso aí, o uso do `var` deixou o código mais obscuro.

Enfim, cada caso é um caso. O uso do `var` pode deixar o código mais enxuto ou mais obscuro. Como qualquer outro recurso, é algo que deve ser usado com bom-senso.

Comment: Entendo. Então seria uma má prática sempre definir o tipo?

Comment: @LongJohnson Atualizei a resposta. Cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi perfeitamente!