# Reaproveitamento de variáveis

Tags: variáveis, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

Me surgiu uma dúvida no que concerne à otimização de código. Parto do princípio de que quanto mais enxuto o código, mas rápido o algoritmo será compilado e executado.

Partindo desse princípio, tenho o costume de reaproveitar variáveis já declaradas. Um exemplo simples para ilustrar, em JavaScript faria o seguinte:

```js
var variavel = "Maria, João";
if(~variavel.indexOf("João")){
   variavel = true;
}else{
   variavel = false;
}

console.log(variavel);
```

Considerando que o valor inicial de `variavel` não será mais necessário posteriormente no código, eu reaproveitei ela para redefinir `true` ou `false` em outra situação. Poderia ter feito assim, declarando uma nova variável `existe` e mantendo a variável `variavel` intacta:

```js
var variavel = "Maria, João";
if(~variavel.indexOf("Joao")){
   var existe = true;
}else{
   var existe = false;
}

console.log(existe);
```

Isso é só um exemplo hipotético, mas considere um algoritmo com centenas de linhas usando esse reaproveitamento de variáveis que, estruturalmente, me permita fazer isso.

Sem se prender a JavaScript especificamente, gostaria de saber em relação às linguagens em geral:

1. Todas as linguagens (ou a maioria) permite esse reaproveitamento de variável?
2. Isso é uma boa prática?
3. Há considerável melhoria em consumo de recursos (memória,
   compilação, execução), ou seja, quanto menos variáveis declaradas, melhor o código em termos de consumo de recursos ou performance?

Comment: Linguagens fortemente tipadas, como java, sem chance de isso ocorrer, ainda mais reaproveitando tipos diferentes.

Comment: @ArticunoL Python é fortemente tipada e permite isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101 Se for do mesmo tipo até Java permite.

Comment: @Maniero quis dizer com os exemplos citados na pergunta. Sem chance de uma variavel String virar boolean assim do nada em java.

Comment: 1. Não; 2. Carece da definição de boa prática; 3. Num geral não há e, mesmo que haja, não vale a pena perder a legibilidade por um ganho, possivelmente, ínfimo.

Comment: @LINQ Obg! Esclarece mais a pergunta. Valeu!

Comment: 1) Todas não, pois as fortemente tipadas só permitem que a variável armazene valores de um tipo ou de subclasses de uma mesma classe. 2) Não, isso acaba com a clareza do código. 3) Não, na maioria das vezes o benefício é desprezível, somente se beneficia disso em casos de grande volume de dados economizados e possíveis reduções relevantes de operações.

Comment: @RHERWOLF legal! Obg pelas explicações.

Comment: Aliás, linguagens como C e C++, que permitem criar escopos onde quiser e neles criar variáveis locais restritas a eles oferecem com isso um controle de tempo de vida de variáveis, o que permite que uma variável em uma região da memória suma e logo depois esse espaço pode ser ocupado por outra que passe pelo mesmo processo, assim não precisando tirar a clareza do código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Parto do princípio de que quanto mais enxuto o código, mas rápido o algoritmo será compilado e executado.

Já partiu de um **princípio errado**. Existem diversos algoritmos complicados que executam rápido justamente por serem sofisticados (ex.: um algoritmo de ordenação que se adapte a listas pequenas, médias ou grandes). E existem muitos algoritmos enxutos mas burros que são lentos por serem simplórios (ex.: um bubble sort, ou um fibonacci de 1 linha que usa duas recursões e refaz uma quantidade imensa de cálculos já feitos).

> 1. Todas as linguagens (ou a maioria) permite esse reaproveitamento de variável?

**Não**. Linguagens com tipos estáticos não permitirão que a variável mude de tipo. Linguagens funcionais com foco em imutabilidade exigirão que você crie uma nova variável no lugar da antiga. Em Erlang, por exemplo, você precisará escolher outro nome ou usar recursão. Em F# você pode fazer dois ou mais let x = ..., mas serão conceitualmente variáveis diferentes (a última oculta a anterior).

> 2. Isso é uma boa prática?

**Não**, nem um pouco. Se você tem outro conceito, melhor usar outro nome (portanto, outra variável). Talvez fosse uma boa prática nos processadores de 8 ou 16 bits. Hoje, não mais. Só seria justificável fazer isso caso fosse testado e comprovado que *em tal programa, em tal linguagem* o reaproveitamento economiza bytes cruciais para o desempenho.

> 3. Há considerável melhoria em consumo de recursos (memória, compilação, execução), ou seja, quanto menos variáveis declaradas, melhor o código em termos de consumo de recursos ou performance?

**Não** também. Cada variável pode ocupar uma quantidade diferente de recursos. Não vai ser economizando variáveis que você vai conseguir melhorar o desempenho, seja de compilação, seja de execução.

Além do mais, se você criar funções pequenas, você não precisará se preocupar com reaproveitar variáveis, pois tudo aquilo que você não retornar deixará de existir no fim da função (ou logo depois, assim que o garbage collector rodar)!

Lembre-se que um byte não ocupa o mesmo que um Object, que não ocupa o mesmo que um MemoryMappedFile ou Socket, então **o número de variáveis é o que menos importa**. No caso de arquivos ou sockets, o que economizaria recursos seria fechá-los (com .close() ou algo equivalente) assim que não fossem mais usados. Reaproveitar a variável teria um efeito insignificante, pois o que realmente consome/libera recursos são os procedimentos de abrir/fechar os arquivos ou conexões.

Outro exemplo que explica por que não reutilizar variáveis são os **JIT**s: se o compilador JIT observar que você apenas declarou function f() {...}, ele poderá chamar a função de forma eficiente com poucas verificações adicionais. Entretanto, se no mesmo código você fizer `f = 1.0;` ou `delete f;` o código precisará ser *desotimizado* para primeiro verificar o tipo de f, chamá-la se for uma função ou gerar "f is not a function" ou "f is not defined" caso contrário. Esse é um dos motivos por que o "use strict" do JavaScript proíbe o programador de redefinir elementos essenciais da linguagem (como `eval` ou `arguments`) e de chamar delete em algumas situações. Situações muito dinâmicas são um empecilho para otimizadores.

Answer (score 14):

> Parto do princípio de que quanto mais enxuto o código, mas rápido o algoritmo será compilado e executado

Isso não é uma verdade absoluta, a maneira como a maioria das pessoas que programam em JavaScript faz tende a deixar o código mais lento justamente porque é enxuto. Ocorre também em outras linguagens, mas em JS costuma ser pior.

Do ponto de vista de legibilidade não deveria reaproveitar variáveis para fazer mais de uma coisa, não há benefício algum de performance se fizer bem feito. Mas no exemplo faz pouca diferença porque o nome já é ruim (eu sei que é só exemplo, mas a pergunta fala em boa prática e estilo de codificação, então o exemplo não é bom).

O primeiro exemplo é terrível para legibilidade, qualquer manutenção futura tende a criar algum problema se acabar precisando da variável em algum outro ponto e o programador não perceber que ela é reaproveitada.

> Todas as linguagens (ou a maioria) permite esse reaproveitamento de variável?

Se o valor for do mesmo tipo todas permitem, não tem como a linguagem entender sua intenção, não há como o compilador saber que aquilo é um reaproveitamento. Se for de outro tipo só as linguagem de [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) permitem.

> Isso é uma boa prática?

Muitos já sabem o que eu penso sobre o assunto e tenho até palestra consagrada criticando boas práticas. Mas de forma geral não deveria fazer isto, é muito difícil justificar o reaproveitamento da variável, e duvido que alguém produza mais que desculpas esfarrapadas ou argumentos sem fundamento para indicar o uso. Claro, em uma tecnologia específica pode haver algo que eu não sei de antemão que possa justificar.

> Há considerável melhoria em consumo de recursos (memória, compilação, execução), ou seja, quanto menos variáveis declaradas, melhor o código em termos de consumo de recursos ou performance?

O ganho, quando houver, será irrisório. Em linguagem de *script* o ganho será maior, porém, é o que eu falo sempre, quem escolheu uma linguagem deste tipo não quer economizar recursos, caso contrário fez uma opção errada e aí tudo será gambiarra, já em linguagem mais de sistemas ou *enterprise* terão ganhos mínimos ou inexistentes, especialmente se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo. A economia depende da tecnologia adotada e até da versão dela ou alguma configuração.

Em linguagens com [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) corretamente implementado o segundo exemplo não funciona também porque a variável criada dentro do `if` só existe lá mesmo.

Comment: É, o lance do escopo eu entendi. Caso usasse `let` eu teria que declarar a variável fora do `if`. Mas foi só um exemplo qualquer mesmo. :)... Mas mt boas as explicações, vou absorvendo as informações. Obg!

Comment: Não leve a mal, mas acho que vc foi mt além da pergunta, como no último parágrafo. rs.. eu dei apenas um exemplo, como frisei, "hipotético". Entre outras afirmativas que eu não concordo, mas não vou entrar em polêmicas. Absorvi o que é absorvível.

Comment: @Sam a pergunta é sobre estilo de codificação, e sobre boa prática, não se pode falar sobre o assunto corretamente com exemplos artificiais hipotéticos de forma adequada. Se eu simplesmente ignorar esses problemas no código, inclusive os outros que eu disse, quem ler isso vai achar que o exemplo é bom e vai começar fazer assim. Um dos motivos das pessoas programarem tão mal é porque elas sempre veem exemplos hipotéticos artificiais mal elaborados. Elas não conseguem discernir o que é artificial e o que é o real.O maior motivo porque quase ninguém sabe OOP (quase todos exemplos são artificiais)

Comment: como eu disse, não vou entrar em polêmica.  Abs!

Comment: @Sam para não entrar em polêmicas você não deve falar nada, quando você fala já entrou. Entrar ou não é uma decisão sua, só seja coerente. E acho uma pena não concordar com outras coisas porque tudo o que eu disse são fatos ou coisas consagradas por todos os melhores programadores (a não ser o fato de não seguir boas práticas, mas isso quando a pessoa vê minha palestra sempre concorda, só não é consagrado porque não é algo universalmente falado). Como não especificou não sei se discorda dos fatos ou das consagradas. Mas novamente cada programador escreve seus códigos como quiser.

Comment: Maniero, dá uma lida no meu último comentário. Desejo a vc o melhor dia que vc pode ter na vida. Abs!

Comment: @Sam eu li e respondi justamente sobre isso, acho que você não leu o meu para repetir o que disse. Você anda discursando que aprendeu muita coisa, mas não parece ser o caso. Se você vai escrever que discorda de algo e não vai falar o que é só suja sua imagem, algo que você tem muita preocupação, por isso ou você não diz nada, ou fala por completo, caso contrário o único objetivo de ter escrito é causa polêmica, só pela polêmica, não é nem para debater um assunto técnico. Fica a dica para próxima, essa já é tarde demais.

Comment: Minha reclamação é só com a incoerência de dizer que não quer entrar em polêmica e ser a única coisa que fez escrevendo isto. Não aceitar a resposta é um direito seu, não me importo com isso, as pessoas vão ler e saber do conteúdo, isso é importante. O motivo por não aceitar é outra incoerência, mas é um direito seu.