# declare(strict_types=1); exibir os erros

Tags: php, tipagem, php-7

Estou começando a usar linguagem **fortemente tipada** no PHP 7.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

Mas não achei uma forma de debugar o erro e exibir onde ele está.

Procurei bastante mas não encontrei.

O que devo usar?

Já tentei:

```
 ini_set("display_errors",true);
 ini_set("display_startup_erros",true);
 error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE );
```

E não consigo exibir os erros de `declare(strict_types=1);`

A ideia é, se eu fizer:

```
public function verNumero (int $num) : int {
   return $num++;
}
```

e chamar o método assim:

```
echo verNumero('7')
```

em vez de

```
echo verNumero(7)
```

Isso me trará um erro que sem:

```
ini_set("display_errors",true);
ini_set("display_startup_erros",true);
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE );
```

não seria possível saber onde está. Pelo contrário, a página nem abriria.

O que eu quero é saber qual tipo de controlador de exibição de erros colocar no código para que eu possa ver onde está o erro ao invés de uma página em branco quando usar:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

Comment: PHP nunca foi e nunca será fortemente tipada, no máximo ela pode agora ter checagem de tipos e se aproxima de tipagem estática. Para ser fortemente tipada ela teria que mudar sua semântica e quebraria vários códigos existentes. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101 Fora isto não sei o que deseja, o que está acontecendo de errado a pergunta não deixa claro qual é o real problema.

Comment: adicionei mais detalhes à pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sintaxe da função [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) está errada. Dê atenção para o comentário acima para entender melhor o conceito todo do que quer fazer.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
ini_set("display_errors", '1');
ini_set("display_startup_errors", '1');
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE ); 
function verNumero (int $num) : int {
   return $num++;
}
echo verNumero('7');
echo verNumero(7);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/87VIGt). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DisplayErrorOn). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/DisplayErrorOn.php).

Comment: Ah sim. Mas... e a resposta à pergunta? Você saberia me responder?

Comment: Acabei de responder e mostrei funcionando conforme disse que queria.

Comment: hum então a solução é lançar o declare acima dos ini_set? Deu certo aqui, O erro parou. Mas pode explicar o porque que colocando o declare abaixo  página dá erro? Mas a principio obrigado, resolveu o problema. Isso deve ser que não tem erros de tipo no meu código.

Comment: Sim algo que afeta a semântica da linguagem tem que ser a primeira coisa a ser declarada, isto é uma instrução para o compilador lidar tudo diferentemente.

Comment: Eu poderia fazer ini_set("strict_types", '1');  ao invés de declare(strict_types = 1); e ter o mesmo resultado? Porque testei em diferentes  posições do código e não deu problema algum, Mas vai saber se está funcionando! @Maniero

Comment: Esse caso se funcionou está ok.