# Calculadora em Python não retorna a funçao

Tags: python, python-3.x

Comecei a usar Python recentemente e estou criando uma calculadora para treinar fatores como função, input e retorno de função dentro de outra função.

Porém, a minha calculadora não está funcionando, ela simplesmente não retorna nada. Parece que não entra no `if`, mesmo printando que a opção está recebendo o valor.

Poderiam me ajudar a identificar o erro?

```
def calculadora():    
    print("Ola! \n" "Bem vindo a calculadora digital em python! \n" "Por favor, digite a opcaoo:")
    print("Opcao 1: Soma \n Opcao 2: Subtracao \n Opcao 3: Multiplicacao \n Opcao 4: Divisao")
    opcao = input()
    if opcao == 1:
        print("Vamos somar!")
        return soma()
    elif opcao == 2:
        print("Vamos subtrair!")
        return subtracao()
    elif opcao == 3:
        print("Vamos Multiplicar!")
        return multiplicacao()
    elif opcao == 4:
        print("Vamos Dividir!")
        return divisao()
 

def multiplicacao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a multiplicacao")
    n = input()
    m = input()
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n*m)

def soma():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a soma")
    n = input()
    m = input()
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n+m)

def subtracao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a subtracao")
    n = input()
    m = input()
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n-m)

def divisao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a divisao")
    n = input()
    m = input()
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n/m)


calculadora()
```

Comment: `opcao = int(input())`

Comment: Como o @AugustoVasques disse, coloque `opcao = int(input())`, pois o `input()` retorna uma `string`, por isso você tem que colocar o `int()` para converter o valor para `inteiro`

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Answer (score 2):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna uma string, mas você está comparando o retorno dela com um número inteiro (na linha `if opcao == 1`). Para fazer esta comparação da forma correta você pode transformar o retorno em um número (usando `int(input(...))`, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/470752/112052)), ou compará-lo com uma string: `if opcao == '1'`.

Mas acho que tem um jeito melhor. Repare que há muita repetição no código: todas as operações pedem que se digite os valores, e as mensagens são praticamente as mesmas, só mudando o nome da operação. Uma forma melhor seria parametrizar tudo isso e também ler os 2 valores antes de cada função.

Outro detalhe é que você está fazendo `return print(...)`, só que `print` retorna `None` e não faz sentido retornar o resultado de um `print` (ou você retorna o valor, ou imprime ele). No caso de funções, eu prefiro que elas retornem o valor e quem as chamou que decida o que fazer com o retorno (podendo inclusive imprimí-lo).

Enfim, uma sugestão de melhoria:

```
def calculadora(operacoes):
    print("Ola! \n" "Bem vindo a calculadora digital em python! \n" "Por favor, digite a opção:")
    print('\n'.join(f'Opção {i}: {op[0]}' for i, op in operacoes.items()))
    opcao = input()
    if opcao in operacoes:
        nome_operacao, verbo, funcao = operacoes[opcao]
        print(f'Vamos {verbo}!')
        print(f'Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a {nome_operacao}')
        n = int(input())
        m = int(input())
        print(f'O resultado é {funcao(n, m)}')
    else:
        print('opção inválida')

def multiplicacao(n, m):
    return n * m

def soma(n, m):
    return n + m

def subtracao(n, m):
    return n - m

def divisao(n, m):
    return n / m

operacoes = {
    '1': ('soma', 'somar', soma),
    '2': ('subtração', 'subtrair', subtracao),
    '3': ('multiplicação', 'multiplicar', multiplicacao),
    '4': ('divisão', 'dividir', divisao)
}

calculadora(operacoes)
```

Agora a função `calculadora` recebe um dicionário contendo as opções e as respectivas operações (na verdade, cada opção é mapeada para uma tupla contendo os textos relativos ao nome da operação e a função a ser chamada).

Depois, eu leio os números e passo eles como argumentos da função. Repare que cada função retorna o resultado da operação, e quem chamou a função se encarrega de imprimir o valor final (nada de `return print`, que como eu já disse, não faz sentido).

Desta forma fica mais flexível (a função `calculadora` pode receber um dicionário com operações completamente diferentes e ainda sim funcionará da mesma forma) e evita as repetições de código (não preciso mais ler os 2 números dentro de cada função, pois elas apenas recebem os valores que já foram lidos anteriormente - e veja também que nesse caso converti os valores para `int`, caso contrário você estaria fazendo as operações com strings). Se quiser, pode usar também [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) em vez de `int`, caso o programa aceite números com casas decimais.

Answer (score 1):

Troque o `input()` por `int(input())`, pois somente o `input()`, retorna um valor como `string`, o `int()` irá expecificar que a *entrada* é inteira, o código ficaria assim:

```
def calculadora():

    print("Ola! \n" "Bem vindo a calculadora digital em python! \n" "Por favor, digite a opcaoo:")
    print("Opcao 1: Soma \n Opcao 2: Subtracao \n Opcao 3: Multiplicacao \n Opcao 4: Divisao")
    opcao = int(input())
    if opcao == 1:
        print("Vamos somar!")
        return soma()
    elif opcao == 2:
        print("Vamos subtrair!")
        return subtracao()
    elif opcao == 3:
        print("Vamos Multiplicar!")
        return multiplicacao()
    elif opcao == 4:
        print("Vamos Dividir!")
        return divisao()
 

def multiplicacao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a multiplicacao")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n*m)

def soma():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a soma")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n+m)

def subtracao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a subtracao")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n-m)

def divisao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a divisao")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n/m)


calculadora()
```

Ou você pode inves de comparar com um *numero* na *função* `calculadora()`, comparar como `string`, e fazendo a conversão apenas nas outras funções, ficando assim:

```
 def calculadora():

    print("Ola! \n" "Bem vindo a calculadora digital em python! \n" "Por favor, digite a opcaoo:")
    print("Opcao 1: Soma \n Opcao 2: Subtracao \n Opcao 3: Multiplicacao \n Opcao 4: Divisao")
    opcao = input()
    if opcao == '1':
        print("Vamos somar!")
        return soma()
    elif opcao == '2':
        print("Vamos subtrair!")
        return subtracao()
    elif opcao == '3':
        print("Vamos Multiplicar!")
        return multiplicacao()
    elif opcao == '4':
        print("Vamos Dividir!")
        return divisao()


def multiplicacao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a multiplicacao")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n*m)

def soma():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a soma")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n+m)

def subtracao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a subtracao")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n-m)

def divisao():
    print("Agora, digite os valores a serem usados para a divisao")
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    return print("O resultado eh: ", n/m)


calculadora()
```

Comment: O fato de ter tipagem dinâmica não tem nada a ver com o fato de `input` retornar `string`, são características distintas que não interferem uma na outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/112052

Comment: obrigado, irei editar