# O que é uma linguagem interpretada? Java é interpretado?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem

[Nesta pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17082/7261) eu cito que Java é uma linguagem interpretada, pois sempre entendi dessa maneira. Mas fui corrigido [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17082/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-script#comment32212_17082) de que Java não é mais interpretado.

Assim fiquei com algumas dúvidas:

- O que é uma linguagem interpretada?
- Então Java já foi interpretado mas não é mais? É isso mesmo?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Uma linguagem interpretada é aquela que precisa de um programa especial - chamado interpretador - para que seus programas sejam executados. Contraste linguagem compilada, em que seus programas passam por um processo de **tradução** que converte da linguagem [semi-]humana para a linguagem de máquina.

Quando se escreve algo como:

```
x = y + z;
```

Se está dizendo para o computador que você quer atribuir à variável `x` o valor da soma das variáveis `y` e `z`. Entretanto, embora essa seja *a intenção*, no início isso não passa de um arquivo de texto. É necessário que esse arquivo sirva de entrada para outro programa, que vai fazer alguma coisa com ele e - em algum momento - a sua intenção ao escrever o código seja realizada.

- A maneira mais simples é a interpretação: o programa analisa a instrução, e em seguida faz o que ela está mandando. Simples e direto!
- Uma mais complexa é a compilação: o programa analisa a instrução, traduz a mesma para a linguagem de máquina, e produz como saída um outro programa - cujo comportamento deve ser realizar aquilo que você expressou no código.

Entre uma e outra, existem vários meio-termos:

- Pode-se analisar a instrução, convertê-la para código de máquina, e executar esse código de máquina imediatamente. Salvando-o numa espécie de "cache" para que - se a mesma instrução tiver que ser executada de novo - ele use o código de máquina gerado anteriormente, evitando ter que analisá-la de novo. Esse processo é chamado *Just-In-Time Compilation* - JIT. É a estratégia usada por exemplo na engine JavaScript V8 (usada no Chrome e no node.js).
- Pode-se analisar a instrução e convertê-la não para código de máquina diretamente, mas para um outro formato (normalmente binário) que seja mais simples de se interpretar e/ou compilar. É útil quando se quer fazer a análise dos fontes uma única vez, mas sem "amarrar" a saída a nenhuma plataforma específica. Essa estratégia é usada pelo Java, que através da ferramenta `javac` converte programas do formato textual para o formato *bytecodes*.

  Nesse caso, diz-se que o código gerado será executado por uma "máquina virtual": algo semelhante a uma máquina real, mas com sua própria arquitetura, seu conjunto de instruções específico, tudo o que em princípio descreveria uma máquina. Só que essa máquina não é física - é apenas um interpretador/compilador do código intermediário para uma arquitetura específica.

  - E respondendo à sua dúvida, antigamente esses *bytecodes* eram usados como entrada para um interpretador; hoje eles são usados como entrada para um compilador JIT, tal como descrito no item anterior.
- Pode-se analisar a instrução e convertê-la para uma instrução equivalente em outra linguagem - em seguida enviando-a para ser compilada/interpretada pelas ferramentas dessa segunda linguagem. É muito usada quando se quer programar num ambiente restrito (ex.: o browser, que só dá suporte a JavaScript) usando uma linguagem diferente daquela suportada nesse ambiente.

Por fim, cabe lembrar que a linha que separa compilado de interpretado não é assim tão bem definida: mesmo o que chamamos de "código de máquina" muitas vezes ainda precisa ser convertido no que chamamos de **microinstruções** - aquelas que são enviadas diretamente à CPU de fato. Nem toda arquitetura possui essa distinção (em algumas o "código de máquina" é diretamente executado), mas as mais usadas sim. No fim das contas, o resultado da compilação não é bem voltado para uma arquitetura específica, mas sim para um conjunto de arquiteturas parecidas (ex.: x86 e x86-64 - que abrangem um imenso conjunto de máquinas desde a década de 80 até hoje).

Answer (score 23):

## Interpretação

Uma linguagem interpretada executa o código diretamente à partir do código fonte.

A interpretação ocorre de forma semelhante à [compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) (tradução), ou seja, tem um processo de análise sintática, léxica e semântica, porém isto é feito sob demanda. O código fonte vai sendo lido (pode ser linha por linha ou outra forma) e interpretado com estes processos e depois algo é executado de acordo com o que está está escrito.

## Java

Java funcionava assim nas primeiras versões.

Ainda há uma certa confusão com isso porque ainda há um processo de "interpretação" do código gerado pelo compilador. Mas normalmente ele não é considerado como um código interpretado já que mesmo essa "interpretação" não ocorre instrução por instrução.

Para entender melhor, temos que observar que um código Java passa pelos mesmos processos de análise citados acima, o que muda é a forma como vai passando pelo código e o que faz no final, que é o que diferencia a interpretação da compilação:

- A interpretação ocorre em trechos curtos do programa, pode ser linha por linha, e no final executa algo que foi determinado neste trecho.
- A compilação ocorre em trechos maiores (funções, classes, pacotes) tentando entender o todo e no final um código é gerado. Há uma tradução para outra forma.

  No caso é um código da máquina virtual do Java ([JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)<sup>gosto de *linkar* a página em português, mas não esqueça de ver em inglês, sempre é melhor</sup>). É como se fosse o código de máquina que um computador entende mas ele é específico para a plataforma Java e não para um processador. Então o programa está compilado mas não consegue executar diretamente no processador como ocorre com linguagens como C ou Pascal que normalmente criam diretamente o código compreensível para o processador.

## [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101)

Então esse código de máquina virtual que é chamado de *bytecode* é compilado também, mas é um processo extremamente simples, ele está em um formato fácil de ser lido e entendido por este novo compilador completamente diferente do compilador do código fonte da linguagem. Além de não ter que se preocupar se o código está correto ou não, isto já foi feito antes. E principalmente esta compilação não ocorre instrução por instrução.

Isso é feito por um compilador JIT (Just-in-Time) que é um compilador que gera o código de máquina do processador, o chamado código nativo. No caso do Java este JITter transforma o *bytecode* em código nativo fazendo algumas otimizações que só são possíveis quando se conhece bem o ambiente que está rodando, não só o computador, sistema operacional, configurações, mas também os outros componentes (*packages*) que estão sendo usados juntos.

Essa compilação JIT entende todo o código intermediário e gera o código nativo sob demanda, conforme ele vai sendo necessário. Mas há como forçar essa compilação ocorrer um pouco antes.

Esse JITter não existia nas primeiras versões do Java. Normalmente o JITter não influencia a semântica da linguagem por isso qualquer linguagem interpretada ou compilada previamente para um *bytecode* pode ser *JITtada* mais tarde. De fato isso é cada vez mais comum. Podemos citar como exemplos JavaScript, Lua, PHP, etc. que passaram ser *JITtadas* posteriormente em implementações independentes.

O JITter normalmente só tem que entender este *bytecode* padrão e o código do processador onde ele será executado, não precisa saber nada da linguagem. Mas há JITters que trabalham em cima do código fonte, então de uma certa forma há uma compilação sob demanda (na hora que vai ser executado) ao contrário da compilação antecipada mais conhecida. Mas mesmo esta compilação sob demanda não é uma interpretação porque ela gera código a ser executado e não executa diretamente.

## Linguagens compiladas sem código de máquina

Há linguagens que estritamente não podem ser consideradas como interpretadas. Ela executa em cima do *bytecode* (algumas vezes chamados de *pseudocode*) mas não são *JITtadas*. A execução é mais rápida que a pura interpretação mas nem tanto quanto a *JITtada*, porque de uma certa forma há uma "interpretação" deste *bytecode* e ele vai sendo executado diretamente, sem transformação em código nativo. [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) (pura, sem o [LuaJIT](https://luajit.org/)) é um exemplo hoje.

Isso não é novo. Uma das primeiras linguagens *mainstream* que fez muito sucesso em várias partes do mundo, inclusive o Brasil, era o [Clipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_(programming_language)) (um dialeto que sobrevive de forma moderna é o [Harbour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbour_(programming_language))). Ele funcionava desta forma mas como gerava um executável muitos programadores acreditavam que gerava código igual ao C. Mas era apenas um *pcode* encapsulado no `.exe`. É parecido com o que o .NET faz hoje. Seus programas parecem estar em um executável nativo, mas internamente ele tem o *bytecode*.

Mas essa técnica existe desde a década de 50.

Há linguagens que não geram um *bytecode* e sim um [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (Abstract Syntax Tree ou árvore de sintaxe abstrata). É um passo antes da geração do código. Um compilador normalmente (em praticamente todas as implementações conhecidas) gera uma AST após os processos de análise sintática e léxica e os demais processos subsequentes ocorrem em cima desta árvore. Ruby padrão usa (ou usava, posso estar desatualizado) esta AST para executar. A interpretação ainda ocorre na AST, mas não é o processo normal de interpretação. De qualquer forma houve um processo de compilação anterior.

Claro que existem implementações de Ruby que funcionam de outra forma, inclusive porque rodam em cima da plataforma do Java, ou seja, no fim das contas o mesmo *bytecode* que é gerado no Java é gerado pelo jRuby e depois ele é JITtado pela JVM. Isto mostra a flexibilidade dessa infraestrutura de JIT.

Algumas pessoas consideram que essas linguagens ainda são interpretadas (ou semi-interpretadas) já que elas não executam código de máquina nativo, há uma interpretação mais leve porque parte do processo necessário foi feito antes por um compilador e algo simples de manipular foi gerado com a "garantia" que não tem erros. Mas é necessário um programa que entende este código e manda executar alguma coisa indiretamente. Isto seria uma interpretação.

Que eu me lembre desde o início do Java era assim, acho que nunca houve a interpretação do código fonte direto. Ou seja, sempre teve o `javac` e a JVM interpretava o *bytecode*.

Então é bem complicado classificar linguagens ou mesmo implementações como interpretadas ou compiladas.

## Linguagens não são interpretadas

Não podemos dizer que existem linguagens interpretadas ou compiladas ou mesmo *JITtadas*. No máximo podemos dizer que as implementações tem estas características. E elas não são mutuamente exclusivas. Embora algumas pessoas dirão que são implementações diferentes fornecidas em conjunto, é possível dizer que as três formas podem existir na [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

## Conclusão

Obviamente a execução de um programa interpretado é bem mais lenta que um programa compilado e que tem seu código de máquina gerado antecipadamente. No caso do código *JITtado* tem um custo para gerar o código de máquina mas é um custo bem mais baixo do que a interpretação direta. Além disto é feito uma vez e depois o código de máquina é sempre reaproveitamento.

A interpretação pura hoje só faz sentido em tempo de desenvolvimento ou para executar *scripts* muito curtos. Por isto qualquer linguagem usada para fazer sistemas deve ter alguma forma de compilação, mesmo que opcional.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: ++1 Você não tem ideia de como essa resposta me ajudou, eternamente grato.

Comment: @bigown você é formado em Java?

Comment: @MarcusBecker como se forma em Java?

Answer (score 9):

#### O que é uma linguagem interpretada?

É um linguagem de programação onde o código de alto nível escrita pelo programador é interpretada por um outro programa de computador e depois executada pelo sistema operacional, ou seja a linguagem escrita não é transformada em código de máquina, mas sim interpretada por outro programa.

#### Java é interpretado ou compilado?

Primeiramente vamos entender alguns termos:

**Javac** - Compilador que transforma o código escrito em Java para **Bytecodes**.

**Bytecodes** - Código em bytes, diferente de código de máquina, pois esse não é imediatamente executável.

**JIT** - *Just In Time Compiler*, compila o **Bytecode** para código de máquina em tempo de execução, realizando otimizações de desempenho.

**JVM** - Plataforma virtual que carrega o arquivo de classe na memória RAM, verifica o **Bytecode** checando se existem violações de restrição de acesso em seu código e converte em código de máquina executável.

Portanto o código de alto nível, escrito em Java pelo programador é compilado pelo  **Javac** que transforma para **Bytecode**. O Bytecode é compilado pela **JVM** através do compilador **JIT** para uma sequência de instruções dadas para código de máquina em tempo de execução antes de executar nativamente. Seu objetivo principal é fazer otimizações pesadas no desempenho. Visto isto, podemos dizer que Java não é interpretado e sim compilado, pois não é diretamente executado por outro programa a partir do código de alto nível escrito pelo programador.