# JavaScript é interpretado ou compilado em tempo de execução?

Tags: javascript, compilação, característica-linguagem

[Nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/7261) eu perguntei a mesma coisa, mas em relação a Java. Agora pergunto sobre o JavaScript.

Pelo que eu saiba, historicamente o JavaScript sempre foi interpretado, mas o Google mudou isso com o V8 no Chromium. Estou certo ou errado? E em relação aos outros *browsers*, como o Firefox e IE, ainda é interpretado?

Comment: Essa é uma boa pergunta

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Compilado em tempo de execução. Tal como o V8, os demais *browsers* introduziram Compilação JIT aos seus motores JavaScript para melhorar a performance, alguns quase que paralelamente ao lançamento do V8 (e outros depois):

- Internet Explorer: suporta JIT a partir da versão 9, com a *engine* [Chakra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_%28JScript_engine%29);
- Firefox: suporta JIT a partir da versão 3.5, com o [TraceMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_%28software%29#TraceMonkey). Segundo a Wikipedia, esta foi inclusive a primeira implementação a usar JIT, e não o V8, mas os respectivos artigos não dão datas exatas. A partir de então, outros motores também JIT foram incorporados ao SpiderMonkey;
- Opera: usa o V8, a partir da versão 15;
- Safari: usa a *engine* [Nitro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore#JavaScriptCore), também *JITada*, a partir de 2008 (não há menção à versão).

Esses são os principais *browsers*. No contexto *standalone*, temos o Node.js que é baseado no V8, e o [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) que é um caso especial: originalmente, ele operava em modo compilado de A pra B, i.e. traduzindo todo o código JavaScript para *bytecodes* Java (um exemplo prático do 3º item na [minha resposta à sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22650/215)). Isso oferecia uma performance de execução ainda melhor que a compilação JIT, mas com a desvantagem do tempo de compilação ser longo. Hoje ele dá suporte aos dois modos: compilado e interpretado, de modo que o programador pode pesar o que é mais importante para ele numa determinada situação - velocidade de execução vs. velocidade de compilação.

Concluindo, todas as implementações modernas mais comuns usam algum tipo de compilação, a maioria do tipo JIT. Podem haver outras que eu não conheço e, de todo modo, vale relembrar [o que disse Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22651/215) na mesma pergunta *linkada*: "Não podemos dizer que existem linguagens interpretadas ou compiladas ou mesmo *JITtadas*. No máximo podemos dizer que as implementações tem estas características. E elas não são mutuamente exclusivas."

Comment: Isso explica por que o Opera ta sempre apanhando das minhas animações enquanto outros navegadores rodam perfeitamente

Answer (score 14):

[V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) e [Rhino](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/rhino/js/1.6R6-candidate2/js-1.6R6-candidate2-javadoc.jar!/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.html#setOptimizationLevel%28int%29) são exemplos de compiladores de JavaScript. Respectivamente, para código nativo interno (C++) e para JAVA Bytecode. Existem ainda outros interpretadores que utilizam um compilador JIT.

À risca, JavaScript é tanto interpretado quanto compilado – essa especificação não é obrigatoriamente de responsabilidade da linguagem, mas no cenário JavaScript, você pode delegar qual mecanismo de interpretação ou compilação você vai querer usar.

Se você quiser utilizar o V8, o [Google explica](https://developers.google.com/v8/build) como trabalhar em cima do seu motor que, como já dito, é compilado. Aplicações naturalmente web, por sua vez, utilizarão os motores e dispositivos providos pelos navegadores do cliente, que trazem consigo mecanismos interpretadores e que **não compilarão o JavaScript em um padrão standard.**

**Cuidado aqui: *precompilação de assets***

Um erro recorrente é confundir compilação de assets com compilação de linguagem. Quando usamos Rails, por exemplo, podemos utilizar o Asset Pipeline para precompilar os nossos assets, fazendo com que uma quantidade **X** de arquivos `.js` se unifiquem e se comprimam para então formar um só, minificado, resultando em uma sensação (errônea) de "compilação".

Na verdade, houve *sim* uma compilação, mas ela *não* é a mesma que você está pensando, como a qual C# ou JAVA fazem.

Comment: Para quem trabalhar com ASP.NET MVC, essa precompilação de assets é também conhecida como bundle e minification - http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn168847.aspx