# Qual o overhead de utilizar orientação a objetos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, desempenho, arquitetura-de-software, característica-linguagem

Na empresa onde trabalho atualmente somos fortemente encorajados a evitar programação orientada a objetos tanto para projetos antigos como para projetos novos.

Para projetos antigos concordo que seja uma má pratica começar a inserir orientação a objetos em um projeto totalmente estrutural, porém para projetos novos acredito ser mais produtivo utilizar OOP.

Questionando a situação recebi como resposta da empresa: orientação a objetos é pesada e lenta, portanto recomendamos não utilizar.

1 - Qual o *overhead* de se utilizar orientação a objetos vs programação procedural?

2 - Considerando que boas práticas de programação são seguidas, é mais produtivo utilizar orientação a objetos ou programação procedural?

Comment: `orientação a objetos é pesada e lenta, portanto recomendamos não utilizar.` Isso aqui parece o mantra do [Rasmus](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf). Como você falou depende do projeto.

Comment: Entendo que usar ou não depende de projeto, mas excluir orientação em 100% dos projetos me parece um pouco radical. Deve haver algum motivo para este tipo de atitude.

Comment: "PHP é pesada e lenta, portanto recomendamos não utilizar" - Eu mesmo. Eu não tenho dados mas duvido que usar objetos seja muito pior que não usar em PHP. Não é uma crítica ao PHP mas para ter as vantagens que ela tem ela tem que estruturar a memória de uma maneira que torna tudo mais lento. Se eu achar uma forma consistente de responder, eu posto alguma coisa.

Comment: @Kaminary, tem um  frase/benchmark do Rasmus que ele jura que o php procedural é mais rápido que o OO, ai algumas pessoas pensam... hum o Rasmus é o criador da linguaguem sabe do que está falando logo é uma 'autoridade' ou seja <ironia>devemos acreditar cegamente nisso!</ironia>

Comment: E eu concordo que procedural seja mais rápido mesmo, existe algum motivo para ser, existe motivo até mesmo em linguagens estáticas. Mas a diferença será muito pequena em uma linguagem que não tem por característica ser rápida (o que não é, em si, um defeito). Mas que o Rasmus deve entender de PHP menos que muitos usuários da linguagem, isto é verdade :D @rray você consegue a citação? Acho que ajudaria na resposta.

Comment: @bigown acho que a fonte original está aqui: https://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html . Por ironia, tem um erro de php na página xD

Comment: Eu perdi alguma coisa ou não dá para acessar nenhuma informação relevante nela?

Comment: @gmsantos, seria esse link do famoso benchmark http://talks.php.net/show/froscon08/24 ? sim ele é antigo. Os slides seguintes são as comparações com os outros frameworks.

Comment: @rray assim que achar a citação crie uma resposta baseada nela.

Comment: Se a questão é o desempenho "bruto" da linguagem, então porque não usar C ou Assembly ao invés de PHP? Se a questão é o tempo de resposta, então basta investir numa boa arquitetura na aplicação, no hardware e no banco de dados, além de usar mecanismos de *cache* onde for possível. Creio que todos os principais frameworks PHP são orientados a objetos, então a afirmação simplesmente não se justifica pragmaticamente.

Comment: Como diria um amigo meu: A orientação a objeto pode "gastar" mais memória do que a orientação procedural, mas você vai concordar que, a longo prazo, de acordo com o que você vai desenvolvendo com o procedural, você vai acabar consumindo mais recursos, por conta de repetições e etc?

Comment: Se orientação a objeto é tão pesada assim, deveriam acabar com o ZEND! Talvez pensar que programação orientada a objeto é pesada seria pensar ridiculamente demais em microotimização. É como aquele usuário do windows que desfragmenta o seu computador de 2 em 2 horas :)

Comment: Pelo que percebi em PHP classes podem até economizar memória. Claro que não sei o contexto que seu amigo fez tal afirmação mas neste contexto aqui ela está errada. Mesmo em C++ só gasta mais memória se usar polimorfismo, e mesmo assim é mínimo é só o espaço de um ponteiro. Quem sabe programar bem proceduralmente faz reuso de código igual ou quase igual à OOP. Pode ser mais complicado organizar, mas é possível. Desconheço um caso de OOP bem feito que consuma menos recursos que procedural bem feito. Em código mal feito pode ser mas aí a comparação é injusta.

Comment: Como também já vivi isso na pele, por favor me permitam um momento de desabafo. Na boa, esse tipo de dogmatismo (XML é muito "pesado", OOP tem muito "overhead", etc) é geralmente usado por quem não conhece nada da tecnologia em questão e tem medo/vergonha de admitir. Pior ainda, tem preguiça de aprender. Pronto, passou.

Comment: A empresa esta errada, o problema agora é influenciar eles a mudarem de ideia.

Comment: Tem muitos motivos bons pra não se usar OOP **à toa** em PHP, mas não são exatamente os que a empresa alega. Uma coisa é fato: OOP não acrescenta nada em PHP, mas se for coisa com bastante reuso (uma biblioteca, por exemplo) não tem motivo pra não usar. Se for pra fazer o router da aplicação, por exemplo, o procedural é muito mais curto e legível. A linguagem permite os dois paradigmas, que tal usar o que tem de bom em cada um e no momento certo? Puristas tem horror a essas "misturas", mas se você(s) está(ão) usando os miolos pra programar, não tem problema nenhum em usar as ferramentas.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Eu não programo em PHP há muito tempo e mesmo na época nunca me aprofundei. Eu cheguei fuçar nos *internals* da linguagem porque gosto de linguagens. Ainda assim não me lembro de todos os detalhes da implementação e na época não tinha orientação a objeto na linguagem, ou pelo menos era incipiente.

## [*Overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) do PHP

Sei que todas essas linguagens ditas de *script* ou pelo menos [dinâmicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21513/101) em sua essência têm uma coisa em comum: elas rodam em cima de uma [máquina vitual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

PHP é basicamente uma [linguagem interpretada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22651/101), pelo menos ainda hoje. Mesmo que ela tenha uma forma de otimização disso, que o código fonte acabe sendo transformado em um *bytecode* para melhorar o desempenho da máquina virtual, ainda será lenta, não só pelo processo de compilação ter um custo e que deve ser pago todas as vezes que a aplicação rodar do zero (e isto ocorre muito na maioria do casos de uso do PHP), mas também a máquina virtual é um software (em geral é um *loop* com um enorme *switch* para selecionar qual micro-instrução deve ser executada naquele momento) que gera um belo de um *overhead*. Uma pré-compilação e um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) faria um trabalho um pouco melhor (embora para um *script* nem tanto).

Além disso linguagens de tipagem dinâmica precisam fazer verificações e possivelmente conversões todas as vezes que for acessar um valor. Apesar de poder fazer algumas otimizações há um *overhead* claro em cada acesso à memória.

Não me lembro do caso do PHP mas quase todas essas linguagens guardam as variáveis em uma estrutura de [*hash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (não consigo imaginar como o PHP possa ser muito diferente, outras linguagens parecidas até podem, mas o PHP não teria sem impor algumas limitações que hoje ele não tem). Acessar uma estrutura que precisa fazer um cálculo é obviamente mais lento que acessar um endereço de memória direto como é o caso de outras linguagens que têm variáveis "reais".

Tem várias outras "vantagens" do dinamismo do PHP que impõe mais *overhead*.

Para montar as classes muito provavelmente há mais *overhead*. Mas é só mais um dentro de um contexto cheio de *overheads*. Talvez nem seja um mal tão grande comparando com tudo o que ocorre na execução.

## Você sabe como essas classes costumam ser montadas em linguagens?

Bem, em linguagens estáticas é possível montar objetos como [estruturas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29) de dados simples, quase como um *array* simples (note que o *array* do PHP é diferente, é uma estrutura complexa e lenta em função da flexibilidade que ele oferece). Há um *ovehead* **se** usar polimorfismo, neste caso haverá uma indireção de ponteiro para indicar qual é o real tipo de um valor. Isto é rápido mas não deixa de ser um *overhead*.

Esse custo existe em todos os valores em linguagens dinâmicas. Qualquer dado em linguagem dinâmica é polimórfico independente de estar um uma classe ou não. E é tão flexível que não basta ter uma indireção de ponteiro, é necessário ter uma estrutura ligeiramente mais complexa e não há garantias de integridade do dado para cada situação obrigando verificação em cada acesso.

Em linguagens dinâmicas classes costumam ser uma forma muito parecida com um *array* associativo, em geral implementado como *hashs*. No fundo você tem elementos que guardam dados e alguns desses dados são referências para funções. Métodos nada mais são que funções "enfeitadas" com um sobrenome e um parâmetro adicional para acessar o `this`.

Classes estão em *hashes*, variáveis comuns também. Então, salvo ter alguma coisa que não sei, não é tão diferente assim acessar uma variável normal ou uma variável de instância de uma classe. Mesmo funções, no fundo também estão em tabelas *hash*. Até funções escritas em C precisam descobrir seu endereço por essas tabelas antes de serem chamadas.

## OOP tem *overhead*?

Então se alguém não me mostrar que há uma enorme diferença, eu digo que há pouca. Mas há.

Claro que é uma camada extra. E isto impõe algum *overhead*. OOP costuma organizar e abstrair mais o código mas impõe código interno extra que produz *overhead*. O simples fato de você ter que carregar vários arquivos já é um *overhead* importante.

Em muitos casos os métodos só existem para chamar outra função procedural. Há casos que métodos precisam ser "interpretados" mesmo que eles não sejam usados de fato.

E lembre-se que muitas funções procedurais são escritas em C e o código PHP não precisa fazer nada. Quando você adiciona uma camada, o código dela precisa ser interpretado. Pior ainda se fizer toda a lógica no método e não apenas delegar para outra função que por si só já seria uma indireção bem mais custosa que um indireção de um ponteiro.

Em tese acessar membros em uma classe não deveria ser muito diferente de acessar membros em um *array* associativo. Mas as pesquisas que estou conduzindo para responder adequadamente esta pergunta mostram que pode não ser bem assim. Por isto não adianta teorizar, é preciso medir para ter uma informação confiável. E é preciso saber medir corretamente.

Eu não tenho condições de fazer minhas medições agora e vou ter confiar em algumas existentes na internet. Não quer dizer que todas estão certas, até porque elas são conflitantes, não pude fazer uma avaliação se elas estão corretas.

Note que existem diferenças dependendo da versão do PHP. Isto faz sentido, então não dá para dizer se OOP em PHP impõe um *overhead* e sim se impõe na versão que você está usando.

Também vemos que *overhead* de memória e de processamento podem dar resultados diferentes, óbvio.

Lembrando que a concorrência direta de [Hack](https://hacklang.org/) está fazendo PHP correr atrás do prejuízo.

- [Pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193049/php-objects-vs-arrays) com testes que mostram que é quase igual ou até mesmo classes podem ser mais rápidas.

  Faz sentido classes por si só, sem olhar sua aplicação real de todos os casos, serem mais rápidas porque elas podem usar uma implementação de *hash* otimizada para a necessidade de uma estrutura que sabe-se que será usada só para armazenar a estrutura de classes.
- [Teste detalhado](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030204910/http://www.theserverpages.com/articles/webmasters/php/performance/Performance_of_OOP_PHP_versus_non-OOP.html).

  Na verdade todos esses testes não são precisos eles comparam não só o *overhead* de processamento usando OOP, há outros processamentos ocorrendo que faz com que a diferença pareça menor do que realmente é se considerarmos só o gasto extra para acessar os dados e métodos em uma classe.
- [*slides* comparando implementações de *frameworks*](https://talks.php.net/show/froscon08/24) (fornecido pelo rray em comentário)

  Vemos aí que tem vários outros fatores que interferem na performance. Nenhuma novidade. A maioria das comparações medem implementações e não o recurso bruto que se quer medir de verdade. Sem medir o caso específico é complicado afirmar alguma coisa. E ficar medindo tudo não faz sentido. **Só vale medir se perceber que há problemas**.
- [Explicação do uso menor de memória](https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323).

  Em PHP parece que classes realmente usam menos memória que *arrays* se esta for a opção de troca. Mas não sei se isto é verdade se a comparação não for com *arrays*.
- [Outra comparação mostrando que classes podem ser mais eficientes](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11568-php-objects-vs-arrays-performance-myth/).

  Note que todas as comparações são contextuais. Nenhuma prova alguma coisa em todos os contextos, mesmo considerando que elas não tenham falhas.
- [Comparação com resultados diferentes das outras](http://www.particletree.com/notebook/object-oriented-php-memory-concerns/).

  Dentro do critério usado (não mostrado) objetos ocuparam mais memória e muito mais tempo para carregar os dados.

Todas estas informações foram colocadas para mostrar que não dá para afirmar nada definitivo.

## Qual usar?

Use o que organiza seu código melhor.

Agora alguns devem estar pensando que OOP é o caminho. E não é, não necessariamente. Vejo muitos códigos OOP bem piores que códigos procedurais, até porque programar OOP não é tão simples assim. Ele provê abstrações, mas a maioria das pessoas têm problemas com abstrações (então nem deveriam tentar programar que é algo todo baseado em abstrações, mas isto é outro problema).

As pessoas optam sempre por uma ou outra para resolver todos os problemas porque elas costumam [ter apenas um martelo e veem todos os problemas como pregos](http://quemdisse.com.br/frase.asp?frase=50830).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em PHP procurei fazer sempre procedural até que OOP se mostre a melhor solução independente de ter *overhead* ou não (a não ser que o *overhad* mate a vantagem, o que é raro). Na verdade quase todo mundo faz muito mais procedural. Muitos sequer entendem a linha que divide procedural de OOP. Só porque criou uma classe não quer dizer que está fazendo OOP de verdade. E quase todas as linguagens que dizem ser 100% OOP estão mentindo.

Quer performance? Use linguagens estáticas, compiladas, de baixo nível. C, C++, Delphi, C# especialmente [Nativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) ou Assembly, por exemplo. Se preocupar com performance usando PHP não faz sentido.

A maior parte das otimizações virão por decisões sobre algoritmos e arquitetura.

Quando se usa boas práticas de verdade usa-se o que é melhor para o caso. É boa prática não seguir cegamente boas práticas. E esta é má prática mais exercida por programadores. Informação é prata, compreensão é ouro.

## Nota final

Aprenda fazer de várias formas e evite o [martelo dourado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

Se quer uma informação confiável aprenda como consegui-la por meios próprios. Se não souber fazer corretamente, não conseguirá nada confiável. Principalmente não conseguirá de pessoas aleatórias na internet, como eu.

E o criador da linguagem é uma pessoa aleatória na internet. Principalmente neste caso onde o criador original criou uma linguagem toda torta, e ele mesmo [admite que não sabia o que estava fazendo](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Rasmus_Lerdorf). Pior que outras pessoas assumiram o desenvolvimento da linguagem e erros piores continuaram sendo cometidos. Parece que PHP não consegue atrair profissionais que realmente saibam o que estão fazendo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Vejo muitos código OOP bem piores que códigos procedurais" é uma afirmação corretíssima, principalmente se você der uma olhada no código fonte do [Codeigniter](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Input.php) :(

Comment: "Parece que PHP não consegue atrair profissionais que realmente saibam o que estão fazendo." Você se refere ao desenvolvimento da linguagem ou ao desenvolvedores que usam a linguagem? Acho que pode caber ao primeiro caso mais no tom de ironia, pois a linguagem tem várias deficiências, mas bem ou mal ela é um "sucesso", já se se trata do segundo caso, em minha opinião seria uma afirmação por demais generalizada e superficial, você pode usar o PHP em uma ocasião específica muito ciente do que está fazendo.

Comment: Isso algo mais como piada, mas eu diria que ambos :D Claro que existem exceções, claro que tem gente boa desenvolvendo a linguagem (não igual aos melhores "linguistas da computação") e desenvolvendo c/ a linguagem. Mas exceções só justificam a regra, não as fazem :P Mas cada dia me convenço mais que isto é mais ou menos generalizado em quase todas as linguagens. Algumas a proporção muda. Já vi programador ruim em Assembly mas é raro. O mesmo vale p/ C/C++, depois que o cara sai da faculdade se ele ñ fica bom, ele pára c/ a linguagem, PHP, JS, Java, C#, etc. o q ñ sabe continua programando.

Comment: Eu programo em php e o que posso dizer sobre a linguagem é que realmente tem muito overhead um em cima do outro, mas a orientação a objeto não tem um diferencial tão grande assim na questão de overhead(é como esperar 1 segundo a mais quando você já estava esperando 1hora). Porém, com as maquina de hoje, o php se tornou uma linguagem muito boa para os profissionais da área(exeto para projeto grandes) você não sente diferença entre ela e outras linguagens em projeto de pequeno e médio porte. Então nesses casos é preferivel usar um linguagem facil de aprender e rapido de desenvolver, ou seja, PHP

Answer (score -1):

Ao meu ver, dizer para não usar OOP porque "gasta mais memória e é mais lento", é o mesmo que:

Não usar bootstrap.css porque gasta mais memória e é mais lento;

Não usar jquery.js porque gasta mais memória e é mais lento;

Não usar angular.js porque gasta mais memória e é mais lento;

Não usar uma IDE porque gasta mais memória e é mais lento, e codificar tudo no bloco de notas.

Tudo tem um preço a se pagar, aí é necessário considerar para onde a balança pende mais, se para o lado dos prós ou se para o lado dos contras

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/96000)

Comment: Mas tem um contexto ai, o que eu disse é que OOP pode ser considerada uma camada a mais. E que sim, pode até consumir um pouco mais de memoria e ser um pouco mais lento, tem o seu preço mas também tem o seu beneficio, igualmente as tecnologias que citei.
Ele fez duas perguntas, não responde tecnicamente a um, mas ainda considero que responde a dois, com um exemplo de argumento a se utilizar.

Comment: Existem dois problemas ao meu ver na sua resposta, primeira: A pergunta já havia sido respondida, escavar perguntas para dar uma resposta não chega a ser errado, porem a sua resposta nada acrescentou ao que o bigown já havia respondido acima :) Acredito que nesse caso caberia mais como um comentário, um adendo.
Entenda que não estou criticando, apenas aconselhando, espero que não se sinta irritado.