# Por que o Codeigniter se sai tão bem em benchmarks mesmo não seguindo os padrões da linguagem?

Tags: php, codeigniter, framework, benchmark

Vejo muitas pessoas cuspindo em cima do Codeigniter, dizendo que é um lixo de framework que se recusa a seguir os "padrões da linguagem". Porém acho estranho dizer isso do framework que tem o melhor desempenho entre os que não são compilados como podemos ver nos benchmarks abaixo

[image: Benchmark de requisições por segundo]

Benchmark de requisições por segundo

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Benchmark de tempo de resposta

---

Font: [Dev-Media](http://www.devmedia.com.br/melhore-a-performance-com-o-phalconphp/29237)

Levei essa fonte consideração pois apresenta as versões do frameworks testados e é um dos poucos que leva em conta o Codeigniter 2.

> **Observação:** o Phalcon se destaca tanto assim dos demais frameworks pelo fato de ser escrito em C, pré-compilado e usado como extensão do servidor, o que tira praticamente todo o overhead que frameworks de linguagens interpretadas geralmente possuem.
>   Obrigado [@Kazzkiq](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1754/kazzkiq)

1. O que faz o Codeigniter ter esse desempenho tão superior aos outros?
2. Quem realmente está errado, o Code Igniter por não seguir os "padrões da linguagem" ou os padrões que estão causando overheads desnecessários nos outros frameworks?

> **Nota:** É importante lembrar que o PHP foi criado para ser procedural, tendo OO implementado em sua versão 5 e mantendo a possibilidade de ser escrito em forma procedural, porém usar o OO no php gera um overhead como pode ser visto [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50273/qual-o-overhead-de-utilizar-orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos/50308#50308)

Comment: Coloca a fonte ou link da onde vieram esses dados

Comment: @rray adicionado

Comment: O artigo é do DevMedia, mas os benchmarks [são da documentação do framework PhalconPHP](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/benchmark/hello-world.html), que a titulo de curiosidade, se destaca tanto assim dos demais frameworks pelo fato de ser escrito em C, pré-compilado e usado como extensão do servidor, o que tira praticamente todo o overhead que frameworks de linguagens interpretadas geralmente possuem.

Comment: @Kazzkiq deixei essa informação meio implicita, mas vou adicionar pra exclarecer melhor a diferença entre eles

Comment: @RodrigoBorth os outros frameworks perdem em desempenho porém ganham em manutenção e legibilidade de código. É possível um desempenho ainda melhor que o codeigniter caso não use framework algum e faça as coisas sob medida.

Comment: Seguir padrões não significa melhor desempenho computacional. Padrões servem para que outros programadores compreendam melhor seu código (ou que você mesmo entenda).

Comment: @gmsantos sim, eu sei disso disso, porém, o code igniter não deixa nada a desejar em legibilidade de código ou em velocidade de manutenção, na verdade ele tem vantagem nesses dois pontos também sobre outros frameworks, aí é que levanta minha dúvida, se usar prodrões de OO, em uma linguagem originalmente procedural, está certo ou não?

Comment: @Oeslei no caso do PHP temos uma diferença entre outras linguagens, pois ele é, em sua essência uma linguagem procedural, e os padrões induziram o OO, que causa um overhead grande na linguagem. Mesmo assim, o Code Igniter que não segue esse padrões consegue ter uma legibilidade maior e uma manutenção mais facil e rápida em relação a outros frameworks. O que levanta a questão, esses padrões foram pensados em prol do php ou foram pensados em prol da linguagem ser vista como igual perante as outras?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth o foco dos frameworks e da linguagem PHP não é o desempenho. Isso vem mudando pouco a partir da versão 5.4 (os testes foram baseados na versão 5.3) pela pressão de frameworks como Phalcon, HHVM. Uma coisa é certa: O Codeginiter parou no tempo. Atualmente ele ainda está na versão 2.x, enquanto os outros FW evoluíram com a linguagem. Gostaria de ver esse mesmo Benchmark com as versões atuais dos FWs em questão... possivelmente essa diferença diminuiria drasticamente.

Comment: @gmsantos o code igniter está lançando a sua versão 3.x, ainda está instavel, porém quem usou disse que a diferença no desempenho para a versão 2 é bastante grande. acredito que essa distancia possa aumentar ainda mais nos proximos benchmarks. Ainda não tenho nenhuma referencia a benchmark atual, acredito que a versão 5.x do php seja o problema, pois está sendo a versão de transição entre o procedural e a OO

Comment: Embora não pareça, existe um abismo entre as versões 5.2, 5.3 e 5.4 do PHP (deve chegar a uma janela de 4 anos no total). Outro fato, o Codeigniter é orientado a objetos.

Comment: @gmsantos sim, sei que ele é OO, porém, olhar a forma como ele usa OO e como outros frameworks usam OO da a impressão que são paradigmas diferentes sendo usados

Comment: Encontrei um segundo Benchmarking um pouco mais recente. Nele o Codeigniter [perde para Kohana e Slim](http://systemsarchitect.net/performance-benchmark-of-popular-php-frameworks/). Na mesma resposta postada como referencia da nota encontrei a frase "Se preocupar com performance usando PHP não faz sentido.", e realmente não faz. Vale a pena a leitura: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16697154/2099835

Comment: @gmsantos olhei o benchmark, lembro de ter visto um benchmark parecido, com os resultados bem semelhantes, porém nele estavam usando a versão 1.7 do CI. Nesse não consegui localizar qual a versão dos frameworks utilizados

Comment: php rápido? ops...tem algo errado aí mesmo, kkk

Answer (score 4):

Codeigniter não é e nunca foi "um lixo de framework". Ele é simplesmente de uma época em que "padrões de linguagem" era a última coisa que um desenvolvedor de PHP tinha em mente.

Codeigniter é mais rápido por ter menos firulas e ter menos abstrações.

Padrões de escrever em uma determinada linguagem servem para facilitar a leitura do código, a extensão do programa, manutenção e testes. Na maior parte das vezes não é dirigido à performance.

Codeigniter é um framework sólido, com ótima documentação e boa performance. Quem sempre usou o CI, não precisa largar, embora eu recomende usar o Laravel para projetos novos ou para iniciantes, pois vai forçar o aprendizado das melhores práticas no desenvolvimento de aplicações PHP.