# PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, estilo-de-codificação, paradigma-de-programação, procedural

Estou aprendendo PHP, e pelos exemplo que tenho visto na internet existe uma mistura na codificação dos programas, de orientação a objeto e procedimentos estruturados.

Isso é mesmo comum ou estou equivocado?

Se PHP é uma linguagem orientada a objetos, até que ponto é interessante ou não essa mistura?

Comment: PHP definitivamente não é uma linguagem OO, está recebendo essas opções recentemente. A questão é, se a linguagem permite os 2 paradigmas, nada mais inteligente do que usar o melhor de cada um onde convém. O resto é moda. Aliás, tem várias linguagens que permitem isso. Na que eu mais uso, que é Harbour, uso OOP para GUI e alguns outros módulos, e a parte "executiva" faço procedural. Ganho tempo, fica organizado e legível.

Comment: Para entender o que é orientação a objetos, recomendo as respostas de mgibsonbr e Luiz Vieira nesta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55493/14584, que são a melhor fonte de definição OOP que conheço aqui no SOpt. Repare por exemplo que *herança* é um detalhe muito desimportante deste paradigma e está longe de defini-lo. Frameworks em linguagens de tipagem estática se beneficiam de herança. Fora isso, herança só recebe destaque em OOP nas apostilas para iniciantes e em sistemas de design duvidoso.

Comment: Um definição de OOP que é bastante escrutinada na internet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming onde fala tudo o que está na minha resposta. Eu vejo que algumas pessoas confundirem OOD, OOM, ou coisa do tipo com OOP (que indica claramente algumas características necessárias para se encaixar no paradigma). Mesmo que a definição fosse outra, esta é o que quase todo mundo usa, então todo mundo pode estar errado (não que eu ache isso), mas é o que todo mundo entende.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

## TL;DR - Kind of

Não está totalmente equivocado, mas está um pouco.

Informalmente podemos dizer que é misturado mesmo, mas quase todas linguagens ditas orientadas a objeto fazem o mesmo. O grosso do código é procedural (ou mais precisamente, imperativo). A orientação a objeto entra em outro nível, mais na organização do código. Ele atua mais na estrutura de dados e onde vai colocar os algoritmos do que nos algoritmos em si, que são imperativos.

[Alguns dizem que OOP nem é um paradigma completo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

Na própria documentação do PHP tem vários exemplos de escrever o mesmo código com o modo procedural e o modo OOP. Podemos aceitar esta definição, mas estritamente aquilo não é bem OOP. PHP é uma linguagem que não costuma seguir muito bem as definições corretas.

No fundo o que eles estão querendo dizer ali é que você pode escolher entre: 1) passar um objeto como parâmetro para um método; ou 2) usar uma sintaxe onde o método é invocado pelo objeto. O que na prática dá no mesmo por baixo dos panos. No fundo este último caso o método apenas terá um parâmetro extra chamado `$this` que fica escondido. Você só está trocando o parâmetro de lugar.

Isso tem alguma vantagem com ferramentas (IDE por exemplo) que podem ajudar codificar e analisar dados já sabendo do que se trata. Fora isso, não há vantagens reais. Individualmente pode haver alguma vantagem secundária que foi melhor resolvida no caso da sintaxe que destaca o objeto, mas foi algo adicional que aproveitaram e resolveram quando estavam criando essa camada extra. Pode haver uma desvantagem por gerar uma camada a mais.

A mistura de sintaxe não causa problemas, pelo menos não deveria. De paradigmas também não. A mistura é sempre boa se ela resolve melhor o problema, purismo é dogmático, é forçar algo pelo gosto e não pela necessidade.

## O que é OOP?

Mas usar essa sintaxe não pode ser considerado programação orientada a objeto. No máximo, quem criou essas classes é que programou orientado a objeto, não quem consumiu. Mesmo isto é complicado dizer porque o uso de classes não define que está se programando orientado a objeto. Esse paradigma sequer exige a presença de classes.

OOP é algo muito mais complexo, e no fundo a maioria dos programadores nem fazem ideia de como programar desta forma. Isto inclui os que dizem que programam orientado a objeto e na verdade não o fazem, ou fazem de forma toda errada. Isso é explicado pelo [efeito Dunning Kruger](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efeito_Dunning-Kruger).

OOP é uma metodologia para organizar melhor o código e promover o seu reuso em uma forma específica.

Nem todo mundo concorda com todas as definições, inclusive o [autor do termo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay) diz que as definições que costumam usar estão erradas. Embora o uso de OOP, de alguma forma, antecede o uso o termo.

Uma das formas mais aceitas diz que OOP se dá quando há herança, polimorfismo e encapsulamento. Abstração e outros conceitos costumam ser incluídos em algumas definições, mas estas três alcançam mais consenso.

A maioria dos programadores que dizem usar OOP não usam ou não sabem usar corretamente os conceitos fundamentais. Então, podemos dizer que esta pessoa está usando OOP de fato?

Em geral elas apenas criam classes, o que pode atender o encapsulamento, se fizer certo. Mas isso é possível fazer em qualquer paradigma de uma forma ou de outra. No fundo, quando as pessoas fazem isso estão programando no [paradigma modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming).

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101) (leia principalmente a parte de OOP, é importante para entender) eu até falo que uma das coisas que mais impulsionaram a programação é a modularização, e uma das formas de modularizar é encapsular. Isso não é exclusivo de OOP. De fato é algo muito importante.

## Pra que OOP é boa?

Justamente por causa da herança OOP é uma mão na roda para representar hierarquias e relações complexas entre objetos. Ótimo para GUIs e alguns tipos de jogos (e outros tipos de aplicação, claro, não vou citar tudo). Mas não é tão bom assim para todos os problemas.

OOP realmente ajuda muito organizar grandes bases de código manipuladas por grandes equipes. Mas OOP tem um custo também.

Em cenários onde as hierarquias não são tão importantes, as relações não são tão complexas e o desenvolvimento é feito de forma individualizada ou por equipe muito pequena, ou pelo menos a aplicação é desenvolvida de forma muito fragmentada (modularização natural, típico de aplicações PHP, já que são *scripts*), OOP, de verdade, não é tão útil assim.

E é menos ainda quando a pessoa não tem um profundo entendimento do que está fazendo. E o que vemos aqui mesmo neste site é que as pessoas cometem muitos erros, alguns grotescos. Eu cometo erros, mesmo tendo estudado bastante o assunto, não é fácil acertar com esse paradigma, e ele precisa ser certo para aproveitá-lo bem, não é fácil corrigir depois se feito errado no começo, apesar de algumas pessoas acreditarem o contrário (se refatoração resolvesse tão bem então fazer procedural não seria problema também).

OOP burocratiza o desenvolvimento. Se isso é bom ou ruim depende de cada caso e não vou cravar uma posição.

O SOpt mesmo usa uma linguagem dita orientada a objeto (ainda que seja uma mentira classificar C# assim), e os engenheiros dele, alguns dos melhores do mundo, escolheram conscientemente não usar esse paradigma para sua construção, **não seguiram folclores**, e se beneficiaram muito disto. Se esse projeto, que não é nada simples, ficou melhor sem OOP, por que você acha que seu projeto web mais simples se beneficiará dele?

## PHP é orientada a objeto?

PHP <strike>é</strike>era uma linguagem de *script*, <strike>é</strike>era uma linguagem sem cerimônia, ela brilha nisso, se não usar tanto cacareco que colocaram depois.

Ela executa pequenos trechos de código de cada vez e morrem. Esses *scripts* não duram na memória, não carregam tudo o que a aplicação fará, as execuções são mais estanques.

É muito mais fácil administrar esse tipo de código do que em um sistema ERP [monolítico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_application), por exemplo.

PHP faz uma modularização de forma natural, você usa só o que precisa para aquele contexto momentâneo. Você inclui o que quer de forma extremamente fácil, sem nada de OOP.

PHP não é orientada a objeto. Ela é originalmente imperativa/procedural e mais recentemente adotou, adicionalmente, conceitos de OO.

Essas extensões da linguagem para manipular OOP são ótimas para transformar PHP em uma linguagem de propósito geral, mas ajudam muito pouco no domínio onde ela tem sucesso, a web.

Essas extensões facilitam o uso de OOP, mas já era possível antes. Como as pessoas não entendem o que é OOP, elas achavam que não dava. As ferramentas só ficaram mais óbvias.

Na verdade PHP é uma das linguagens mais fáceis de adotar OOP mesmo antes de existir sintaxe específica para isto. Todo sistema de classes, herança, polimorfismo, etc. do PHP foi desenvolvido em cima dos *arrays* associativos (não estou dizendo que ele usa exatamente os mesmos *arrays* da linguagem, como o JavaScript faz, apenas é algo muito semelhante) e não é difícil simular todos conceitos OO usando esse mecanismo (tem [exemplo ingênuo nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101)). Só não tinha a sintaxe mais conveniente e já bem reconhecida em outras linguagens tradicionais que implementam classes.

## PHP se beneficia de OOP?

Eu sou uma das poucas pessoas que já usou PHP para uma aplicação que não seja web, em que o código todo rodava junto por horas, então o código era mais "junto". E mesmo neste caso não senti falta de nada orientado a objeto, imagine em códigos efêmeros que é o caso típico das aplicações web.

A maioria dos códigos PHP que usam classes que eu vejo por aí não precisariam ser escritos desta forma e não teriam malefícios usarem o procedural puro, desde que feito do jeito certo. Programar certo é necessário em qualquer paradigma.

Muitos dizem que assim é mais organizado. Eu até concordo que OOP pode ajudar a organizar mais o código para quem não consegue organizar de outra forma. Eu entendo que as receitas de bolo em OOP costumam ser bem organizadas e as receitas que não usam OOP costumam ser mais desorganizadas, até porque elas foram feitas em uma época que as pessoas não dominavam tanto o que estavam fazendo, mas só ajuda se a pessoa é seguidora de receita.

Se o programador vai criar programas por conta própria, ele terá que aprender fazer direito, e pode fazer organizado nos dois paradigmas, na maioria dos cenários.

[Para saber mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50273/101).

## Padrões de projeto e *frameworks*

Os padrões de projeto famosos, gerais e mais úteis e arquiteturas - tipo [MVC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC) - podem ser muito bem aplicados em OOP ou procedural.

Muitos [padrões de projeto também famosos só funcionam para OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). Mas eles existem para resolver os problemas que OOP começou impor (informação complementar nos comentários by rray). Já virou meme o abuso destes padrões específicos.

Outros existem porque a linguagem é estática. Linguagens dinâmicas, como PHP, são bem mais flexíveis e exigem menos padrões de projeto "artificiais". Estão querendo "acabar" com isto também (até gosto de linguagem estática, mas PHP é o que é por ser dinâmica).

Princípios foram criados para ajudar as pessoas usarem OOP do jeito certo, mas a maioria os desconhece ou não sabem quando usar e quando deixar de lado.

Tudo isto acrescenta complexidade para o software. Quando ele precisa disso, ótimo, esta complexidade ajuda softwares que precisam ser complexos serem mais fáceis de dar manutenção. Se não precisava disso vira apenas complicação.

Concordo que OOP ajudou criar os *frameworks* atuais que fazem tanto sucesso. De fato esse paradigma ajuda esse tipo de software. Eu até questiono um pouco o uso deles. Não que não tenha vantagem, eles apenas não resolvem tudo. E é comum as pessoas os adotarem porque não sabem fazer as coisas direito, o motivo é errado.

Mas em códigos mais comuns vejo poucas vantagens no seu uso.

## OOP não resolve tudo

Ao contrário do que algumas pessoas acreditam, [OOP tá cheio de defeitos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Criticism), bem cheio, e [não resolve todos os problemas](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/unix_and_oo.html). A questão é saber quando ela tem mais vantagens que desvantagens, e escolher seu uso de forma consciente, e não porque ouviu dizer (ouviu de alguém que é apaixonado pela metodologia e muitas vezes ganha dinheiro disseminando ela, ouviu que é bom para você e vai resolver todos seus problemas).

Nunca ninguém apresentou provas, ou mesmo evidências empíricas, que OOP dá mais produtividade que outros paradigmas. Pelo contrário, há pelo menos um [estudo mostrando que não há ganhos](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/%7Ev8q/Homepage/Papers%20Old/spetep-%20printable.pdf). Outro [mostrando que as linguagens não se beneficiam fundamentalmente desse paradigma](http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/object-oriented-programming-is-an-expensive-disaster-which-must-end).

Mas a análise que mais gosto é do Paul Graham quando define a [mediocridade como fator determinante para o sucesso do paradigma](http://www.paulgraham.com/noop.html).

[OOP não reproduz o mundo real](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Are-We-There-Yet-Rich-Hickey) como alguns pregam.

Note bem que não estou dizendo que OOP é uma porcaria que não deveria ser usada. Algumas pessoas tendem a enxergar só esta parte do que digo e não a ponderação, até porque elas não ponderam o uso. Elas pensam: "Ou você é amigo da OOP ou é inimigo". Eu uso OOP onde precisa.

Há um problema generalizado do entendimento do que é a computação e o processo científico como um todo. Então a pessoa lê um livro que dá uma visão, compra esta visão e passa repeti-la sem saber do que está falando. E olha que eu odeio academicismos. E os melhores programadores que conheço não são formados (isso tem mudado um pouco).

Há um [artigo que reúne várias críticas fundamentas sobre o uso de OOP](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/all-evidence-points-to-oop-being-bullshit).

## Conclusão

Eu fiz várias simplificações aqui. A intenção não é escrever uma tese, é alertar e tentar fazer a pessoa refletir e procurar mais informações, até mesmo fazendo novas perguntas mais específicas, até questionando o que eu disse, assim outras pessoas podem escrever e dar uma visão plural. É ruim quando se aceita cegamente a visão de uma pessoa, mesmo que seja a minha visão. Desconfie dela também. Seja proativo, só não seja teimoso, só você perde (se as pessoas que te contratam, estas perdem por tabela).

Use ambas. Aprenda o que tem de vantagem em cada uma e aproveita as vantagens. Evite o [martelo dourado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

[image: Martelo usado com um parafuso]

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: Sobre linguaguens que deram suporte a OO lá no inicio(quando?) parece que elas se venderam melhor, os conceitos definidos pelo Alan Kay foram pratica transformados em funcionalidades simples de usar como as 3 que foram citadas na resposta além de estado e escopo mais flexivel(variáveis locais X globais), apesar de alguns mecanismos já existirem como naquele pergunta sobre polimorfismo em linguagem procedural. Se entendi direito o que aconteceu foi, linguagens com recursos mais simples de usar e sua utilização deveria seguir o paradigma OO. Isso parece fundido, como se os mecanismos não ...

Comment: Como se os mecanismos não existissem sem os conceitos. Outro ponto que vendem é procedural foca-se em resolver o problema mas em baixo nível equanto OO baseia-se fortemente em abstrações de alto nível chamando abstração de baixo nível para resolver problemas('tecnicos', bits&bytes). Também é possível criar certas abstrações com procedural e até aplicar refatorações como 'compor método'. Aplicar os conceitos de OO em exemplos `carro.motor.funcionar()` é bem simples, na hora de jogar isso para um problema real balancear o nível de abstração e onde ele de ficar é um pouco mais complicado.

Comment: Concordo com o 1o. comentário integralmente. Não sei se entendi bem a afirmação. Você está dizendo do mito que procedural é mais concreto, mais baixo nível? Isto de fato é um mito, dá para abstrair bem no procedural. OOp tem alguns mecanismo melhores para alguns tipos de abstração. Mas para usá-los precisam entender como fazer isto direito. Eu vejo cada afirmação aqui no site de pessoas que "adotam" OOP... Eles não têm a menor noção e acham que estão certos. Criar abstrações certamente não é algo fácil, inclusive para nomear variáveis que não deixa de ser uma criação de uma abstração.

Comment: Sobre "procedural ser mais baixo nível" isso é visto em livros geralmente e argumentam que "OO é mais simples pelo fato de tentar imitar o mundo real". Outro ponto sobre DP que quase ninguém comenta é no livro do GOF a maioria deles é aplicado para resolver problemas de GUI e os exemplos estão em C++ e foi publicado em 94, antes disso os padrões já deveriam existir mas não eram populares e talvez não tivessem nomes. Problemas de GUI naquela década pareciam ser o bicho.

Comment: OOP é péssimo para imitar o mundo real :) Isso faz parte do mkt. Antes disse ñ eram necessário pq ñ usavam OOP q criou os problemas q eles resolvem :) Claro que tem coisa que é útil universalmente. E tem problema é existe por causa da linguagem ser estática. OOP foi adotada por causa de GUI, depois teve gente que achou que deveria usar em tudo. O GoF organizou e popularizou alguns deles.

Comment: Voltaram meus votos, +1 pela resposta e obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: Em uma aplicação orientada a objetos que utiliza PHP, pode-se dizer que a execução inicial será sempre procedural? Por exemplo, a framework Symfony é orientada a objetos, mas tem o "app.php" que inicia e termina o ciclo, onde tudo é inicializado. O que eu quero dizer é que uma aplicação que utiliza PHP depende sempre de algum código procedural, certo?

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Acredito que sim, não o conheço pra afirmar. Na verdade mesmo OOP no fundo tem um (não tão) pouco de procedural, as pessoas esperam uma pureza que não existe.

Answer (score 17):

Existem muitos exemplos internet a fora de como utilizar a linguagem de forma errada, como formatação de data, utilização de funções obsoletas, código vulnerável a sql injection etc.

A linguagem da suporte aos paradigmas orientado a objetos e procedural, a definição de qual escolher fica a cargo do programador. Procedural e OO são ideias de como organizar o código ou seja é possível programar de forma procedural em linguagens '100% OO' ou 'puras'.

Comment: +1. Com os códigos obsoletos que se disseminam na internet por conta do programador PHP não procurar se informar e se atualizar. E digo mais: Tutoriais em PHP em português são (na maioria dos casos, não generalizando) ruins. Por isso desenvolvi o hábito de pesquisar as coisas em inglês (foi assim que conheci o SOEN).