# PHP 7 tem tipagem de argumentos e de retorno, mas é opcional. Isso é bom ou ruim?

Tags: php, estilo-de-codificação, tipagem, php-7, indução-de-tipo

Não gostaria de levantar aqui uma questão polêmica a respeito da linguagem PHP 7, que foi lançada recentemente, mas apenas entender alguns pontos a respeito da tipagem.

Vamos lá:

Nas versões anteriores ao PHP 7, as funções não possuem tipagem de retorno. Temos a indução de tipo para os valores `array`, `objeto` e `interfaces`.

Acho muito útil esses dois últimos citados na indução de tipo.

Porém, com o lançamento do PHP 7, foram adicionados suporte a indução dos tipos `float`, `int`, `bool`,  `string` e etc...

Nesse ponto, creio que tenha facilitado, em relação a não ter que ficar fazendo ifs dentro da minha função/método e lançar uma exceção caso o argumento seja um tipo inesperado. O PHP 7 já faz isso.

Mas aqui vai a questão que quero fazer: Também é possível não informar o tipo de argumento que tal função vai receber.

Exemplo com indução de tipo:

```
function soma(int $a, int $b) : int
{
    return $a + $b;
}
```

Exemplo sem indução de tipo:

```
function soma($a, $b)
{
     return $a+$b;
}
```

Veja, é possível fazer das duas formas no PHP 7.

Então, não querendo ser crítico em relação ao recurso da linguagem (que ajuda em alguns casos), mas qual é o motivo de se adicionar indução de tipos para os tipos comuns do PHP, se afinal de contas quem vai codificar vai escolher se ele vai usar esse recurso ou não?

Isso é para manter compatibilidade com código legado? Ou é para tornar a linguagem dinâmica?

Isso me deixa um pouco confuso.

Comment: Creio que seja o mais óbvio. Manter uma retrocompatibilidade. Não é interessante perder usuários ou desincentivá-los na migração para as novas versões.

Comment: De argumentos me parece muito útil, ajuda a trabalhar melhor e evitar coisas como is_string, is_array, is_int, etc. Agora no `return` parece mesmo desnecessário na maioria dos casos, talvez seja por uma questão de `cast` como o valor veio quebrado como 1.0 (float), então teria que usar algo como `return (int) $a;`, se você tiver vários `returns` fica mais fácil já induzir a saída. Mais tarde formulo uma resposta :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não sei se é inútil a questão do `return`. Me caiu muito bem no framework que estou fazendo. Acho que facilita a compreensão de uma implementação de uma interface, por exemplo. `ArrayableInterface::toArray() : array`. Saca?

Comment: Sei que é uma "supersimplificação", mas basicamente onde a tipagem vai mais ajudar, é achar bugs e/ou inconsistências mais cedo. Ao fazer o parse, o PHP já vai poder te avisar de uma série de tipos não compatíveis que você normalmente só descobriria chamando todas as funções em todas as condições possíveis. Ou em (argh!..) testes unitários, se estiver com sorte.

Comment: @Bacco leia-se `print_r` e `var_dump`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters bom exemplo!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## *Type Hinting*

O que a linguagem está fazendo é colocar o máximo possível de *type hinting*, ou uma ajuda para o compilador verificar contratos no uso de funções. Isto ajuda detectar erros de forma mais simples e teoricamente mais cedo - o que não acontece com PHP por ser uma linguagem de *script*.

Esta parece ser uma tentativa do PHP de abraçar softwares mais complexos que "exigem" tipagem estática. Tipagem dinâmica dificulta a escala de projetos grandes.

## Um pouco de opinião

Não entendo bem o que estão fazendo, já que o nicho onde a linguagem é forte não precisa muito disto, e se precisar de escala do projeto, [Hack](https://hacklang.org/), só para ficar no exemplo de mesma sintaxe, faz o serviço completo. Praticamente ninguém usa Hack e isto mostra como esses recursos que ajudam escalar projetos são desnecessários para estes que o PHP atende. É só uma pena que as pessoas se encantem pelo que não é necessário. Mostra que as pessoas escolhem tecnologias como religião e não por motivos técnicos.

Não entenda errado, acho a tipagem estática importantíssima, muito, mas muito mais que OOP, que as pessoas passaram adorar em PHP sem uma razão aparente.

## Estático X dinâmico

A linguagem não pode e nunca poderá ser realmente estática, sem perder **compatibilidade com tudo existente**, onde o ganho passa ser mais interessante. Não pode em parte pelo legado existente e em parte porque isto mudaria a semântica de forma profunda. É bom que a linguagem continue assim e dê opção, ainda que isto não seja o ideal para a robustez.

Seria melhor se a linguagem pudesse habilitar uma verificação obrigatória para quem prefere assim. Pode ser que até já exista, mas entendo se não existir, afinal a **essência da linguagem continua ser de *script***, então seria difícil definir quando pode usar uma coisa ou outra e a **tipagem dinâmica é muito importante para uma linguagem de *script***, que deve exigir pouca cerimônia.

É bom deixar claro que isto não deixa a linguagem mais dinâmica, muito pelo contrário, deixa ela mais rígida (nem tanto por não ser obrigatório). Pode eventualmente ajudar a dar mais robustez, o que é bom.

## [Paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101)

E é mais importante dizer que isto não tem nada a ver com OOP ou outros paradigmas. Vejo que ainda há muita confusão do que é paradigma, metodologia, princípio, fundamento, padrão, sistema, modo, tipagem, etc. Se paradigmas podem ser ortogonais, imagine outros conceitos.

Tipagem nada tem a ver com paradigma algum, embora eventualmente algum possa se encaixar melhor com alguma tipagem. E curiosamente, pasmem, OOP puro se encaixa melhor com tipagem dinâmica. Mas como as linguagens que fizeram o paradigma "estourar" são estáticas muita gente acha que é o contrário.

## Conclusão

De uma certa forma a pergunta responde a si mesma. Só confirmei o que foi perguntado/afirmado. É a melhoria possível, não haverá ganho de performance, interoperabilidade, robustez total, ou outros ganhos que a tipagem estática dá. E por ser opcional não perde nada do que a dinâmica fornece.

Ela é uma melhoria interessante para usar um muitos lugares, mas não em todos. Ao contrário de OOP que, em PHP, é para usar em poucos lugares.

Quem entende de OOP sabe que a tipagem dinâmica dá polimorfismo "for free" (o custo de processamento alto existe). Muitos dos tais *design patterns* famosos são desnecessários neste tipo de linguagem. Isto é bom! Se você tomar os devidos cuidados! O que não é difícil em *scripts*.

Então acho que é bom ter a possibilidade de induzir o tipo, mas para PHP é melhor ainda que seja opcional. E pra falar bem a verdade, se é para ter tipagem estática mesmo é melhor usar outra linguagem. Isto, apesar de ser bem-vindo, é uma deturpação do que fez a linguagem ser o sucesso que é. Se as pessoas usarem bem será uma ferramenta útil. Espero que não façam como OOP que é usado onde não deveria e não faz nada útil pelo código de *script*.

- [Entenda mais sobre tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).
- [Veja sobre a mistura de paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101).

## Extra

E passado um tempo eu edito aqui para colocar que PHP 8.0 resolveu praticamente virar uma linguagem estática e determinar que PHP quer ser Java. É muito estranho e o resultado não é bom. Uma linguagem não nasce de *script* e se torna *enterprise* sem um preço alto a pagar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A adição de uma tipagem mais rigida muda bastante a linguagem em si, é engraçado que o time de desenvolvimente prefere adicionar esse recurso do que consertar as (algumas) funções de strings que não trabalham caractares multibyte, parece que estão varrendo a sujeira para de baixo do tapete.

Answer (score 7):

Estritamente falando o real motivo de "por que é assim?" você teria de perguntar [ao pessoal que propôs e votou](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/voting) na aceitação dessas funcionalidades, contudo não é muito difícil deduzir as razões por trás da tipagem ser opcional:

1. [Compatibilidade com versões anteriores](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibilidade_reversa): Imagine se a nova versão da linguagem exigisse tipagem nas funções, qualquer código php de uma versão anterior estaria **quebrado** na nova versão e caso você deseje atualizar o seu servidor para ela em busca de outras funcionalidades novas, melhorias de segurança ou ganhos de performance seria obrigado a atualizar todo seu código, o que muitas vezes torna o processo inviável. Veja que a história já mostra que lançar uma nova versão de uma linguagem que não é compatível com versões anteriores gera infinitas discussões e divisão na comunidade, vide a transição de python2 para python3 que já dura quase 8 anos e ainda está longe de acabar.
2. Manter a linguagem dinâmica: PHP é por origem um linguagem de script não tipada, isso é o que atrai grande parte dos usuários, logo alterar o compartamento e enforçar tipagem não seria "natural".

Tipagem é algo bom ou ruim?
Essa é uma pergunta subjetiva que gera inúmeras discussões e ainda não possui uma resposta exata. **Na minha opinião**: Tipagem não é só boa, é essencial; a dinâmicidade de uma linguagem não tipada é útil quando você quer escrever algo rápido, prototipar uma ideia, contudo para código de produção a falta de tipagem gera **incerteza**, você tem funções que recebem parâmetros de determinados tipos e retornam determinados tipos e isso é definido pelo código interno dela, não é enforçado pela linguagem, o que da margem para inúmeros erros, coisas como você estar esperando que uma função retorne um inteiro e na verdade ela está retornando um double. Na prática trabalhando com várias pessoas no mesmo código, principalmente se ele for grande, esse tipo de problema ocorre o tempo todo.

Só para reforçar um pouco o meu comentário sobre como tipagem "é boa": é possível notar como a comunidade de programação está aos poucos migrando rumo a tipagem e não a remoção dela. Linguagens populares como php e [python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) estão adotando tipagem opcional, outras como [Haskell](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) estão ganhando notoriedade devido (dentre outros motivos) a seu forte modelo de tipagem.