# Quais as principais diferenças e vantagens entre as linguagens PHP e Hack?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, hack

Vejo que a sintaxe de ambas são bastante semelhantes, mas com certeza elas têm suas diferenças, afinal não são uma só.

Quais são suas diferenças?

Vou colocar alguns itens que acho importantes para a análise (algumas opcionais):

- paradigmas delas;
- ambientes que rodam;
- tipagem;
- evoluções;
- operações;
- manipulação de erros e exceções;
- vantagens em geral de uma em relação à outra.

Só um resumo das diferenças e vantagens. Farei novas perguntas de acordo com as respostas, se necessário.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não vou entrar em detalhes muito específicos, apenas um apanhado geral para ajudar entender as diferenças.

## Tipagem

Vou começar pela tipagem que eu acredito ser a principal diferença. [Hack](http://hacklang.org/) tem [tipagem estática, enquanto que PHP tem uma tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). É bem verdade que [PHP está caminhando, ou quase pronto no básico, para ter uma tipagem estática opcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107705/101). Hack sempre irá se beneficiar por ter isso como fundamento da linguagem. Na verdade a linguagem usa o chamado de [*gradual type system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing) onde pode-se [usar o tipo estático](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/types/introduction), mas também o dinâmico onde for benéfico. Em geral inferência de tipo é usada.

Por causa da tipagem, resumidamente, há mais confiabilidade no código, facilita a manutenção de várias formas e permite melhor performance.

## Ambiente de execução

É importante notar que [PHP é uma linguagem essencialmente de *script*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101) e utilizada para aplicações web. Roda multiplataforma. Hack pode ser usada desta forma com facilidade e sucesso, mas ela tenta ir um pouco além. Ela foi pensada para trabalhar com aplicações que vão além de um *script*. Ela é mais adequada para aplicações diferentes de web, embora faltem experiências nesse sentido e bibliotecas que ajudem. É importante lembrar que ela é usada principalmente pelo Facebook. Hack também roda nas principais plataformas.

Hack usa um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) que gera um código nativo para a plataforma que está executando. Isso produz um enorme ganho de performance.

## Maturidade e ecossistema

Claro que Hack era menos madura e possui um ecossistema inferior. Há situações onde o PHP é mais adequado, mesmo Hack sendo uma linguagem "mais moderna".

## Paradigma

[O paradigma básico de quase todas linguagens é o imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). PHP e Hack não são diferentes. [Em PHP a orientação a objeto foi introduzida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101) e é uma adaptação à linguagem. Em Hack isso é mais orgânico e presente de forma mais completa. É uma linguagem que se adéqua mais a este paradigma.

## Tratamento de erros

O tratamento de erros é parecido com a forma mais moderna (uso de exceções) do PHP. Em geral ele não trabalha tanto com a forma legada de erros do PHP (até há compatibilidade), mas ela não é incentivada. A implementação em Hack foi um pouco mais próximo de como outras linguagens trabalham.

## Incompatibilidade

Veja [alguns recursos não suportados](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/unsupported/introduction).

Existe [ferramenta que ajuda converter de PHP para Hack](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/tools/introduction).

## Evolução

As evoluções de PHP tentam chegar mais perto do que Hack já tem, mas nem tudo será possível.

## Melhorias

Um [recurso novo em Hack](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/generics/introduction) que dificilmente terá em PHP é o uso de [genéricos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) que é fundamental para a tipagem estática funcionar em sua plenitude.

[*Lambda* é um recurso que funciona de forma um pouco diferente](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/lambdas/introduction). Assim como [*callables*](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/callables/introduction).

Existe suporte para [`async`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/async/introduction), [*type aliasing*](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/type-aliases/introduction), [*type constant*](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/type-constants/introduction), [*shapes*](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/shapes/introduction), [suporte à XML](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/XHP/introduction), [atributos](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/attributes/introduction), [enumerações](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/enums/introduction), [novos operadores](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/operators/introduction), [entre outros recursos](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/other-features/introduction).

Há grande melhoria na biblioteca e suporte especial à [coleções de dados](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/collections/introduction) que não estão presentes em PHP, em especial [tuplas](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/tuples/introduction). Em Hack o *array* não é usado para tudo, há estruturas de dados mais especializadas com melhor performance, robustez e semântica.

Bebe um pouco na fonte de C#.

## Conclusão

Hack é uma opção para quem precisa de mais performance, mais robustez e facilidades no desenvolvimento e pretende fazer aplicações mais complexas que um conjunto de *scripts* como costuma ser a maioria dos sites.

Claramente PHP quer se tornar Hack. Um dia conversei pessoalmente com o criador de PHP e ele demonstrou um certo desdém com Hack, mas ao mesmo tempo que gostava do que a linguagem tinha. Hack tem a vantagem de não ter o legado a ser considerado e ser melhor pensada. Mas PHP já tem muito do que Hack implantou, s vezes PHP fez pior, por um motivo ou outro, e é provável que tenha outros recursos em breve, alguns já anunciados.

Hoje a linguagem é chefiada pelo Eric Lippert, que é uma das pessoas mais capacitadas da computação e com experiência em linguagens que causa inveja.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 por linkar minha pergunta :D. Brincadeira, a resposta está boa :D

Comment: Acha que é interessante estudar sobre essa linguagem e acredita que ela tenha potencial?

Comment: É interessante estudar qualquer linguagem quando se deseja programar bem. O Facebook a criou e está usando bem. Se muitas pessoas vão usar eu não sei. As pessoas decidem usar as coisas por critérios meio malucos. Se todo mundo está gostando das novidades do PHP então deveriam ir p/ Hack. Se acham que o PHP era bom, não deveriam aceitar as modificações feitas já que a linguagem original que fez sucesso está sendo deturpada. Então existe só o efeito de manada, não de escolha consciente da tecnologia.