# Como ter performance em sistemas?

Tags: php, c++, desempenho

Como funciona a questão da performance em softwares, sites e etc.?

O Facebook *transpilou* PHP em C++ para ganhar performance. Como isso funciona? Sei que com C++ para *setar* exatamente as variáveis, mas a performance depende da linguagem, programador ou hardware?

Comment: A velocidade de um carro depende do motorista, do fabricante ou do pneu?

Comment: creio que seja do fabricante talvez do motorista se ver de outra forma!

Comment: O ponto é que não tem uma resposta. Se uma área for deficiente, o todo é afetado. É uma questão extremamente ampla e não dá pra apontar uma coisa em específico que é mais importante. Quando tiver um caso específico, aí sim dá pra analisar e ver onde tá o gargalo; o que está impactando o programa mais severamente. De modo amplo, é uma questão que não tem informações o suficiente pra dar uma resposta específica.

Comment: Boa forma de pensar @PedrovonHertwig obrigado!

Comment: @WillianCesar A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

O maior ganho de performance sempre será dado pelo programador. Uma escolha errada por mudar a performance facilmente em pelo menos 10 ordens de magnitude.

Usar algoritmos certos sempre é o melhor caminho. Usar bibliotecas performáticas ajuda muito. A linguagem pode dar alguma diferença, mas somente em linguagens muito dispares é que terá diferenças que podem chegar a apenas uma ordem de magnitude.

Os casos de diferenças maiores são de bibliotecas ruins. A maioria dos caos não deve mudar mais que 3 ou 4 vezes.

Uma linguagem de *script*, interpretada, com tipagem dinâmica e sem mecanismo que procurem o menos custo da abstração realmente pode dar uma diferença grande. Mas a diferença não será tão grande só pela *transpilação*. Tanto que o ganho passou ser melhor quando passaram usar a [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101). E mais ganho quando começaram usar outras linguagens.

Facebook fez isso porque a decisão inicial foi ruim, havia uma base muito grande de código para ser portado, por alguma razão acharam que era mais simples criar uma infraestrutura nova do que reescrever todo o código, o que é um completo absurdo em um caso como este. Ou seja, eles estavam com vontade de fazer isso. E claro, o ganho para eles foi muito grande, Se você estiver usando 10.000 servidores e puder reduzir para 1.000, vale o esforço, só acho que poderiam ter reescrito o código em outra linguagem. Vários unicórnios preferiram esse caminho, mesmo tento um ganho geral bastante inferior ao do Facebook, mas até maior no detalhe.

Toda rede Stack Exchange, incluindo o site principal com cerca de 10 milhões de visitas por mês, poderia, no limite extremo, servir tudo em apenas um único servidor ([roda em 9 para dar folga](https://stackexchange.com/performance)), e com performance bem superior ao do Facebook. Em C# que nem é uma linguagem considerada tão performática. Isto é engenharia. Tem gente que faz coisas muito simples, sem concorrência, só uma operação, e entope a máquina por completo.

Eu até questiono se precisava tudo isso. O gasto para fazer um software tão rápido provavelmente é maior que o custo de adicional um pouco mais de hardware, sem falar na inflexibilidade e dificuldade de manutenção causado (a UX é prejudicada por causa da filosofia adotada, as melhorias são implementadas a passo de tartaruga). O Facebook também é assim.

Hardware dará ganho linear, no máximo, provavelmente bem menos que isto. E o ganho por dólar adicionado será bem inferior depois de entrar na casa dos milhares.

Eu responderia um pouco melhor se o texto da pergunta fosse um pouco melhor.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas respondeu um pouco minha duvida mas também eu não expliquei corretamente como eu trabalho com web sei que 90% da performance tem que estar no front-end minificar arquivos e imagens mas ganho mais performance do que apenas minificar arquivos a questão muitos acessos como faço para que o servidor não caia não entendo muito isso ainda pois sou novo na área e sistema com muitas linhas de código como ganhar performance nisso também?

Comment: tipo o Google com youtube como eles conseguem carregar tão rápido um vídeo não sei talvez hardware ou programador mesmo?

Comment: Não, está longe de ser isto. E a pergunta está se torna ampla demais, fora que o carro está entrando na frente do bois.

Comment: Oque sera então a linguagem quero aprender como fazer meus sistemas terem mais performance abrir mais rápido pensar mais rápido ate mesmo armazenar e ler mais rápido?

Comment: tenho esse problema em me expressar desculpe!