# PHP 8.2: O que são Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF) Types?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, tipagem, php-8

Essa é uma nova *feature* adicionada na linguagem nessa versão. Como funciona? Quais contextos e vantagens no seu uso?

E qual a relação com *Intersection types*? Se possível dar uma visão sobre esse último também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP começou um caminho para se tornar uma linguagem mais robusta e para isto passou adotar o que existe em tipagem estática. Como a linguagem sempre foi de tipagem dinâmica e não pode quebrar compatibilidade, na verdade a tipagem não pode ser estática de fato, mas pode ter algumas vantagens com anotações de tipos para que o compilador pegue erros mais cedo, no local mais adequado e possa dar melhores mensagens de erro.

Quando a linguagem anota tipo o código passa ter que respeitar alguns contratos e não pode mais fazer do jeito que bem entende desde que dê o resultado esperado, tem que estar correto. E isto deixa a linguagem menos flexível, obriga em alguns casos fazer códigos mais complexos para resolver certas questões que envolvem mais de uma possibilidade de código. O que antes podia usar um dado de "tipo" *mixed*, ou seja, o que vier, aceita e se ele for adequado faz o que deve fazer, nas versões mais recentes pode-se anotar o tipo do dado e aí só aquele tipo é aceito, o que dá a tal da robustez.

Acontece que em alguns casos pode ser útil poder receber um tipo ou outro(s). E de acordo com cada um fazer algo ligeiramente diferente e ainda alcançar o resultado desejado.

Especialmente em PHP isso é importante porque a linguagem, atualmente, não tem como ter sobrecarga de métodos para executar algo um pouco diferente dependendo do tipo que usa.

Mais ainda, e se você precisar garantir que algum dado cumpra mais de um contrato?

Como resolver essa questão então?

Os tais tipos disjuntivos podem fazer isto.

Existem basicamente dois deles: a união (`|`) e a interseção (`&`).

A união (*union type*) permite dizer que você aceita um tipo OU o outro tipo. Ou seja, se vier qualquer um dos tipos de dados naquele parâmetro e retorno (por enquanto só eles), eles poderão ser manipulados por seu método ou função.

A interseção (*intersection type*) exige que você mande um dado de um tipo E o outro tipo. Ou seja, tem que vir um dado que cumpra o contrato de todos os tipos de dados naquele parâmetro e retorno (por enquanto só eles), para que possam ser manipulados por seu método ou função.

É possível até misturar ambos.

Um exemplo bastante óbvio seria este:

```
function teste(int|null valor) {
    if (valor == null) {
        echo 'sem valor';
        return;
    }
    echo valor;
}
```

Não pode mandar uma *string*, pode só um `int` ou um `null`.

Outro exemplo só para demonstrar o mecanismo, considere que as interfaces são:

```
interface HasId {
    public function getId(): string;
}
interface HasName {
    public function getName(): string;
}
```

que exigem que o tipo tenha uma determinada formação. Exemplo só para demonstrar o mecanismo.

```
function generateHash(HasName & HasId $item) : string {
    return sha1($item->getName() . $item->getId());
}
```

Esse caso ele espera um valor qualquer desde que o objeto tenha os métodos `getName()` E `getId()`, porque o código precisa dos dois (não basta um deles).

Então isto é permitido:

```
class Pessoa {
     public function getId() : string { return '1'; }
     public function getName() : string { return 'João'; }
}
generateHash(new Pessoa());
generateHash(null);
```

Mas isto não executará e gerará um erro específico de inadequação do tipo:

```
class Produto {
     public function getId() : string { return '1'; }
     public function getDescription() : string { return 'Arroz'; }
}
generateHash(new Produto());
```

Veja [funcionando no **Online PHP**](https://onlinephp.io/c/b6aa1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/Disjunction.php).

Isso ajuda flexibilizar sem quebrar a robustez. Ainda que a linguagem está cheia de pontos de pouca robustez ou pouca flexibilidade. É complicado para uma linguagem mudar tanto assim de filosofia e manter a compatibilidade. Se fizeram um pouco mais praticamente ela se transforma em [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101) (mas teria a quebra de compatibilidade).