# Programação Orientada a Objeto e Procedural ao mesmo tempo em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, procedural

Galera tenho um sistema em PHP que venho desenvolvendo a mais de um ano. Ele foi escrito praticamente de forma procedural, pois me adaptei melhor, e acho mais simples de trabalhar. Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

*E ruim misturar POO dentro de um sistema procedural?*

Comment: Se o paradigma procedural funciona bem para você não sei qual é a necessidade de você mudar de paradigma ou misturar com outro. Eu diria para você fazer o que funciona melhor e vai garantir menos problemas no futuro :D rsrs.

Comment: Misturando você estará aproveitando o melhor de cada um. Quem tem experiência faz isso normalmente quando a linguagem permite. Só não acontece muito, pois a boa parte das pessoas não se aprofunda nem em um, quanto mais em dois paradigmas, por isso se atrapalham um bocado. Agora, se domina o procedural, OOP não vai te acrescentar nada de bom em PHP especificamente. Só é bom conhecer para consumir o que já tem pronto, pois as maiores vantagens que a orientação a objeto poderia trazer, não fazem tanta diferença numa linguagem que é pra fazer um punhado de scripts.

Comment: Entendo, bom deixa eu tentar explicar melhor meu caso. Eu tento manter o meu código o mais organizado possível. Exemplo, tenho uma paina caixa.php, onde tenho o php fazendo o select e montando o html. A página esta toda documentada, dentada. Isso e o correto? Tipo não sei como e feito em grandes empresas, não quero desenvolver um sistema todo gambiarra entende.

Comment: Se tiver a curiosidade, veja essa postagem:[PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104340/70)

Comment: @HugoBorges não caia no mito do "como é feito em grandes empresas", muitas vezes as grandes empresas fazem cada coisa horrenda. Aliás, tem empresa grande demais que perde o controle do tamanho do soft, e contrata os tais "arquitetos" (existem uns bons, mas não sei se a maioria é), que implantam tudo que tá na moda, aí você precisa de 5 programadores acadêmicos no lugar de cada programador pragmático pra conseguir fazer o sistema continuar rodando.

Comment: hahahhahhahha entendi. estou lendo o link que vc me mandou ;)

Comment: @HugoBorges veja se o que você quer saber já foi respondido no link, capaz que a sua acabe sendo duplicata daquela, aí dá pra fechar a sua linkando praquela outra (ambas continuam no site, valendo pontos, mas apontam pro mesmo resultado, para evitar conteúdo repetido no site).

Comment: Entendi, bom obrigado ;)

Comment: @HugoBorges vendo o histórico de edição da pergunta, um palpite meu é que se seu sistema estiver funcionando bem no procedural, acho que você tem mais é que aproveitar as vantagens, e não tem a mínima necessidade de passar nada pra OOP. Mas se precisar usar um componente orientado a objeto, não faz mal nenhum usar. E tem mais: o fato de usar classes não necessariamente significa que está programando em OO, dá muito bem pra usar as classes já existentes no PHP em programação procedural.

Comment: ... ainda que também não tenha necessidade na maioria dos casos