# Declarar variáveis públicas no método __construct

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, visibilidade

Observe o exemplo do método:

```
<?php
#noticia_construct.class.php
class Noticia{
    public $titulo; // Acredito que não seja necessário
    public $texto; // Acredito que não seja necessário
    function __construct($valor_tit, $valor_txt){
        $this -> titulo = $valor_tit;
        $this -> texto = $valor_txt;
    }
    function exibeNoticia(){
        echo "
            <center>
                <b>". $this->titulo ."</b>
                <p>". $this->texto ."</p>
            </center>
        ";
    }
}
$noticia = new Noticia('Novo curso de PHP Avançado', 'Abordaremos: POO, XML, tex.');
$noticia -> exibeNoticia();
?>
```

Minha dúvida é sobre a necessidade de declarar as variáveis como públicas.
Elas não são utilizadas em lugar algum do código. Em outros exemplos da apostila acontece a mesma coisa(sobre classes e herança). Se eu retiro esta parte do código, ele continua funcionando.

Declarar a visibilidade sas variáveis é alguma boa prática ou algo parecido?

Este é um exemplo da apostila de PHP avançado da Unicamp.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

## Visibilidade

A decisão se vai deixar a variável pública ou não é do programador de acordo com a necessidade. O fato de não usar em outros lugares não significa que não possa ser usada em algum momento. O que muito programador não entende é que a classe deve ser pensada para ser usada em diversas situações. Se for para fazer algo simples, que não vai ser usada de diversas formas e não precisará de manutenção complexa, não tem por que criar uma classe.

O importante é entender por que fazer as coisas. Apostilas servem para dar uma base sobre a técnica, mas elas não ensinam as pessoas pensarem sobre os problemas e como resolvê-los.

O mais comum em orientação a objeto é deixar as variáveis privadas até que tenha um motivo para torná-las públicas. Porém acho razoável entender que esses dados podem ser necessários em algum lugar de forma isolada, principalmente se a classe é só isso mesmo, onde ela teria pouca utilidade. Eu provavelmente faria dessa forma, se eu fosse obrigado criar uma classe ([isso pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101)).

#### Fazendo OOP em PHP

Outro ponto importante é sobre métodos para acessar os campos da classe. Há quem diga que eles devem ser usados sempre. Isso faz até algum sentido, mas muitas pessoas repetem isso sem saber por que é necessário. Quer fazer assim, ok, todo mundo pode fazer como quiser, mas em PHP não tem necessidade na maioria dos casos.

PHP é uma linguagem de *script*, os códigos possuem *binding* em tempo de execução, então do ponto de vista técnico não faz diferença acessar a variável ou um método, a não ser que se saiba que o método precisará ser usado no futuro. Mesmo nesses casos tenho minhas dúvidas se ele é tão útil para aplicações que o PHP se encaixa bem (eu sei que muita gente faz uso do PHP onde ele não se encaixa, mas aí o problema é outro).

Na maior parte dos casos é mais interessante inicializar os membros existentes com um construtor. Nem sempre, mas [precisa saber quando usar um construtor ou não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), não pode só seguir uma regra.

## Deixar de declarar variáveis

Se a pergunta fosse sobre o que o bfavaretto falou em comentário abaixo (o AP mostrou que não é), sobre a variável ser criada automaticamente sem ser declarada, até é possível, mas não é recomendado, o motivo de criar uma classe é justamente organizar o código, declarar qual a função dela, seus membros, poder é uma coisa, ser certo é outra. Algumas coisas imprevisíveis podem ocorrer.

Na verdade, esse é apenas um dos motivos que eu tenho objeções à OOP em PHP, a linguagem não foi pensada para isso, ela deixa fazer muita coisa errada em nome da "simplicidade", OOP não combina com isso. Em PHP um objeto é só uma forma de *array* associativo que permite inserir e retirar membros à esmo.

Me surpreende a Unicamp ensinando PHP, tomara que seja só algum curso caça-níquel.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que a dúvida dele não é nem essa (apesar de eu concordar que deveria ser private). Parece que ele descobriu que pode omitir a declaração das propriedades públicas, o PHP as cria on the fly na atribuição. Mas omitir compromete muito a clareza do código, na minha opinião.

Comment: @bfavaretto o comentário código até induz a isso, mas a descrição fala em declará-las como públicas já que não usa em lugar algum. Editei para falar dessa parte.

Comment: Desculpem se me expressei mal, mas a questão abordada é referente a declaração, publica ou privada da variável. Mas concordo que deveria ser declarada como privada.
Provavelmente a apostila que cito é de algum aluno, não da instituição propriamente dita.

Comment: @MatheusDelatorrre obrigado por esclarecer, a resposta tem informações sobre as duas coisas, tentei ser o mais completo possível dando uma perspectiva de como deve ser o uso com OOP e como isso não costuma ser necessário de fato.

Comment: Eu que agradeço @bigown!

Comment: @bigown esta resposta vai de encontra a nossa converse de outro dia, deixa-me a pensar que estou a fazer tudo errado desde sempre com o PHP....

Comment: @JorgeB. isso eu não posso dizer, mas acho que a forma de uso do PHP é errada na maioria dos casos. Não é culpa do PHP! (ou quase). Vejo bem poucas justificativas para fazer coisas complexas em PHP. Dá para fazer, mas é a ferramenta errada. Se é simples, ótimo! Não tem porque usar recursos que servem para fazer coisas complexas (estou falando de OOP). Até existe alguma vantagem em usar a classe, mas como isso foi um remendo, e não algo pensado na linguagem, é quase o mesmo que usar um *array* associativo. Eu falo disso entendendo o todo, as duas linhas de pensamento.

Comment: Eu morro de rir das suas respostas, @bigown

Comment: @taiar mas é sério :)

Answer (score 3):

## Resposta à pergunta

Você está correto! Se você deseja que as variáveis fiquem mesmo públicas, ao utilizá-las dentro da classe elas são declaradas implicitamente (públicas). Este exemplo funciona sem erros nem warnings:

```
<?php
  class Banana {
    public function __construct($a, $b) {
      $this->a = $a;
      $this->b = $b;
    }

    public function s() {
      echo "Digamos que {$this->a} {$this->b}.." . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }

  $a = new Banana('FORA', 'TEMER');
  $a->s();

  $a->b = "PEC 241";
  $a->s();
```

Repare que as variáveis de instância $a e $b não foram declaradas e eu consigo inclusive atualizar o seu valor diretamente de fora da classe.

## Recomendações

No seu código não existe a necessidade de declarar as variáveis como públicas e, inclusive, é recomendável que elas sejam privadas.

Em orientação a objetos, não é muito comum que você deixe variáveis públicas. A boa prática é que sua classe se expresse através de métodos.

No exemplo que você forneceu, seria interessante que você deixasse as suas variáveis privadas e criasse métodos para acessar seus valores (chamados getters e setters). Segue um exemplo:

```
<?php

class Noticia {

    private $titulo;
    private $texto;

    function exibeNoticia(){
        echo "
            <center>
                <b>". $this->titulo ."</b>
                <p>". $this->texto ."</p>
            </center>
        ";
    }

    public function setTitulo($titulo) {
      $this->titulo = $titulo;
    }

    public function setTexto($texto) {
      $this->texto = $texto;
    }

    public function getTitulo() {
      return $this->titulo;
    }

    public function getTexto() {
      return $this->texto;
    }
}

$noticia = new Noticia();
$noticia->setTitulo("Título da notícia");
$noticia->setTexto("Texto da notícia......");

$noticia->exibeNoticia();
```

Isso é uma boa prática por vários motivos, vou citar alguns deles:

1. Desacopla o construtor da classe: você agora não precisa mais necessariamente passar os valores no construtor da classe, ao instanciá-la;
2. Encapsula os dados da classe: recomento que você leia mais sobre o conceito de encapsulamento em orientação a objetos. Basicamente, sua classe pode fazer várias coisas ao setar uma de suas propriedades e o programador que está utilizando a sua classe, não precisa se preocupar com isso.

Vamos supor que, ao setar o título, você quer sempre remover caracteres HTML. Desse jeito, o seu setter do título ficaria algo assim:

```
    public function setTitulo($titulo) {
      $this->titulo = strip_tags($titulo);
    }
```

Caso este comportamento não estivesse encapsulado, você precisaria fazer essa rotina sempre que fosse atualizar o campo título da sua classe.

Comment: Insistindo na minha interpretação (ver comentário na outra resposta), só para deixar claro pra quem perguntou: independente de a propriedade ser pública ou privada, declare-a no topo da classe. Se não declarar, será criada uma propriedade pública implícita no momento da atribuição, e isso não é claro.

Comment: Sobre os getters e setters, de fato é a recomendação. Mas se eles não tiverem nenhuma lógica adicional dentro, eu usaria propriedades públicas (afinal pra que complicar?)

Comment: Sobre o seu primeiro comentário, você está correto. Vou atualizar a minha resposta para contemplar o assunto. Sobre o seu segundo comentário, a única vantagem em usá-los não estão somente no que eu disse. Quando vc pensa em manutenção de um projeto grande, com APIs bem definidas, isso se torna essencial. Depois dê uma lida aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/2802720