# Como construir uma classe corretamente com métodos de acesso?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters

Como eu faço para juntar várias variáveis em um único objeto? Como eu arrumo o seguinte código?

```
<?php
class Produto {
    //Atributos
    var $cpu;
    var $mb;
    var $psu;

    //Getters & Setters
    function setProduto($produto, $produto1){
        $this->cpu = $produto;
        $this->mb = $produto1;
    }


    function getProduto(){
        return $this->cpu;
        return $this->mb;
    } 
}?>
```

Código para acessar a classe

```
<?php
include('exibindo_classes.php')
$produto = new Produto();
$produto->setProduto('Core i7 7700', 'Z270');

echo $produto->getProduto();
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isto está muito errado. Minha sugestão é se concentrar naos fundamentos, em fazer muito bem o procedural, quando ver que tem necessidade e perceber que já domina o básico então pense em OOP que é menos útil do que se fala, ainda menos em PHP, e mais difícil do que parece. Fazer OOP certo é tão difícil fazer que normalmente sai melhor não usar. Claro que há problemas que se beneficiam muito de OOP e em geral pode ser bem útil quando a pessoa já tem bastante experiência em todo o resto.

Por exemplo, lhe falta ainda condições de dar nomes bons para as coisas, o que é algo básico e deve ser dominado antes de fazer OOP.

Quase sempre *getters* e *setters* não é uma ideia tão boa em PHP quanto é um Java. Até existem [propriedades em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45285/101) que seria um pouco melhor. Vou deixar do jeito que quer, mas já adianto que esta é forma que quase todo mundo faz, porém não é a forma mais correta. E quase todo mundo faz assim porque não aprende corretamente, fica só reproduzindo o que os outros que façam errado também.

É muito difícil fazer OOP certo sem ver o todo, sem conhecer cada detalhe, sem fazer tudo como uma coisa só, o que não tem neste código, mas para dar um passo:

```
<?php
class Produto {
    private $cpu;
    private $mb;
    private $psu;
    public function __construct($cpu, $mb) {
        $this->cpu = $cpu;
        $this->mb = $mb;
    }
    function getCpu() {
        return $this->cpu;
    } 
    function setCpu($cpu) {
        $this->cpu = cpu;
    } 
    function getMb() {
        return $this->mb;
    } 
    function setMb($mb) {
        $this->mb = mb;
    } 
}

$produto = new Produto('Core i7 7700', 'Z270');
echo $produto->getCpu();
?>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SZNup6). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vfubkgbk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Constructor.php).

Note que usei um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162906/101). É assim que se inicia um objeto. Você não tem apenas um *getters* e um *setter* para todo o objeto, tem uma para cada atributo. Se forem necessários. Eventualmente um `__toString()` poderia ser útil, entre outras coisas, mas quase sempre as pessoas usam errado ([veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), e [mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212797/101)).

Comment: Se a intenção for usar o objeto mais ou menos como um struct, eu removeria todos os getters e setters e usaria direto as propriedades – que são públicas nesse exemplo, porque declaradas com `var`.

Comment: É o que eu faria. Vou arrumar isto.

Comment: entendi.. era isso q eu estava com dúvida.. se tem um get e um set para cada atributo.

Comment: @Stormwind não sei se entendi o que quer saber.

Comment: @Stormwind então, depende de contexto, correto sem contexto é sempre errado :) Como eu disse, em PHP eu sequer teria uma classe mesmo, se tivesse um motivo para uma classe, acho que o construtor seria assim, mas tem esse exemplo não é bom para se basear. O certo depende de muitos fatores concretos e este é abstrato demais. Por isso que eu falo que todo mundo aprende OOP errado, todo mundo ensina errado, ensina com exemplos abstratos, aí a pessoa acha que é assim. Mesmo sabendo fazer certo é difícil fazer certo, eu erro o tempo todo, minha única vantagem é que reconheço isso :D

Answer (score 6):

Eu não vejo muito sentido em ficar criando getters e setters em PHP em muitos casos. Claro que vai depender muito do contexto, de como a classe foi projetada e do uso que você pretende fazer das instâncias dela. Às vezes o que você precisa é um simples objeto com propriedades públicas. Por exemplo:

```
<?php
class Produto {
    public $cpu;
    public $mb;
    public $psu;

    public function __construct($cpu, $mb, $psu) {
        $this->cpu = $cpu;
        $this->mb = $mb;
        $this->psu = $psu;
    }
}

$produto = new Produto('Core i7 7700', 'Z270', '500W');
echo $produto->cpu; // Core i7 7700
$produto->mb = 'Z271';
echo $produto->mb; // Z271
```

<sup>https://ideone.com/aD5cGk</sup>

Às vezes nem isso, basta um array associativo:

```
$produto = [
    'cpu' => 'Core i7 7700',
    'mb' => 'Z270',
    'psu' => '500W'
];

echo $produto['cpu'];
$produto['mb'] = '...';
// ...
```

Comment: Eu fui no foco da pergunta, mas eu provavelmente nem a classe criaria, em PHP, por isso é a resposta que mais gosto ;)

Comment: Achei que faltava esse contraponto aqui :)

Comment: Esse último exemplo, do array associativo, faz basicamente a mesma coisa de uma classe com magic getters/setters, se não tiver nenhuma lógica a mais nesses acessores. Que é praticamente um *expando object*.

Answer (score 1):

não sei se é o q vc esta querendo, mas a função não pode ter varios retornos, então vc pode utilizar arrays. mais ou menos assim:

```
function getProduto(){
    return array('variavelcpu' => $this->cpu, 'variavelmb' => $this->mb);
}
```

Depois vc pode acessar elas assim:

```
$produtoretorno = $produto->getProduto();
echo $produtoretorno['variavelcpu'];
echo $produtoretorno['variavelmb'];
```

Pelo que entendi q vc está precisando seria isso, se for alguma outra coisa, tenta dar mais detalhes.

Comment: Vlw fernando.. mais eu estou só praticando o que eu aprendi em uma aula.. aí n entendia como q poderia ser feito da forma que eu fiz ou se era só por array msm..

Comment: Entendi @JPFreitas, é que quando vc coloca o retorno na função, qualquer coisa abaixo dela não será executada. 
Por exemplo se vc colocar um return e abaixo dele uma linha com echo, essa linha de baixo nunca será lida.

Answer (score -1):

quebrando a cabeça um pouco.. eu cheguei a seguinte conclusão.. e que deu certo por sinal.. só que eu n estou com arquivos separados(a classe em um arquivo separado da exibição)..

```
<?php
class Produto {
    //Atributos
    private $cpu;
    private $mb;
    private $psu;

    //Getters & Setters
    function setProduto($produto, $produto1, $produto2){
        $this->cpu = $produto;
        $this->mb = $produto1;
        $this->psu = $produto2;
    }


    function getProduto(){
        return $this->cpu;
        return $this->mb;
        return $this->psu;
    } 

    function mostrarProduto(){
        echo $this->cpu .$this->mb .$this->psu;
    }
}

//Exibindo a classe
$produto = new Produto();
$produto->setProduto('Core i7 7700 <br />', 'Z270E STRIX <br />', 'CX750M <br />');
$produto->mostrarProduto();
?>
```

estou correto em usar dessa forma?? estou fazendo um curso de desenvolvimento WEB.. estou no módulo de Orientação a Objetos em PHP..
Agradeço a toda ajuda que vcs estão me proporcionando.

Comment: o seu  getProduto() mais uma vez está errado, vc esta usando varios return, o que acaba retornando apenas a primeira linha `'Core i7 7700 <br />'` e ignorando as outras duas. Porém ele não está sendo utilizado em nenhum lugar no seu código. 

O `<br />` que você utilizada no setProduto, deveria ser tratado dentro da classe, e não quando adicionar o produto. 

mais ou menos assim: **$produto->setProduto('Core i7 7700', 'Z270E STRIX', 'CX750M');** 

E depois dentro de  mostrarProduto(), vc pode colocar assim:
        **echo $this->cpu .'<br />'.$this->mb .'<br />'.$this->psu;**

Comment: Entendi... vlw..

Comment: @JPFreitas não está, parece que pegou parte do que eu fiz, mas manteve algumas coisas erradas.