# Estou tentando aplicar orientação a objetos em um programa em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, refatoração

Estou tentando aplicar orientação a objetos nesse programa e queria começar pela troca desses `if`s, alguém tem alguma dica do que colocar no lugar?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MenuPizza {

    protected static Scanner l;
    private boolean execute;
    protected List<Pizzas> pizzas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MenuPizza();
    }

    public MenuPizza() {

        l = new Scanner(System.in);
        execute = true;
        pizzas = new ArrayList<Pizzas>();

        System.out.println("Olá\n" + "Seja bem-vindo ao nosso menu de pizzas");

        while (execute) {
            String opcao = menu();
            if (opcao.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                inserirPizza();
            } else if (opcao.equals("2")) {
                listarPizza();
            } else if (opcao.equals("3")) {
                removerPizza();
            } else if (opcao.equals("4")) {
                alterarPizza();
            } else if (opcao.equals("5")) {
                exibirMenu();
            } else if (opcao.equals("6")) {
                execute = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nOpção Inválida\n");
            }
        }
    }

    private static String menu() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1. Inserir Pizzas");
        System.out.println("2. Listar Pizzas");
        System.out.println("3. Remover Pizzas");
        System.out.println("4. Alterar Preço da Pizza");
        System.out.println("5. Exibir Menu de Opções");
        System.out.println("6. Sair");
        System.out.println("\r\nDigite uma das opções :");
        return l.nextLine();

    }

    public class Pizzas {

        public String sabor;
        public String preço;

        public Pizzas() {
        }

        public String getSabor() {
            return sabor;
        }

        public void setSabor(String sabor) {
            this.sabor = sabor;
        }

        public String getPreço() {
            return preço;
        }

        public void setPreço(String preço) {
            this.preço = preço;
        }
    }

    private void inserirPizza() {
        boolean inserindo = true;
        while (inserindo) {
            System.out.println("\r\nInserir Pizzas");

            Pizzas d = new Pizzas();
            d.setSabor(textInput("\r\nDigite o sabor da pizza: "));
            d.setPreço(textInput("\nDigite o preço da pizza: "));

            String inserir = textInput("\nAdicionar pizza ?  (S/N)");

            if (inserir.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                System.out.println("\r\nPizza adicionada ao menu");
                pizzas.add(d);
            }

            else if (inserir.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.println("\r\nPizza não adicionada");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("\nOpção inválida\n");
            }
            inserindo = false;
        }
    }

    private void listarPizza() {
        if (pizzas.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("\r\nAinda não há pizzas adicionadas\n");

        } else {
            System.out.println("\r\nListar Pizzas\n");

            for (Pizzas pizzas2 : pizzas) {
                System.out.println("Sabor: " + pizzas2.getSabor());
                System.out.println("Preço: " + pizzas2.getPreço() + "\n");
            }

        }

    }

    private void removerPizza() {
        listarPizza();

        String remover = textInput("Digite o sabor da pizza que deseja remover: ");

        for (Pizzas pizzas2 : pizzas) {
            if (pizzas2.sabor.equalsIgnoreCase(remover)) {
                remover += pizzas.remove(pizzas2);

                System.out.println("\nPizza removida\n");

                listarPizza();
            }

        }

    }

    private void alterarPizza() {
        listarPizza();

        String sabor = textInput("Digite o sabor da pizza que deseja alterar o preço: ");
        String novoPreço = textInput("\nDigite o novo preço: ");

        for (Pizzas pizzas2 : pizzas) {
            if (pizzas2.getSabor().equalsIgnoreCase(sabor)) {
                pizzas2.setPreço(novoPreço);

                System.out.println("\nPreço alterado\n");

                listarPizza();
            }
        }

    }

    private void exibirMenu() {
        menu();
    }

    private String textInput(String fim) {
        System.out.println(fim);
        return l.nextLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Eu não sei quase nada de java, mas em C, dá erro se usar `Ç` para nome de variável

Comment: Em java "Ç" não é um problema. Seu código esta todo desconfigurado, esta obvio que você pegou um código feito em uma linguagem estruturada, e jogou dentro de uma solução JAVA e quebrou tudo.

Comment: Dei uma lida em todas as respostas colocadas aqui.
A resposta do Maniero foi muito excepcional a ponto de me fazer querer ler centenas de livros sobre OOP. Mas como pelo visto você quer a todo custo apenas substituir o if/else tente ler sobre o switch, eu sou apenas um estudante também e não sei se é possível usar o switch com uma String. Dei uma lida rápida no Google e parece ser possível sim usando o metodo hashCode(); Achei algo na [documentação da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) e essa [duvida no stackoverflow](https://stackoverf

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

As pessoas querem fazer orientado a objeto, mas não tem ideia do que seja isso. Na verdade aprendem fragmentos do que é OOP e tentam aplicar. Em geral fica um monstrengo e se bobear ficam com o pior dos dois mundos.

Orientação a objeto não é panaceia e só funciona se o programador souber organizar muito bem o código e entender profundamente porque se usa OO, que vantagens trará fazendo assim, que tenha capacidade de ver quando algo está errado, quando OO ali não é adequado.

Programação orientada a objeto é difícil e mesmo programadores experientes costumam errar muito. Erra mais ainda quando falta entendimento do imperativo antes de tentar o OO. Se for para fazer OO errado é melhor nem fazer. Se for para não ver um benefício claro não vale o esforço.

Minha estimativa informal é que mais de 90% dos programadores acham e falam que programam orientado a objeto, mas nem imaginam que não estão fazendo de fato. Tem uma minoria que faz OO em diversos níveis de qualidade. Por isso não entendo porque o pessoal insiste em tentar algo que eles nunca entendem como fazer.

Já adianto que o imperativo pode ser melhor do que está escrito aí e que a tentativa de deixar orientado a objeto deixou o código mais confuso do que se fizesse mais procedural.

O primeiro problema desse código é que ele faz um monte de coisa diferente dentro de uma só classe. Ele é o principal, é um menu, é o CRUD, é o repositório de dados, é a regra de negócio, ou seja, nada desse código é orientado a objeto já na base.

Não adianta eliminar alguns `if`s que o código não ficará magicamente orientado a objeto. Dá para eliminar o `if` e não ficará nada orientada a objeto. Pode criar um mapa, mas o ganho em legibilidade e manutenibilidade costuma ser zero, pode ser até negativo.

É possível usar uma lógica bastante complexa para permitir criar novas opções no menu sem mexer no código, só adicionando novidade. Não vale a pena fazer isto, não vale nem se o projeto tivesse meio milhão de linhas de código e fosse administrado por uma equipe de dezenas de pessoas e tivesse novidades quase todos os dias, que é onde a orientação a objeto brilha.

Mas para quem? Para chamar coisas privadas? Não faz sentido.

Não entendo porque tem membros protegidos. Pode existir alguma razão, mas parece que foi colocado assim aleatoriamente.

Não entendi essa classe `Pizzas` (o nome deveria ser singular porque representa apenas uma pizza) faz dentro desta classe.

O encapsulamento desta última classe está ruim. E eu questiono se ele é necessário. Claramente ele foi feito como receita de bolo.

Sinto muito, mas a refatoração adequada neste código é começar de novo. Ou tentar fazer algo menos ambicioso.

Comment: Dá para ver que tem certo conhecimento. Gostaria de ver um código simples seu, com esse conceito de OO. Teria algum git ?

Comment: @RaoniBZ o Maniero é lendário, basta abrir seu perfil e abrir o github linkado =) Quase todas as perguntas ele mantém também uma cópia lá no repositório dele feito somente para futura referência das respostas que o Maniero disponibiliza aqui

Comment: Não sabia ! kkkk Dei uma olhada e achei isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237154/101, mas queria algo um pouco maior para entender mais especificamente o conceito de OO como citado. Acho que daria um belo artigo.

Comment: E esse código eu não apliquei OO, só quero tentar aplicar nesse código, que foi pedido pelo meu supervisor dessa forma, com esses métodos, e que fizesse o que ele já está fazendo, até ai tudo bem, porém, ele está muito feio e quero mudá-lo principalmente esse if, acho que você não me compreendeu bem

Comment: Eu quero arrumar tempo pra fazer um projeto *open* com os conceitos certinhos. Faço OOP desde a década de 80, até hj erro. E evoluo sempre alguma coisa. Então nenhum artigo vai resolver nada. Esse é o problema, hoje parece que todo mundo quer fórmulas mágicas. Tem que ler muitos livros, de várias correntes de pensamento, ver os debates gerais, os específicos, ver bons códigos e entender cada detalhe, ver o que sai errado, perguntar muito, pedir ajudas específicas, não tentar aprender tudo de uma vez. Principalmente entender o imperativo 100% antes de ir para OO.

Comment: O resto já falei na resposta, releia ela.

Comment: Entendi, é uma coisa muito difícil que mesmo se eu estudar 40 anos não vou dominar totalmente