# O que significa compilar?

Tags: terminologia, compilação, compiladores

Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o processo de compilação de um código:

- O que é o processo de compilação? Como funciona?
- Quais as etapas do processo de compilação?
- Qual a diferença entre compilação x montagem (Assembler)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### O que é o processo de compilação?

Compilação é o ato / processo de traduzir um programa feito em uma linguagem de alto nível para uma linguagem de máquina, para que suas instruções sejam executadas pelo processador, ou seja, cria o executável de um programa escrito em uma linguagem de alto nível.

### Como funciona?

É feita uma sequencia de `Analises: Léxica, Sintática e Semântica` em cima do código fonte com objetivo de identificar respectivos erros, é gerado um código intermediário (se não me falha a memória o intermediário do processo de compilação de `c` é um arquivo de extensão `.o`), é feita uma otimização deste código e a construção do mesmo para determinada arquitetura (x86, amd64, arm, sparc) ao final do processo tem-se um código de máquina (no windows por exemplo o `.exe`), é feito o `binding` de métodos e bibliotecas (O processo segue uma sequencia `pipes e filtros` basicamente).

Abaixo um exemplo que demonstra o fluxo de sequencia do processo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Quais as etapas do processo de compilação?

1. Pré-processamento (Juntar linhas que foram separadas por sequências de escape;
   Remove comentários e os substitui por espaços em branco; Expande macros; Processa diretivas de pré-processamento (geralmente orientações ao compilador)).
2. Analise lexicográfica.
3. Analise Sintática.
4. Analise Semântica.
5. Gerar código intermediário.
6. Otimização do código.
7. Gera código objeto para determinada arquitetura (arquiteturas diferentes trabalham de forma totalmente diferentes ex: *sparc leem* strings da forma contrária aos x86).
8. Gera código de maquina para a arquitetura determinada (é nesta fase que é chamado o `linker` (sua função é substituir todos as chamadas de funções e acessos a variáveis em arquivos objeto pelo endereço real)).

### Qual a diferença entre compilação x montagem (Assembler).

A montagem é realizada para traduzir um programa em linguagem de montagem (assembly) para seu equivalente em linguagem binária através do montador. possui geralmente os seguintes passos:

1. substituir os nomes simbólicos dos código de operação e operandos.
2. Reservar espaço de memória para o armazenamento das instruções e dados.
3. Converter valores de constantes para código binário.
4. Examinar a correção de cada instrução.

> Disciplinas e Livros onde são ensinados estes conceitos:

**Arquitetura de Computadores**

**Lógica** (é ensinado sobre árvores de derivação (usadas nos processos de analises))

**Linguagens de Programação** (vemos a nível intermediário tudo sobre as analises e todo o processo em si) - Linguagens de Programação do ROBERT W. SEBESTA

**Teoria de Compiladores**

Answer (score 5):

> com·pi·lar - Conjugar (latim compilo, -are) verbo transitivo
>
> 1. Reunir metodicamente escritos diversos sobre o mesmo assunto. = COLIGIR, COMPENDIAR
> 2. Reunir numa mesma obra trabalhos de várias origens. = COLIGIR, COMPENDIAR
> 3. Juntar um conjunto de informações. = COLIGIR
> 4. [Informática]  Converter linguagem de programação em linguagem ou código que possa ser lido ou corrido por um computador (ex.: compilar
>    um programa).
>
> "compilar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/compilar [consultado em
> 25-10-2022].

O termo é um pouco complicado e depende do contexto que é usado. Quase sempre falamos informalmente e não nos atemos ao que realmente acontece. A pergunta provavelmente quer saber sobre esse uso informal, que não está errado, mas a compilação mesmo é mais que isso.

De fato, quando a pessoa falar em compilar ela está querendo dizer outra coisa. Quase sempre ela está falando em construir a aplicação, o que algumas pessoas chamariam, como *buildar* por falta de um termo melhor em português.

Não é que a pessoa não esteja compilando e em geral ela faz isso em implementações de linguagens que tenham um software chamado compilador, e faça a geração da aplicação, muitas vezes gerando um executável do sistema operacional.

Ao contrário do que diz a resposta aceita, compilar não é gerar código de máquina, ainda que em muitos casos isso realmente ocorre. A maneira como as pessoas falam é o processo de geração da aplicação gerando código de máquina ou não. A compilação pode gerar códigos que serão "interpretados" de várias formas, e pode nem rodar diretamente no processador. Não é incomum a geração de linguagens que são intermediárias e que passaram por outro processo de tradução, e que pode ou não ser outra compilação.

Como a compilação de fato ocorre menos ainda e existem várias formas de dar o resultado final, muitas delas sem passar perto da linguagem de máquina.

Também não é obrigatório a criação do executável, ainda que seja comum.

Sem falar que a compilação em si não costuma gerar o executável e sim, a *linkedição*.

Estritamente falando, compilar significa apenas traduzir um código, provavelmente em forma de texto para uma outra forma que poderá ser entendido por algum mecanismo. Qualquer coisa além disso já não é a compilação em si. Muitas vezes o termo é usado para dizer sobre o processo de *parsear* o texto (não é só que ele faça o *parsing*, tem também outras análises explicadas nos *links* abaixo).

Até interpretadores tem uma compilação, mas não falamos que vamos compilar algo nele. O PHP ou JavaScript por exemplo não geram executáveis, em condições normais, não tem um processo de *build* normal (bem, JS tem um maluco em alguns casos dependendo da implementação :D), não traduzem diretamente ou até indiretamente em alguns casos para código nativo, mas mesmo assim ainda existe uma compilação de alguma forma.

Reforço que informalmente não está errado, mas precisamos ter a informação correta formal. As pessoas estão criando aplicações de forma muito ruim por não entenderem completamente o que estão usando, por preferirem opiniões a definições formais.

Respondi sobre o assunto em diversas perguntas que devem ser lidas para entender melhor o processo (se seguir os *links*). Lá tem os pontos que não respondi aqui, mas já foi respondido.

- [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101)
- [O que é Transpilação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101)
- [O que é assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/101)
- [O que é um JITter?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101)
- [Diferença entre compilação Ahead-Of-Time e Just-in-Time](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356739/101)
- [Pra que serve um linker?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre build e linkagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/457302/101)
- [O que é código objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454415/101)
- [Qual é a vantagem de usar linguagens que compila pra outras linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102787/101)
- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101)
- [Existe diferença entre um compilador e um interpretador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190209/101)
- [O que é uma linguagem interpretada? Java é interpretado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101)
- [C# é uma linguagem compilada ou interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/101)
- [Como fazer uma "compilação" do código em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/271758/101)
- [Existe interpretador C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179754/101)

Comment: Bom ponto. Eu já ia comentar que ex. os compiladores Java/.NET não geram (diretamente) código de máquina "real", mas a tua resposta aborda isso.