# O código Assembly de um programa compilado é diferente do que foi escrito?

Tags: assembly, debug, descompilação

Eu compilei esse código Assembly

```
global  _main 
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World!', 10, 0
```

quando eu fui dar u dump no codigo assembly me apareceu isso

```
hello.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00401000 <___mingw_CRTStartup>:
  401000:   53                      push   %ebx
  401001:   83 ec 38                sub    $0x38,%esp
  401004:   a1 24 30 40 00          mov    0x403024,%eax
  401009:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  40100b:   74 1c                   je     401029 <___mingw_CRTStartup+0x29>
  40100d:   c7 44 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x8(%esp)
  401014:   00 
  401015:   c7 44 24 04 02 00 00    movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
  40101c:   00 
  40101d:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  401024:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
  401026:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  401029:   c7 04 24 10 11 40 00    movl   $0x401110,(%esp)
  401030:   e8 7b 0b 00 00          call   401bb0 <_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter@4>
  401035:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
  401038:   e8 13 04 00 00          call   401450 <___cpu_features_init>
  40103d:   e8 ee 04 00 00          call   401530 <__fpreset>
  401042:   8d 44 24 2c             lea    0x2c(%esp),%eax
  401046:   89 44 24 10             mov    %eax,0x10(%esp)
  40104a:   a1 00 20 40 00          mov    0x402000,%eax
  40104f:   c7 44 24 04 00 50 40    movl   $0x405000,0x4(%esp)
  401056:   00 
  401057:   c7 04 24 04 50 40 00    movl   $0x405004,(%esp)
  40105e:   c7 44 24 2c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x2c(%esp)
  401065:   00 
  401066:   89 44 24 0c             mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
  40106a:   8d 44 24 28             lea    0x28(%esp),%eax
  40106e:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
  401072:   e8 d9 0a 00 00          call   401b50 <___getmainargs>
  401077:   a1 18 50 40 00          mov    0x405018,%eax
  40107c:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  40107e:   74 42                   je     4010c2 <___mingw_CRTStartup+0xc2>
  401080:   8b 1d fc 60 40 00       mov    0x4060fc,%ebx
  401086:   a3 04 20 40 00          mov    %eax,0x402004
  40108b:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  40108f:   8b 43 10                mov    0x10(%ebx),%eax
  401092:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  401095:   e8 be 0a 00 00          call   401b58 <__setmode>
  40109a:   a1 18 50 40 00          mov    0x405018,%eax
  40109f:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  4010a3:   8b 43 30                mov    0x30(%ebx),%eax
  4010a6:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  4010a9:   e8 aa 0a 00 00          call   401b58 <__setmode>
  4010ae:   a1 18 50 40 00          mov    0x405018,%eax
  4010b3:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  4010b7:   8b 43 50                mov    0x50(%ebx),%eax
  4010ba:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  4010bd:   e8 96 0a 00 00          call   401b58 <__setmode>
  4010c2:   e8 99 0a 00 00          call   401b60 <___p__fmode>
  4010c7:   8b 15 04 20 40 00       mov    0x402004,%edx
  4010cd:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
  4010cf:   e8 dc 05 00 00          call   4016b0 <__pei386_runtime_relocator>
  4010d4:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
  4010d7:   e8 34 08 00 00          call   401910 <___main>
  4010dc:   e8 87 0a 00 00          call   401b68 <___p__environ>
  4010e1:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  4010e3:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
  4010e7:   a1 00 50 40 00          mov    0x405000,%eax
  4010ec:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  4010f0:   a1 04 50 40 00          mov    0x405004,%eax
  4010f5:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  4010f8:   e8 53 02 00 00          call   401350 <_main>
  4010fd:   89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
  4010ff:   e8 6c 0a 00 00          call   401b70 <__cexit>
  401104:   89 1c 24                mov    %ebx,(%esp)
  401107:   e8 ac 0a 00 00          call   401bb8 <_ExitProcess@4>
  40110c:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi

00401110 <__gnu_exception_handler@4>:
  401110:   53                      push   %ebx
  401111:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
  401114:   8b 44 24 30             mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
  401118:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  40111a:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  40111c:   3d 91 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc0000091,%eax
  401121:   77 3d                   ja     401160 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x50>
  401123:   3d 8d 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc000008d,%eax
  401128:   72 4d                   jb     401177 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x67>
  40112a:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
  40112f:   c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
  401136:   00 
  401137:   c7 04 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,(%esp)
  40113e:   e8 35 0a 00 00          call   401b78 <_signal>
  401143:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  401146:   0f 84 f4 00 00 00       je     401240 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x130>
  40114c:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  40114e:   0f 85 a0 00 00 00       jne    4011f4 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0xe4>
  401154:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  401156:   83 c4 28                add    $0x28,%esp
  401159:   5b                      pop    %ebx
  40115a:   c2 04 00                ret    $0x4
  40115d:   8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
  401160:   3d 94 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc0000094,%eax
  401165:   74 4b                   je     4011b2 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0xa2>
  401167:   3d 96 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc0000096,%eax
  40116c:   74 17                   je     401185 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x75>
  40116e:   3d 93 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc0000093,%eax
  401173:   75 df                   jne    401154 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x44>
  401175:   eb b3                   jmp    40112a <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x1a>
  401177:   3d 05 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc0000005,%eax
  40117c:   74 42                   je     4011c0 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0xb0>
  40117e:   3d 1d 00 00 c0          cmp    $0xc000001d,%eax
  401183:   75 cf                   jne    401154 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x44>
  401185:   c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
  40118c:   00 
  40118d:   c7 04 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
  401194:   e8 df 09 00 00          call   401b78 <_signal>
  401199:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  40119c:   74 69                   je     401207 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0xf7>
  40119e:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4011a0:   74 b2                   je     401154 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x44>
  4011a2:   c7 04 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
  4011a9:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
  4011ab:   b8 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  4011b0:   eb a4                   jmp    401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  4011b2:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  4011b4:   e9 76 ff ff ff          jmp    40112f <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x1f>
  4011b9:   8d b4 26 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
  4011c0:   c7 44 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp)
  4011c7:   00 
  4011c8:   c7 04 24 0b 00 00 00    movl   $0xb,(%esp)
  4011cf:   e8 a4 09 00 00          call   401b78 <_signal>
  4011d4:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  4011d7:   74 4a                   je     401223 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x113>
  4011d9:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4011db:   0f 84 73 ff ff ff       je     401154 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x44>
  4011e1:   c7 04 24 0b 00 00 00    movl   $0xb,(%esp)
  4011e8:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
  4011ea:   b8 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  4011ef:   e9 62 ff ff ff          jmp    401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  4011f4:   c7 04 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,(%esp)
  4011fb:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
  4011fd:   b8 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  401202:   e9 4f ff ff ff          jmp    401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  401207:   c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
  40120e:   00 
  40120f:   c7 04 24 04 00 00 00    movl   $0x4,(%esp)
  401216:   e8 5d 09 00 00          call   401b78 <_signal>
  40121b:   83 c8 ff                or     $0xffffffff,%eax
  40121e:   e9 33 ff ff ff          jmp    401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  401223:   c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
  40122a:   00 
  40122b:   c7 04 24 0b 00 00 00    movl   $0xb,(%esp)
  401232:   e8 41 09 00 00          call   401b78 <_signal>
  401237:   83 c8 ff                or     $0xffffffff,%eax
  40123a:   e9 17 ff ff ff          jmp    401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  40123f:   90                      nop
  401240:   c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
  401247:   00 
  401248:   c7 04 24 08 00 00 00    movl   $0x8,(%esp)
  40124f:   e8 24 09 00 00          call   401b78 <_signal>
  401254:   85 db                   test   %ebx,%ebx
  401256:   b8 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
  40125b:   0f 84 f5 fe ff ff       je     401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  401261:   89 44 24 1c             mov    %eax,0x1c(%esp)
  401265:   e8 c6 02 00 00          call   401530 <__fpreset>
  40126a:   8b 44 24 1c             mov    0x1c(%esp),%eax
  40126e:   e9 e3 fe ff ff          jmp    401156 <__gnu_exception_handler@4+0x46>
  401273:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
  401279:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

00401280 <_mainCRTStartup>:
  401280:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
  401283:   c7 04 24 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
  40128a:   ff 15 f4 60 40 00       call   *0x4060f4
  401290:   e8 6b fd ff ff          call   401000 <___mingw_CRTStartup>
  401295:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
  401299:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

004012a0 <_WinMainCRTStartup>:
  4012a0:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
  4012a3:   c7 04 24 02 00 00 00    movl   $0x2,(%esp)
  4012aa:   ff 15 f4 60 40 00       call   *0x4060f4
  4012b0:   e8 4b fd ff ff          call   401000 <___mingw_CRTStartup>
  4012b5:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
  4012b9:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

004012c0 <_atexit>:
  4012c0:   a1 0c 61 40 00          mov    0x40610c,%eax
  4012c5:   ff e0                   jmp    *%eax
  4012c7:   89 f6                   mov    %esi,%esi
  4012c9:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

004012d0 <__onexit>:
  4012d0:   a1 00 61 40 00          mov    0x406100,%eax
  4012d5:   ff e0                   jmp    *%eax
  4012d7:   90                      nop
  4012d8:   90                      nop
  4012d9:   90                      nop
  4012da:   90                      nop
  4012db:   90                      nop
  4012dc:   90                      nop
  4012dd:   90                      nop
  4012de:   90                      nop
  4012df:   90                      nop

004012e0 <___gcc_register_frame>:
  4012e0:   55                      push   %ebp
  4012e1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  4012e3:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
  4012e6:   a1 0c 20 40 00          mov    0x40200c,%eax
  4012eb:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  4012ed:   74 3a                   je     401329 <___gcc_register_frame+0x49>
  4012ef:   c7 04 24 00 30 40 00    movl   $0x403000,(%esp)
  4012f6:   e8 c5 08 00 00          call   401bc0 <_GetModuleHandleA@4>
  4012fb:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
  4012fe:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401300:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  401305:   74 15                   je     40131c <___gcc_register_frame+0x3c>
  401307:   c7 44 24 04 0e 30 40    movl   $0x40300e,0x4(%esp)
  40130e:   00 
  40130f:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  401312:   e8 b1 08 00 00          call   401bc8 <_GetProcAddress@8>
  401317:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  40131a:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  40131c:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
  40131e:   74 09                   je     401329 <___gcc_register_frame+0x49>
  401320:   c7 04 24 0c 20 40 00    movl   $0x40200c,(%esp)
  401327:   ff d2                   call   *%edx
  401329:   c7 04 24 40 13 40 00    movl   $0x401340,(%esp)
  401330:   e8 8b ff ff ff          call   4012c0 <_atexit>
  401335:   c9                      leave  
  401336:   c3                      ret    
  401337:   89 f6                   mov    %esi,%esi
  401339:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

00401340 <___gcc_deregister_frame>:
  401340:   55                      push   %ebp
  401341:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  401343:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  401344:   c3                      ret    
  401345:   90                      nop
  401346:   90                      nop
  401347:   90                      nop
  401348:   90                      nop
  401349:   90                      nop
  40134a:   90                      nop
  40134b:   90                      nop
  40134c:   90                      nop
  40134d:   90                      nop
  40134e:   90                      nop
  40134f:   90                      nop

00401350 <_main>:
  401350:   c3                      ret    
  401351:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  401353:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  401355:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  401357:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  401359:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  40135b:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  40135d:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  40135f:   90                      nop

00401360 <___dyn_tls_dtor@12>:
  401360:   83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
  401363:   8b 44 24 24             mov    0x24(%esp),%eax
  401367:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401369:   74 15                   je     401380 <___dyn_tls_dtor@12+0x20>
  40136b:   83 f8 03                cmp    $0x3,%eax
  40136e:   74 10                   je     401380 <___dyn_tls_dtor@12+0x20>
  401370:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  401375:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
  401378:   c2 0c 00                ret    $0xc
  40137b:   90                      nop
  40137c:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
  401380:   8b 54 24 28             mov    0x28(%esp),%edx
  401384:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  401388:   8b 44 24 20             mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
  40138c:   89 54 24 08             mov    %edx,0x8(%esp)
  401390:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  401393:   e8 18 07 00 00          call   401ab0 <___mingw_TLScallback>
  401398:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40139d:   83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
  4013a0:   c2 0c 00                ret    $0xc
  4013a3:   8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
  4013a9:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

004013b0 <___dyn_tls_init@12>:
  4013b0:   56                      push   %esi
  4013b1:   53                      push   %ebx
  4013b2:   83 ec 14                sub    $0x14,%esp
  4013b5:   83 3d 28 50 40 00 02    cmpl   $0x2,0x405028
  4013bc:   8b 44 24 24             mov    0x24(%esp),%eax
  4013c0:   74 0a                   je     4013cc <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x1c>
  4013c2:   c7 05 28 50 40 00 02    movl   $0x2,0x405028
  4013c9:   00 00 00 
  4013cc:   83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax
  4013cf:   74 12                   je     4013e3 <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x33>
  4013d1:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  4013d4:   74 42                   je     401418 <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x68>
  4013d6:   83 c4 14                add    $0x14,%esp
  4013d9:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4013de:   5b                      pop    %ebx
  4013df:   5e                      pop    %esi
  4013e0:   c2 0c 00                ret    $0xc
  4013e3:   be 14 70 40 00          mov    $0x407014,%esi
  4013e8:   81 ee 14 70 40 00       sub    $0x407014,%esi
  4013ee:   c1 fe 02                sar    $0x2,%esi
  4013f1:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  4013f3:   7e e1                   jle    4013d6 <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x26>
  4013f5:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
  4013f7:   8b 04 9d 14 70 40 00    mov    0x407014(,%ebx,4),%eax
  4013fe:   85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  401400:   74 02                   je     401404 <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x54>
  401402:   ff d0                   call   *%eax
  401404:   83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
  401407:   39 f3                   cmp    %esi,%ebx
  401409:   75 ec                   jne    4013f7 <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x47>
  40140b:   83 c4 14                add    $0x14,%esp
  40140e:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  401413:   5b                      pop    %ebx
  401414:   5e                      pop    %esi
  401415:   c2 0c 00                ret    $0xc
  401418:   8b 44 24 28             mov    0x28(%esp),%eax
  40141c:   c7 44 24 04 01 00 00    movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
  401423:   00 
  401424:   89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
  401428:   8b 44 24 20             mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
  40142c:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  40142f:   e8 7c 06 00 00          call   401ab0 <___mingw_TLScallback>
  401434:   eb a0                   jmp    4013d6 <___dyn_tls_init@12+0x26>
  401436:   8d 76 00                lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
  401439:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
```

...

o codigo esta completamente diferente, por que o codigo muda depois de compilado?

Comment: Na verdade você não compilou o código Assembly, você ["montou"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178807/86952). Parece que alguns montadores podem fazer pequenas otimizações, veja no [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler).

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

O código fonte do seu Assembly é bonitinho, o código binário não tem comentários, não tem formatação, não tem detalhes.

O seu código não inclui tudo o que é necessário para executá-lo. Você pegou um binário que incluiu outros códigos necessários para executar. Tem configurações para reduzir isto ou até eliminar, porém ao eliminar tudo produzirá um binário, mas não um executável.

É possível que no processo de montagem o código que escreveu seja reescrito, especialmente se estiver usando alguma forma de *macro assembler* que se comporta como um compilador mesmo.