# O que são assembly languages (linguagem de montagem)?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, assembly

Eu estava pesquisando quais são as linguagens utilizadas para construir sistemas operacionais. Ao que parece, Windows, Mac e Linux usam, em larga medida, C e C++. Na mesma fonte que encontrei essa informação, li que toda kernel precisa ser programada em uma linguagem de montagem (assembly code).

Mas o que são linguagens de montagem? É o mesmo que linguagens de baixo nível? E, finalmente, por que um sistema operacional precisa ser construído com esse tipo de linguagem?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é assembler?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178804/69296)

Comment: E o [HLA(High Level Assembly)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Assembly) é uma linguagem de alto nível ou continua sendo linguagem de baixo nível só que usando perfume importado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mas o que são linguagens de montagem? É o mesmo que linguagens de baixo nível?

Assembly é uma linguagem de baixo nível, porém, não é o nível mais baixo. Um programa escrito em Assembly ainda precisa ser "convertido" em linguagem nativa (binária) para ser executada por um microprocessador. Quem faz essa conversão é o **Assembler**.

Assembly é uma linguagem baseada em mnemônicos, que são como "apelidos" de operações básicas que um microprocessador sabe executar. Por exemplo: acessar um local na memória, mover um valor de um local para outro na memória, etc.

Cada família de microprocessador pode possui seus próprios mnemônicos, assim como outras características específicas que podem influenciar no seu desempenho.

> E, finalmente, por que um sistema operacional precisa ser construído com esse tipo de linguagem?

Quando se usa uma linguagem de alto nível, podemos usar classes para separar escopos de funções e variáveis, as estruturas condicionais e de repetição, e claro, o Garbage Collector, são benefícios que facilitam nossa leitura, mas esse dinamismo cobra caro na hora de traduzir o programa para a máquina, uma vez que, existem vários microprocessadores, arquiteturas diferentes, e um compilador precisa saber a melhor forma de transformar o código que escrevemos em algo que a máquina irá ler da melhor forma. As vezes isso gera muito código adicional, pra não dizer lixo.

Linguagens de baixo nível precisam de mais código para executar programas complexos pois usam apenas operações básicas, isso a torna difícil para um humano ler, porém, o que é escrito em Assembly já segue uma lógica praticamente do nível que um microprocessador irá ler.

Normalmente, os programas de um sistema operacional são escritos em C e C++ -que alguns autores consideram como linguagens de nível médio. Escrever um programa diretamente em Assembly é mais comum quando se está desenvolvendo para camadas mais próximas do Hardware, como a comunicação com o microprocessador ou com os periféricos, ou configurações mais limitadas ou especificas como para softwares embarcados.