# Existe interpretador C?

Tags: c, c++, interpretador

Todo mundo sabe que C é uma linguagem compilada. Alguns sabem que em tese qualquer linguagem pode ser interpretada, a não ser que que ela tenha alguma especificação que impeça. Existem interpretadores C? Servem para alguma coisa?

E C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, existe sim. A utilidade dele é um pouco questionável já que C não é uma linguagem de *script*, nem de perto. Tem que ser meio maluco para usar C para isso, mas muita gente usa, talvez por ser a linguagem que está mais confortável.

Pode ser útil usar um [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) para ajudar a criar um código durante aprendizado, testes rápidos ou prototipação.

Os mais conhecidos são o [Ch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_(computer_programming)) (proprietário) e o CINT (*open source*). Ambos funcionam com C++ também, mas possuem limitações. O segundo é limitado até com C, mas aceita coisas que o C não aceita, ou seja, não é bem padrão, mas é mais adequado para *script*.

O [Cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling) é uma evolução do [CINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CINT).

Há quem use o [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) como interpretador.

Vale a pena dar uma olhada também no [picoc](https://github.com/zsaleeba/picoc), [cinterpeter](https://github.com/danielkeller/cinterp), [ccons](https://github.com/asvitkine/ccons), e principalmente o [iGCC](http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Entre as aplicações práticas existe o Tcs.

O TCS (TC shell) é um shell interpretador de comandos baseados em C. Você pode usá-lo para executar os comandos C diretamente da linha de comando.

Também vale a pena dar uma olhada no Lua (www.lua.org/), que é uma linguagem interpretada baseada e pode ser usada para extender os comandos em C.